# Tips for golfing in Scala

Tags: code-golf, tips, scala

What general tips do you have for golfing in Scala? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Scala (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

[(This is a shameless copy of ... in Python)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*disclaimer: parts of this answers are generalizations of other answers found here.*

### Use lambdas without specifying their argument types

It's allowed to submit something like this: `a=>a.size` instead of `(a:String)=>a.size`.

### Use ascii-symbols as identifiers.

These include `!%&/?+*~'-^<>|`. Because they arent't letters, they get parsed separately when they're next to letters.

Examples:

```
a=>b       //ok
%=>%        //error, parsed as one token
% => %      //ok
val% =3     //ok
&contains+  //ok
if(x)&else* //ok
```

### Use Set instead of contains

```
if (Seq(1,2,3,'A')contains x)... //wrong
if (Set(1,2,3,'A')(x))...         //right
```

This is possible because `Set[A] extends (A => Boolean)`.

### Use a curried function when you need two arguments.

```
(a,b)=>... //wrong
a=>b=>...  //right
```

### Use the `_`-syntax when possible

The rules for this are somewhat obscure, you have to play a little bit around sometimes to find the shortest way.

```
a=>a.map(b=>b.size)) //wrong
a=>a.map(_.size)     //better
_.map(_.size)        //right
```

### Use partial application

```
a=>a+1 //wrong
_+1    //better, see above
1+     //right; this treats the method + of 1 as a function
```

### Use `""+` instead of `toString`

```
a=>a.toString //wrong
a=>a+""       //right
```

### Use strings as sequences

`""` is sometimes the shortest way to create an empty sequence if you don't care about the actual type

### Use BigInt to convert numbers to and from strings

The shortest way to convert a number to a string in a base other than base 10 is through BigInt's `toString(base: Int)`method

```
Integer.toString(n,b) //wrong
BigInt(n)toString b   //right
```

If you want to convert a string to a number, use `BigInt.apply(s: String, base: Int)`

```
Integer.parseInt(n,b) //wrong
BigInt(n,b)           //right
```

Be aware that this returns a BigInt, which is useable like a number most of the times, but can't be used as an index for a sequence, for example.

### Use Seq to create sequences

```
a::b::Nil   //wrong
List(...)   //also wrong
Vector(...) //even more wrong
Seq(...)    //right
Array(...)  //also wrong, except if you need a mutable sequence
```

Use Strings for Seqences of chars:

```
Seq('a','z') //wrong
"az"         //right
```

### Make use of Stream for infinite sequences

Some challenges ask for the n-th element of an infinite sequence. Stream is the perfect candidate for this. Remember that `Stream[A] extends (Int => A)`, that is, a stream is a function from an index to the element at that index.

```
Stream.iterate(start)(x=>calculateNextElement(x))
```

### Use symbolic operators instead of their wordy counterparts

`:\` and `:/` instead of `foldRight` and `foldLeft`

```
a.foldLeft(z)(f) //wrong
(z/:a)(f)        //right
a.foldRight(z)(f) //wrong
(a:\z)(f)         //right
```

`hashCode` -> `##`

`throw new Error()` -> `???`

Use `->` for creating and unpacking tuples

```
(a,b)  //wrong
a->b   //right
```

### Use `&` and `|` instead of `&&` and `||`

They work the same for booleans, but will always evaluate both operands

### Alias long method as functions

```
def r(x:Double)=math.sqrt(x) //wrong
var r=math.sqrt _            //right; r is of type (Double=>Double)
```

### Know the functions in the standard library

This especially applies to the methods of collections.

Very useful methods are:

```
map
flatMap
filter
:/ and :\ (folds)
scanLeft and scanRight
sliding
grouped (only for iterators)
inits
headOption
drop and take
collect
find
zip
zipWithIndex3
distinct and/or toSet
startsWith
```

Answer (score 14):

The shortest way of repeating something is with `Seq.fill`.

```
1 to 10 map(_=>println("hi!")) // Wrong!
for(i<-1 to 10)println("hi!") // Wrong!
Seq.fill(10)(println("hi!")) // Right!
```

Comment: `for(i<-1to 10)println("hi!")` has the same length

Answer (score 13):

#### suspicious identifier: ?

You can use ? as identifier:

```
val l=List(1,2,3)
val? =List(1,2,3)
```

Here it doesn't save you anything, because you can't stick it to the equal sign:

```
val ?=List(1,2,3) // illegal
```

But later on, it often saves one character, since you don't need a delimiter:

```
print(?size)  // l.size needs a dot
def a(? :Int*)=(?,?tail).zipped.map(_-_)
```

However, it is often tricky to use:

```
       print(?size)
3
       print(?size-5)
<console>:12: error: Int does not take parameters
       print(?size-5)
              ^
```

Comment: There are also other identifiers, such as `|`, `>`, and pretty much any symbol that's not a word character (other than parentheses, commas, dots, semicolons, equal signs, square brackets, curly brackets...)

Answer (score 12):

### Collections

The first choice for a random collection is often *List*. In many cases you can replace it with *Seq*, which saves one character instantan. :)

Instead of

```
val l=List(1,2,3)
val s=Seq(1,2,3)
```

and, while s.head and s.tail is more elegant in usual code, `s(0)` is again one character shorter than `s.head`.

Even shorter in some cases - depending on needed functionality is a tuple:

```
val s=Seq(1,2,3)
val t=(1,2,3)
```

saving 3 characters immediately, and for accessing:

```
s(0)
t._1
```

it is the same for direct index access. But for elaborated concepts, tuples fail:

```
scala> s.map(_*2)
res55: Seq[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)

scala> t.map(_*2)
<console>:9: error: value map is not a member of (Int, Int, Int)
       t.map(_*2)
         ^
```

#### update

```
def foo(s:Seq[Int])
def foo(s:Int*)
```

In parameter declaration, Int* saves 4 characters over Seq[Int]. It is not equivalent, but sometimes, Int* will do.

Answer (score 10):

Use infix syntax to remove the need for `.` characters. You don't need spaces unless adjacent items are both in alphanumeric or both in operator characters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala)), and not separated by reserved characters (brackets, commas etc).

E.g.

```
List(1,2,3,4).filter(_ % 2 == 0) // change to:
List(1,2,3,4)filter(_%2==0)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can usually use `map` instead of `foreach`:

```
List("a","b","c") foreach println
```

can be replaced with

```
List("a","b","c") map println
```

The only difference is the return type (`Unit` vs `List[Unit]`), which you aren't interested in anyway when using `foreach`.

Answer (score 9):

Call two times the same function for initialization:

```
val n,k=readInt
```

(Seen somewhere else, but can't find it now).

Answer (score 9):

The `true` and `false` literals are shorter to write as `2>1` for true and `1>2` for false

Answer (score 7):

define shorter Types:

If you have multiple declarations of a type, like

```
def f(a:String,b:String,c:String)
```

it is shorter to define a type alias, and use it instead:

```
type S=String;def f(a:S,b:S,c:S)
```

Original length is 3*6=18 
Replacement-code is 8(type S=;)+6+3*1(=new length)=17

if (n*length < 8+length+n), then it is an advantage.

For classes which are instantiated via a factory, we can set a shorter variable name to point to that object. Instead of:

```
val a=Array(Array(1,2),Array(3,4))
```

we can write

```
val A=Array;val a=A(A(1,2),A(3,4))
```

Comment: This applies to C++ as well with `#define` for example, but I admit it's nice that `def` and `val` are shorter.

Comment: Hm. `def` is the keyword to define a method, and a simple translation to c++ for `val` is 'const', and it is a declaration, but the type is often inferred. The shortening is in the first case the `type=` which is closer to `typedef` - isn't it? The second example isn't from me and it is new to me. I have to watch out, where to use it.

Comment: `typedef long long ll;` is the same as `#define ll long long`, so the latter's shorter by 1.  But yeah, `typedef` does work.  Looking at the `val` example again I definitely misread it.  It seems even less Scala-specific.  `x = thingWithAReallyLongComplicatedNameForNoReason` is a pretty general strategy :P

Comment: @userunknown When you instantiate a `List` or `Array` etc with syntax `val x = List(1,2,3)` you're just calling the `apply` method on the `List` object. (This technique for object creation is known as a "factory method", in contrast to using a constructor with `new`.) So above, we're just making a new variable that points to the same singleton object as the variable name `Array`. Since it's the same thing, all the methods, including `apply`, are available.

Answer (score 6):

Rename Methods, if their name is long, and if they're used multiple times - real world example:

```
 x.replaceAll(y,z)

 type S=String; def r(x:S,y:S,z:S)=x.replaceAll(y,z)
```

Depending on the possibility to save 'S=String' at different places too, this will  only be economical, if you replace at least replaceAll 3 times.

Answer (score 6):

Initialize several variables at once using a tuple:

```
var(a,b,c)=("One","Two","Three") //32 characters
```

vs.

```
var a="One";var b="Two";var c="Three" //37 characters
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use `lazyZip` or `zipped` (and `_`) instead of `zip` when combining lists

Using `a.zip(b)` is shorter than `a.lazyZip(b)` or `(a,b).zipped`, but if you're using `map` on it later, the latter will be shorter, since with `zip`, `map` requires function taking a single `Tuple2`, but with `lazyZip`/`zipped`, you can use a function of two parameters with underscores.

Here's an example adding together two lists:

```
val list1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val list2 = List(5, 6, 7, 8)

list1.zip(list2).map(t=>t._1+t._2)   //Not good
list1.lazyZip(list2).map((a,b)=>a+b) //Okay, this is worse
list1.lazyZip(list2).map(_+_)        //But underscores make it all better
(list1,list2).zipped.map((a,b)=>a+b) //Same as with lazyZip
(list1,list2).zipped.map(_+_)        //Same as with lazyZip
```

Since `zipped` is deprecated, I'd recommend `lazyZip`, as you can also use infix syntax with it. However, in some situations, such as when you're zipping more than 2 lists, `zipped` may still be better (and it's not available on TIO, which uses an older version of Scala - you'll need Scastie).

Answer (score 3):

## Treat a String as a Sequence

### Use `filter` instead of `replace` or `replaceAll`

If you need to erase characters from a String use instead of `replace` / `replaceAll`

```
x replaceAll(y,"") // 18 bytes
x replace(y,"")    // 15 bytes
```

the `filter` method:

```
x filter(y!=)      // 13 bytes
```

### Do not use `charAt`

If you need a character from a specific index from a String, do not use `charAt`:

```
x charAt 7  // 10 bytes
```

Treat the String as a sequence:

```
x(7)        // 4 bytes
```

### Use `drop` / `slice` instead of `substring`

```
x substring y    // 13 bytes
x drop y         //  8 bytes


x substring(a,b) // 16 bytes
x slice(a,b)     // 12 bytes
```

**Thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for extending the answer!**

Comment: If you want to expand your answer(s) with more String-related tips, here's another: `s.drop(x)` is shorter than `s.substring(x)`, and `s.slice(a,b)` is shorter than `s.substring(a,b)` (really, almost any time you treat a `String` like a `Seq`, it's shorter).

Answer (score 3):

0. Use syntactic sugar and built-in functions to save bytes.

syntactic sugar, e.g.    use `/: operator (fold left)`

```scala
val sum = numbers.foldLeft(0) { (accumulator, element) => accumulator + element }

val sum = (0 /: numbers) { (accumulator, element) => accumulator + element }
```

1. Type conversion.  `231+.0` instead of `231.toDouble`.  `231+""` instead of `231.toString`
2. Use `Seq` instead of `Array` or `List`
3. Rewrite type name and method name.

Rewrite the type name if the type appears **very many times**.

Use generic parameter instead of external type definition to save more bytes.

```scala
/*42 bytes*/
def f(a:String,b:String,c:String,d:String)

/*36 bytes*/
type S=String
def f(a:S,b:S,c:S,d:S)

/*33 bytes*/
def f[S<:String](a:S,b:S,c:S,d:S)
```

If the method appears **very many times**, please rewrite the method name.

```scala
implicit class V[A](val x:A)extends AnyVal{def Q=x.toSet}
```

4. Avoid `def` return type if possible.   Use `def` instead of lambda function `val f=`.   e.g.

   use `def f(a:Int)=a+1` instead of `val f:(Int=>Int)={a:Int=>a+1}` to save bytes.
5. Avoid unnecessary braces `{} ()`
6. Simultaneously initialize multiple variables `val r,c=new StringBuilder;`
7. use  `0 to x-1` instead of `0 until x`

Comment: Use generic parameter instead of external type definition: [`def f[S<:String](a:S,b:S,c:S,d:S)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wYKlpSVpuhY3FVNS0xTSooNtrIJLijLz0mM1Eq2CdZKAOBmIU6yCNaEK3RUUbBO1lYAwCUwmg8kUay4uh9zEzDwFkDkghoamgq1CAdCokpw8jTQNpUQlHaUkIE4G4hQlTahxMPsB) This is shorter than just inlining the type if you have more than 2 arguments of that type.

Comment: @noodle man,  so many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## If you need to reuse a function, make a `def` instead of a `val`

If you absolutely need to define a function in your answer to reuse multiple times, it's usually better to define it like a method rather than using a lambda.

Consider these two pairs of functions:

```scala
//Recursive
def f(i:Int):Int=if(i>0)i*f(i-1)else 1
val f:Int=>Int=i=>if(i>0)i*f(i-1)else 1

//Not recursive is also shorter with def
def f(i:Int)=i+1
val g=(i:Int)=>i+1
```

## Except when using pattern matching

However, if you're pattern matching, you can use Scala's special syntax and omit `match` when assigning an anonymous function to a `val`. As you can see, it's a lot shorter:

```scala
//Highly efficient way to sum a list
val g:List[Int]=>Int={case h::t=>h+f(t)case _=>0}
def f(l:List[Int]):Int=l match{case h::t=>h+f(t)case _=>0}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `⇒` instead of using `=>` for function definitions.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. Since most of the time, answers are counted in bytes rather than characters, your tip only has a limited scope. I would address this and also add a tip title like _Shortening function definitions in character count based code golf challenges_.