# Make a "Ceeeeeeee" program

Tags: code-golf, string

Once I wrote a JavaScript program that would take as input a string and a character and would remove all characters except for the first one and the character given as input, one by one.

For example, computing this with inputs `codegolf.stackexchange.com` and `e` for the character yields:

```
codegolf.stackexchange.com
cdegolf.stackexchange.com
cegolf.stackexchange.com
ceolf.stackexchange.com
celf.stackexchange.com
cef.stackexchange.com
ce.stackexchange.com
cestackexchange.com
cetackexchange.com
ceackexchange.com
ceckexchange.com
cekexchange.com
ceexchange.com
ceechange.com
ceehange.com
ceeange.com
ceenge.com
ceege.com
ceee.com
ceeecom
ceeeom
ceeem
ceee
```

It keeps the first character and all `e`s. All other characters are removed one by one.

Your task is to write a program (or function) that takes two inputs and outputs (or returns) a string that accomplishes this effect.

### Specifications

- You can assume that the string will not contain any newlines.
- The second input will always be one character.
- If the answer is in the form of a function, you may return an array of strings containing each line in the output.
- The output can contain a trailing newline.

### Test Cases

`Test Cases`, `s`:

```
Test Cases
Tst Cases
Ts Cases
TsCases
Tsases
Tsses
Tsss
```

`Make a "Ceeeeeeee" program`, `e`:

```
Make a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Mke a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Mea "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me"Ceeeeeeee" program
MeCeeeeeeee" program
Meeeeeeeee" program
Meeeeeeeee program
Meeeeeeeeeprogram
Meeeeeeeeerogram
Meeeeeeeeeogram
Meeeeeeeeegram
Meeeeeeeeeram
Meeeeeeeeeam
Meeeeeeeeem
Meeeeeeeee
```

`Hello World!`, `!`:

```
Hello World!
Hllo World!
Hlo World!
Ho World!
H World!
HWorld!
Horld!
Hrld!
Hld!
Hd!
H!
```

`Hello World!`, `z`:

```
Hello World!
Hllo World!
Hlo World!
Ho World!
H World!
HWorld!
Horld!
Hrld!
Hld!
Hd!
H!
H
```

`alphabet`, `a`:

```
alphabet
aphabet
ahabet
aabet
aaet
aat
aa
```

`upperCASE`, `e`:

```
upperCASE
uperCASE
uerCASE
ueCASE
ueASE
ueSE
ueE
ue
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Kinda random, but +1

Comment: +1 for `Meeeeeeeeegram`

Comment: In the case that it returns an array, do each of the elements have to include a trailing newline?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills No.

Comment: Reminded me of SOMA Transmission #8 (look up on YouTube). "It's the weight of the s-e-e-e-ea!"

Comment: Meeeeeeeeeeeeem

Comment: String encoding matters a lot for how difficult this is in some languages. Should be be able to handle utf8 in both the input character and the string?

Comment: Input: `Return expression_that_is_so_long_that_you_cant_even_read_in_one_second`,
Output: ***`Reeeeeee`***

Comment: @l4m2 The `alphabet` example I think answers your question but I'm not sure. The first character will never be pruned and every iteration should prune a character as shown by the `"Ceee"` example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 12 bytes

```
òYpó.“„a]òd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394U2TB4c16hyYfahFKjD28KeX//@T8lNT0/Jw0veKSxOTs1IrkjMS89FS95Pzc/6kA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f259 70f3 2e93 8412 615d f264            .Yp.....a].d
```

I have tested this with [the latest version of V available before the challenge](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/tree/439edc84892be237dc65eb408ea3e6ba93ceff4d), and everything runs correctly, making this answer competing.

Explanation:

```
ò         ò    " Recursively:
 Yp            "   Duplicate this line
   ó           "   Remove:
    .a]      "     A compressed regex
            d  " Delete our extra line
```

The compressed regex translates to

```
.\zs[^e]
```

Which means

```
.           " Any character
 \zs        " Leave the previous character out of the selection
    [^e]    " Any character except for 'e' (Or whatever is given for input)
```

**[11 bytes version](https://tio.run/nexus/v#ATAAz///w7LDmcOzLsKTwoQSYV3DsmT//2NvZGVnb2xmLnN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29t/2U)**

This version uses a shortcut for `Yp` that wasn't available when this challenge was posted.

Comment: @challenger5 Awesome! I'll check out an old version and verify that it works correctly. I might have to modify it slightly. I'll ping you once I've updated.

Comment: @Challenger5 I have edited the answer, and verified that this version worked when the challenge was posted.

Comment: How would I execute a bunch of Vim commands stored in a file on a Linux system? Would i `cat filename | vim` or would I do something else?

Answer (score 31):

## Vim, <s>27, 26</s>, 25 bytes

```
DJqqYp:s/.\zs[^<C-r>-]<CR>@qq@qD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@@/iVVgYWWBVrK8XU1UcHSekG8vlUFjoUOjy/38qV3J@Smp6fk6aXnFJYnJ2akVyRmJeeqpecn4uAA)

Input comes in this format:

```
e
codegolf.stackexchange.com
```

My naive first approach is three bytes longer:

```
i:s/.\zs[^<Right>]<Esc>"addqqYp@a@qq@qdd
```

I'm also happy with this answer because it starts with my name.

```
DJqq:t$|s/.\zs[^<C-r>"]<CR>@qq@qD
DJMcMayhem
```

See the similarity? Eh?

Less successful approaches:

```
i:s/.\zs[^<Right>]<Esc>"addqqYp@a@qq@qdd
i:s/.\zs[^<Right>]<CR>@q<Esc>"adkqqYp@aq@qdd
DJ:s/.\zs[^<C-r>"]<CR>uqqYp@:@qq@qdd
DJqq:t.|$s/.\zs[^<C-r>"]<CR>@qq@qdd
```

Explanation:

```
D                                   " Delete everything on this first line
 J                                  " Remove this empty line
  qq                                " Start recording into register 'q'
    Y                               " Yank this line
     p                              " And paste it
      :s/                           " Run a substitute command on the last line in the buffer. Remove:
         .                          "   Any character
          \zs                       "   Move the selection forward (so we don't delete the first one)
             [^<C-r>-]              "   Followed by anything *except* for the character we deleted
                      <CR>          " Run the command
                          @q        " Call register 'q'
                            q       " Stop recording
                             @q     " Run the recursive macro
                               D    " Delete our extra line
```

Comment: I think you got a typo there where the input is given there is a `k` too much :)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 I'm not sure if I get what you mean?

Comment: It says `(...)comk` In line 5 currently.

Comment: There's no reason to use `:t` here. Normal `Yp` would save a byte. You'll have to switch to `<C-R>-` of course. Typical PPCG rules are frustrating, because for any reasonable test case, `:t.|s` with `99@:` or even `999@:` would be correct, but there's no good way to get an *infinite* repeat that way. You're forced to use less interesting strats.

Answer (score 22):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```
y-f1X-"t[]@X@q-(
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J2NvZGVnb2xmLnN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tJwonZSc) Or verify test cases: [1](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J1Rlc3QgQ2FzZXMnCidzJw), [2](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J01ha2UgYSAiQ2VlZWVlZWVlIiBwcm9ncmFtJwonZSc), [3](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkIScKJyEn), [4](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkIScKJ3on), [5](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eS1mMVgtInRbXUBYQHEtKA&input=J2FscGhhYmV0JwonYSc).

#### Bonus

Modified code to *see the string being gradually shrunk* (offline compiler):

```
y-f1X-"tt.3Y.XxD[]@X@q-(].3Y.XxDvx
```

[image]

Or try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=y-f1X-%22tt.3Y.XxD%5B%5D%40X%40q-%28%5D.3Y.XxDvx&inputs=%27codegolf.stackexchange.com%27%0A%27e%27&version=19.4.0)

### Explanation

```
y        % Implicitly input string and char. Duplicate string onto top
-        % Subtract. Gives nonzero for chars in the input string that are
         % different from the input char
f        % Array of indices of nonzero values
1X-      % Remove 1 from that array. This gives an array of the indices of 
         % chars to be removed from the string
"        % For each
  t      %   Duplicate previous string
  []     %   Push empty array
  @      %   Push index of char to be removed. But this index needs to be 
         %   corrected to account for the fact that previous chars have
         %   already been removed...
  X@q-   %   ... So we correct by subtracting the 0-based iteration index
  (      %   Assign empty array to that position, to remove that char
         % Implicitly end for each
         % Implicitly display
```

Comment: GIFS! gifs are cool!

Answer (score 20):

## Haskell, 50 bytes

```hs
w@(a:x)%c|(d,_:y)<-span(==c)x=w:(a:d++y)%c|0<1=[w]
```

Defines a function `(%)` returning a list of strings.

#### Explanation

`(%)` is called as `w%c`, with `w` being the input string, and `c` the character to keep. In short, this definition works by separating `w` into the first character (`a`) and the remainder (`x`), splitting `x` at the first occurrence of a character other than `c`, and recursively calling itself with that one character dropped.

```
w@(a:x)%c              -- define (%) with w separated into a and x.
 |(d,_:y)<-span(==c)x  -- split x; bind the string of `c` to d, and the rest
                       -- to _:y, dropping first character and calling the rest y.
  =w:(a:d++y)%c        -- if there was a character to drop, cons w onto the
                       -- sequence gained by recursively calling (%) with that
                       -- character removed (i.e. call with a:d++y).
 |0<1=[w]              -- if nothing needed to be dropped, the result sequence is
                       -- simply the one-element list [w]
```

Comment: Can you explain the code?

Comment: @bli Done! Hopefully this helps?

Answer (score 14):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
;{G*1`
R1r`(?!^|.*¶?\1$)(.)
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=O3tHKjFgClIxcmAoPyFefC4qwrY_XDEkKSguKQ&input=Y29kZWdvbGYuc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb20KZQ)

#### Explanation

```
;{G*1`
```

There's a lot of configuration here. The stage itself is really just `` G1` ``, which keeps only the first line, discarding the input character. `*` turns it into a dry run, which means that the result (i.e. the first line of the string) is printed without actually changing the string. `{` tells Retina to run both stages in a loop until the string stops changing and `;` prevents output at the end of the program.

```
R1r`(?!^|.*¶?\1$)(.)
```

This discards the first character which a) isn't at the beginning of the input, b) isn't equal to the separate input character.

Answer (score 10):

## Perl 5, 29 bytes

I got 35 bytes using Strawberry Perl: 31 bytes, plus 1 for `-nE` instead of `-e`, plus 3 for space + `-i` (used for the single-letter input; the longer string is from STDIN).

```
chomp;say;s/(.)[^$^I]/$1/&&redo
```

However, I've no doubt this is doable without `chomp;` using `<<<`, which is 29 bytes, even though I can't test it myself using Strawberry.

```
say;s/(.)[^$^I]/$1/&&redo
```

Thus:

```
perl -im -nE'say;s/(.)[^$^I]/$1/&&redo' <<< "example"
```

Comment: You can just specify "no newline in the input" (which is how the second program works). If you badly need to remove newlines in the input, look into the `-l` option, which turns on an automatic newline handling mode in which `print` prints an additional newline (irrelevant here) and `-p`/`-n` input removes the newline (very relevant). Also, it's deprecated, but I think you can replace the `^I` with a literal control-I for an extra byte of savings. Finally, I think `s/.\K[^$^I]/redo/e` would be one character shorter, although I'm not 100% sure that's a legal place to put a `redo`.

Comment: @ais523, thanks for the newline advice, but I guess I handled the issue well enough already. Re literal `^I`, that's true for most of the control-letter variables, but not this one, IIRC. Re `\K` and putting `redo` in the replacement with `/e`, thanks! I'll test it when I have a chance to….

Comment: ... and it doesn't work. @ais523

Answer (score 10):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>22</s> <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
Lv+#Paa@oQb?++oPaRA:ox
```

Takes string as first command-line argument, character as second. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=THYrI1BhSWFAb1FiKytvRSBQYVJBOm94&input=&args=VGVzdCBDYXNlcw+cw)

#### Explanation

Loops over characters of input; if the character equals the special character, move on to the next one; if not, delete it and print the string.

An ungolfed version (`a`, `b` get cmdline args; `o` starts with a value of `1`, `x` is `""`):

```
P a         Print a
L #a-1      Loop len(a)-1 times:
 I a@o Q b   If a[o] string-eQuals b:
  ++o         Increment o
 E {         Else:
  a RA: o x   In-place in a, Replace char At index o with x (i.e. delete it)
  P a         Print a
 }
```

Golfing tricks:

- The loop header for `L` is only evaluated once, so we can sneak the initial print in there. `#Pa-1` won't work because `P` is low-precedence (it would parse as `#P(a-1)`), but we can rearrange it to `v+#Pa`, using the `v` variable preinitialized to `-1`.
- The `RA:` operator returns the new value of `a`, so we can print that expression instead of having a separate `Pa` statement.
- Now both of the branches of the if statement are single expressions, so we can use the ternary operator `?` instead.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>47 40</s>  38 bytes

```perl6
->\a,\b{a,{S/^(."{b}"*:)./$0/}...^{$^a eq $^b}}
```

```perl6
->\a,\b{a,{S/^(."{b}"*:)./$0/}...^&[eq]}
```

```perl6
{$^b;$^a,{S/^(."$b"*:)./$0/}...^&[eq]}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
{       # lambda with two placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

  $^b;    # declare second parameter

  $^a,    # declare first parameter, and use it to seed the sequence

  {       # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
    S/      # string replace and return
      ^       # beginning of string
      (       # capture into ｢$0｣
        .       # the first character
        "$b"*   # as many ｢$b｣ as possible
        :       # don't allow backtracking
      )
      .       # any character ( the one to be removed )

    /$0/      # put the captured values back into place
  }

  ...^      # repeat that until: ( and throw away the last value )

  &[eq]     # the infix string equivalence operator/subroutine

}
```

The reason `...^` was used instead of `...` is that `&[eq]` wouldn't return `True` until the last value was repeated.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
def e(i,k):
 for r in i:
  if r!=k:i=i[0]+i[1:].replace(r,'',1);print(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFVI1MnW9OKSyEtv0ihSCEzTyETyFHITFMoUrTNtsq0zYw2iNXOjDa0itUrSi3ISUxO1SjSUVfXMdS0LijKzCvRyNT8n6qh/mH@jO4P85dO/TC/tw9ITwbiiUj0JKB4G5CeAqWB4r2tQHoOVM0UCL@3BSSvrqMOElbX/A8A)

```python
e('','')
```

Go on a diet:

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>71</s> 66 bytes:

```
f,m=input();k=f[0]
while f:a=f[0]==m;k+=f[0]*a;f=f[1+a:];print k+f
```

A full program. Takes 2 inputs through STDIN in the format `'<String>','<Char>'`.

Also, here is a recursive solution currently at **140 bytes**:

```
Q=lambda c,p,k='',j=1,l=[]:c and Q(c[1:],p,k+c[0]*(j<2)+c[0]*(c[0]==p),j+1,l+[k+c])or'\n'.join(sorted({*l},key=l.index))+('\n'+k)*(k not in l)
```

This one should be called in the format `print(Q('<String>','<Char>'))`.

Comment: I'm no python buff, but shouldn't this print only one line?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yeah, I misread the post before. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>26</del> 25 bytes

```
¬ˆ[¦Ðg_#¬²k0Qi²ˆë¯J?,]¯J?

¬ˆ                         Put the first character into an array
  [                        While true
   ¦                       Remove the first character
    Ð                      Triplicate
     g_#                   if the string is empty, break
        ¬²k0Qi             if the first character is equal to the one specified in the input
              ²ˆ           Add it to the array
                ë          Else
                 ¯J?       Display the array
                    ,      Display the remaining string
                     ]     End while
                      ¯J?  Display the last string
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqzLhlvCpsOQZ18jwqzCsmswUWnCssuGw6vCr0o_LF3Cr0o_&input=TWFrZSBhICJDZWVlZWVlZWUiIHByb2dyYW0KZQ)

Please note that `¬²k0Q` could be rewritten `¬²Q`, but for some reason it doesn't work when the current character is a quote mark: Q returns the actual string instead of a boolean and it causes an infinite loop.

This code can be golfed further since `¯J?` is duplicated. Moving this part in the loop would remove the duplication and would also allow to drop the closing square bracket.

Comment: `DˆćUΔD²KRнõ.;DXìˆ}¯¨»` for 21, but that uses new commands.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```
(s,c)=>[...t=s.slice(1)].map(d=>c!=d?s+=`
`+s[0]+(t=t.replace(d,``)):s)&&s
```

Comment: I think this produces incorrect output for `f('test cases', 's')` (ending with `stss`, rather than `tsss`).
I think this is because `replace` removes the first occurance so it removes the first `t` rather than the second `t` in the fourth iteration of the `map` loop.

Comment: @Lmis Thanks for pointing that out, I think I was able to fix one of my versions for "only" a 7 byte penalty.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>148</s> <s>139</s> <s>97</s> <s>90</s> <s>83</s> <s>77</s> 62 bytes

```
a,c=$*;p s=""+a;i=1;while d=s[i];(d!=c)?(s[i]="";p s):i+=1;end
```

Not sure if amateur code is accepted on this exchange but I'm interested in learning to code golf although I'm terrible at it, any help on how I'd get this program looking as small as the others here?

**EDIT:**

Replaced puts with p

Removed a tonne of whitespace and counted bytes correctly thanks to Wheat Wizard

Thanks to challenger5 went from `s=gets.chop;c=gets.chop;` to `s,c=gets.chop,gets.chop;`

replaced `then` with `;` and `gets.chop` with `gets[0]` thanks Mhutter!

Taking input as command line variables now, eg. `prog.rb helloworld l`

Thanks to numerous improvements by jeroenvisser101 replacing `a=s.dup` with `s=""+a` and the previous if statement `if s[i]!=c;s[i]="";p s;else i+=1;end` with `(d!=c)?(s[i]="";p s):i+=1;` huge improvement!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I am not an expert in Ruby golfing but it looks like you have extra whitespace.  Particularly around the `=`s.  For more comprehensive tips you can visit our [tips page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby).

Comment: The easiest way to remove bytes is to eliminate excess whitespace, for example `s=gets.chomp`. I'm not sure if you can do this in Ruby but in some languages like Python you can combine multiple assignments into one statement, like `a,b,c=0,1,2`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip about whitespace read the ruby documentation and realised semicolons can replace them for ending statements :') as for making the s=gets.chop and c=gets.chop i cant do s,c=gets.chop or anything like that unfortunately theyre definitely the largest part of the code and I'd like to remove that lengthy statement..

Comment: You still have some extra spaces particularly before keywords  (`do`,`then` and `end`), and around the fourth `=`.

Comment: It looks like you are short changing yourself on the byte count.  I only count 90 bytes myself.

Comment: @WheatWizard trimmed it a bit more! The file size is being counted as 97 bytes in my file explorer... I guess I should've calculated them instead of taking explorers word on it thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `then` is not needed: Replace with `;`, -4 bytes or so; `c=gets[0]`, -1 byte

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys down to about half what I started at!

Comment: `a,c=$*;s=""+a;i=1;p s;while s[i]do(s[i]!=c)?(s[i]="";p s):i+=1;end` is 67 chars, extra trick with ternary and `""+a` instead of `Object#dup`

Comment: Actually, it's 66 chars, I didn't count correctly 

Comment: And -1 `a,c=$*;s=""+a;i=1;p s;while s[i];(s[i]!=c)?(s[i]="";p s):i+=1;end`, 65 bytes now

Comment: And -3 `a,c=$*;p s=""+a;i=1;while d=s[i];(d!=c)?(s[i]="";p s):i+=1;end` is 62 bytes

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 wow awesome job I love the s=""+a; trick very clever!

Comment: Replacing puts with p changes the output for strings (adds unexpected quotes around it). It's a good trick to use with types for which `inspect` is `to_s` like integers, but not strings.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 <s>64 69</s>

Thanks to @Shaggy for shaving 1 byte!

Returning a single string with newlines

```js
s=>c=>[...s].map((x,i,z)=>i&&x!=c&&(s+=`
`+z.join(z[i]='')))&&s
```

```js
F=
s=>c=>[...s].map((x,i,z)=>i&&x!=c&&(s+=`
`+z.join(z[i]='')))&&s
  

function update() {
  var s=S.value,c=C.value[0]
  O.textContent=F(s)(c)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=S value='Hello world!' oninput='update()'>
<input id=C value='!' oninput='update()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Slightly odd in that it doesn't take two arguments but one argument and then returns another function where you need to give the second argument. I'm not sure this was the expected behaviour.

Comment: @MT0 I's odd but it's accepted for a function with 2 arguments, as it saves 1 byte. I'll give you a reference when I find one. Here it is http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8427/21348

Comment: Great technique, I didn't realize that modifying the third argument to `.map` was cumulative. I saw the `.map().filter()` and thought "This would make a great array comprehension!", but the lack of index in array comprehensions killed it and it ended up at the same length: ```s=>c=>[for(x of(i=0,z=[...s]))if(--i&&x!=c)(z[~i]=~i?'':x,z.join``)]``` (btw, I count 68 bytes for all of these.)

Comment: Actually, by rearranging the params you can get the array comprehension down to 66: ```([...z],c,i=0)=>[for(x of z)if(--i&&x!=c)(z[~i]=~i?'':x,z.join``)]```

Comment: @ETHproductions can't believe I was wrong in byte count *again*. Anyway, thanks to making me think again about it, so I got 64 with standard ES6

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxDsMgDADAvb/ogoySeu5iPhJFMnIhJW0ABRQhPk978@32skXOkOvjeg5Po5ARMgsilhUPmwHaHOauyQSl2p1EKSgT8Y2njnsKEfoSVmLWWitVRj5DrOCBJb3clr4eS7XycU3eNm4OJR2sgd3/jx8)

Answer (score 4):

## c90, <strike>129</strike> 125 bytes

with whitespace:

```
main(q, x)
{
    for (char **v = x, *a = v[1], *b = a, *c;*b++;)
        for (c = a; c == a | *c == *v[2] && *b != *v[2] && putchar(*c),
            ++c != b || *b != *v[2] && !puts(b););
}
```

without whitespace:

```
main(q,x){for(char**v=x,*a=v[1],*b=a,*c;*b++;)for(c=a;c==a|*c==*v[2]&&*b!=*v[2]&&putchar(*c),++c!=b||*b!=*v[2]&&!puts(b););}
```

ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *a = argv[1];
    for (char *b = a + 1; *b; b++) {
        if (*b == *argv[2]) {
            continue;
        }
        putchar(*a);
        for (char *c = a + 1; c != b; c++) {
            if (*c == *argv[2]) {
                putchar(*c);
            }
        }
        puts(b);
    }
}
```

This takes a pointer to the start of the string, and loops, iterating this pointer until it reaches the end of the string. Within the loop, it prints the first character, then any instances of the second argument it finds between the start of the string and the pointer. After this, it calls puts on the pointer, printing out the rest of the string.

This must be compiled on a system where sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*). +3 bytes otherwise.

This is the first time I've tried code golfing here, so I'm sure there are some optimizations to be made.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>88</s> <s>84</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> 78 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to @IsmaelMiguel, 3 bytes thanks to @user59178, 3 bytes inspired by @user59178

```
while($b=substr("$argv[1]\n",$i++))$a>""&$b[0]!=$argv[2]?print$a.$b:$a.=$b[0];
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `php -r <code> '<string>' <character>`

---

- appends a newline to the input for an implicit final print.
  That adds <s>5</s> 4 bytes of code, but saves on the output and an additional `echo$a;`.

Comment: `$argv[1]."\n"` can be written as `"$argv[1]\n"`

Comment: As `$b` gets a newline added to it it will always by truthy as long as it has length >= 1. As such the `""<` is unnecessary.

Comment: You can save another byte by using a ternary in the `substr()` rather than assigning `$b`.

Comment: @user59178 I didn´t really catch you there: I need the `substr` result for both the condition and the `print`; so I should assign it somewhere. But You inspired me.

Comment: I meant `for(;$b=substr($b?:".$argv[1]\n",1);)` but what you have now even better.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 27 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

`{×i←⊃1+⍸⍺≠1↓⎕←⍵:⍺∇⍵/⍨i≠⍳≢⍵}`

`⍺` is the excluded character, `⍵` is the initial string

print argument; find index `i` of the first non-`⍺` after the first char; if found, call recursively with `i` removed

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
Most@FixedPointList[StringReplace[#,b_~~Except@a:>b,1]&,a=#2;#]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes two strings as input, and returns a list of strings as output. Works by repeatedly removing the first non-instance of the character.

Comment: I am definitely going to start using `FixedPointList`.

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

Thanks @Kade for 2 bytes!
Thanks @Emigna for 1 byte!

```
¬UDvy²k0Êiy¡¬s¦yý«Xs«=¦
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqxVRHZ5wrJrMMOKaXnCocKsc8KmecO9wqtYc8KrPcKm&input=TWFrZSBhICJDZWVlZWVlZWUiIHByb2dyYW0KZQ)

`y²k0Ê` could be `y²Ê` but the `"` messes it up.

This probably could be golfed more because `«` is repeated twice. Please leave a comment if you have any suggestions or ways to golf it down more.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>155</s> <s>140</s> <s>139</s> 124 bytes

```java
c->s->{var r=s+"\n";for(int i=0;++i<s.length();)if(s.charAt(i)!=c)r+=(s=s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i--+1))+"\n";return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pZCxbsIwEIZ3nuLIgq0Qi85pIqGoVRcmKnUoHY7ggME4lu@CRBHPnqYlEp1aqnrxyefvP3/e4gGT7WrXlhaJYIbGnQYAxMimhG3XVQ0bq6rGlWxqpx774r7YYMCSdRj/eG3Owbj1GC57nkMFWVsmOSX56YABQkZxtHBRWtVBGMdgskkax@aelNVuzRshU2kqQarsBk5ZGDnMShniTFBGipolfSWLydjI@PuBSZL4TspLetDcBAchPbfpoBP0zdJ2gr3noTYr2Hfu4vLM1zdA@fkPAPMjsd6rumHluxZbJyqF3tujGNFI9mX0rImhQNIUSZn@SuorOcOdBoRFVOh@LSLwoV4H3N@UNbxmPWlra3ipg10Nb2Lf/8HilUXrN7jU/Ff3xnsdiun8oQfPg3P7AQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
c->s->{          // Method with character and String parameters and String return-type
  var r=s+"\n";  //  Result-String, starting at the input-String with trailing new-line
  for(int i=0;++i<s.length();)
                 //  Loop over the characters of the String, skipping the first
    if(s.charAt(i)!=c)
                 //   If the current character and the input-character are equal
      r+=(s=s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i--+1))
                 //     Remove this character from the String `s`
         +"\n";  //     And append the new `s` with trailing new-line to the result-String
  return r;}     //  Return the result-String
```

---

**Old 139 bytes recursive answer:**

```java
void c(String s,int c){System.out.println(s);for(int i=1;i<s.length();)if(s.charAt(i++)!=c){c(s.substring(0,i-1)+s.substring(i),c);break;}}
```

-1 bytes thanks to *@Eugene*. (Next time make a comment instead of editing someone else's post, please.)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nY@xbsIwEIZ3nuKSBVsJUZldBoSQujBRqUPpcHFMYjBx5HOQWpRnT50oA0OHqDfef9@v7y54x9WluPbSIBEcUNePBQB59Fr2d6sLkOzona5LoFTXHiR/HL/Jq1tmW581IfGmZsTF2To2HOjNWuhXyoyqS18xLrg@M8pkhW7rmU4SHm1CiQw7anMau9lLqldrnjyvNE8lF7lTeBVd14tF8Gra3Gg56cGodwvKk@HnFyAf9CFIx@@KPOyQFMUpLGnJxZj8IT8lgTngVQHCKd6paU4xNM6WDm9Di5rV8qaMsfBhnSmigYr@Rf3MotA0FebKDwTOItqmUW63Pe6fHuoWXf8L)

**Explanation:**

```java
void c(String s,int c){     // Method with String and integer parameters and no return-type
  System.out.println(s);    //  Print the input-String with trailing new-line
  for(int i=1;i<s.length();)//  Loop over the characters of the String, skipping the first
    if(s.charAt(i++)!=c){   //   If the current character and the input-character are equal
      c(s.substring(0,i-1)+s.substring(i),c); 
                            //    Remove this character, and do a recursive call
      break;}}              //    And stop the loop
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much shorter to not bother with a char[], and just use s.charAt()?

Comment: @dpa97 Ah, you're completely right. I used a foreach loop at first, but changed it to a regular for-loop. Forgot to remove the char-array. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>135</s> <s>138 :(</s> 137 bytes

Golfed:

```
IEnumerable<string>F(string s,char c){int i=1,l;for(;;){yield return s;l=s.Length;while(i<l&&s[i]==c)i++;if(i==l)break;s=s.Remove(i,1);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
    IEnumerable<string> F(string s, char c)
    {
        int i = 1, l;

        for (;;)
        {
            yield return s;

            l = s.Length;

            while (i < l && s[i] == c)
                i++;

            if (i == l)
                break;

            s = s.Remove(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

Function returns collection of strings.

EDIT1: @psycho noticed that algorithm was not implemented properly.

EDIT2: Created variable for `s.Length`. One byte saved thanks to @TheLethalCoder.

Comment: Won't work if the input char is present more than once in a row. Ex : `codeegolf e` would give `ce` instead of `cee`.

Comment: @psycho I swapped `if` with `while` and it works.

Comment: Better ! But it can be shorter. I'll post my own !

Comment: Create a variable for `s.Length` to save one byte: `int i=1,l;for(;;){yield return s;l=s.Length;while(i<l&&s[i]==c)i++;if(i>=l)break;s=s.Remove(i,1);}}`

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>122</strike> <strike>117</strike> 112 bytes

```
IEnumerable F(string s,char c){for(int i=0;i<s.Length;++i)if(i<1||s[i]!=c)yield return i>0?s=s.Remove(i--,1):s;}
```

Ungolfed :

```
public IEnumerable F(string s, char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) {
        if (i < 1 || s[i] != c)
            yield return i > 0 ? s = s.Remove(i--, 1) : s;
    }
}
```

Returns a collection of strings.

Comment: Nice trick with using not generic collection. But it won't work, if last char is not special char `c`. In that case loop will try to work forever.

Comment: @paldir Woops, you're right ! Turning my brain on this time, found a better (and shorter !) way.

Comment: You could remove the parenthesis of the for loop to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @PmanAce Sorry, what do you mean ? Which parenthesis ?

Comment: public IEnumerable F(string s, char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        if (i < 1 || s[i] != c)
            yield return i > 0 ? s = s.Remove(i--, 1) : s;    
}

Comment: @PmanAce Hmm... What you wrote is exactly my code with spaces. Wild guess : did you mean the brackets ? They're only present in the ungolfed version :)

Comment: Ah ok sorry, my bad then, I assumed your ungolfed version was just indented. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>26</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
jljjhF3<Q/Q*jih>s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=jljjhF3%3CQ%2FQ%2ajih%3Es&input=e%0Acodegolf.stackexchange.com)

```
                  - Q = input
j                 - j = input_2
 ljjhF3           - for (i, j, j[0]) for i in range(len(j))
       <          -     j[:i]
        Q/        -    ^.count(Q)
          Q*      -   ^*Q
                s -  sum(j[0], ^, V)
            jih>  -   j[i+1:]
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @Challenger5 done and golfed 2 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

**TSQL, 127 bytes(Excluding variable definitions)**

```
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(100)='codegolf.stackexchange.com'
DECLARE @2 CHAR(1) = 'o'

DECLARE @ char=LEFT(@1,1)WHILE patindex('%[^'+@2+']%',@1)>0BEGIN SET @1=STUFF(@1,patindex('%[^'+@2+']%',@1),1,'')PRINT @+@1 END
```

Formatted:

```
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(100) = 'codegolf.stackexchange.com'
DECLARE @2 CHAR(1) = 'o'
DECLARE @ CHAR = LEFT(@1, 1)

WHILE patindex('%[^' + @2 + ']%', @1) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @1 = STUFF(@1, patindex('%[^' + @2 + ']%', @1), 1, '')

    PRINT @ + @1
END
```

Comment: Good use of `patindex`, but the `alphabet` example doesn't seem quite right, it displays `aaphabet` down through `aaa`. Also worth mentioning this should be run on a server or database with a case-sensitive collation, otherwise the `upperCASE` example also fails, displaying `ueE` on its final row.

Answer (score 2):

## **Python 2 - <s>65</s> 73 Bytes**

```
lambda s,c:[s[0]+c*s[1:i].count(c)+s[i+1:]for i in range(len(s))]
```

And a **76 Bytes** recursive solution, because despite being longer than the firt one, I kinda like it better:

```
f=lambda s,c,i=1:s[i:]and[[s]+f(s[:i]+s[i+1:],c,i),f(s,c,i+1)][s[i]==c]or[s]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Racket 194 bytes

```
(let p((s s)(n 1)(t substring)(a string-append))(displayln s)(cond[(>= n(string-length s))""]
[(equal? c(string-ref s n))(p(a(t s 0 n)(t s n))(+ 1 n)t a)][else(p(a(t s 0 n)(t s(+ 1 n)))n t a)]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s c)
  (let loop ((s s)
             (n 1))
    (displayln s)
    (cond
      [(>= n (string-length s))""]
      [(equal? c (string-ref s n))
       (loop (string-append (substring s 0 n) (substring s n))
             (add1 n))]
      [else
       (loop (string-append (substring s 0 n) (substring s (add1 n)))
             n)])))
```

Testing:

```
(f "Test cases" #\s)
(f "codegolf.stackexchange.com" #\e)
```

Output:

```
Test cases
Tst cases
Tst cases
Ts cases
Tscases
Tsases
Tsses
Tsses
Tsss
Tsss
""
codegolf.stackexchange.com
cdegolf.stackexchange.com
cegolf.stackexchange.com
cegolf.stackexchange.com
ceolf.stackexchange.com
celf.stackexchange.com
cef.stackexchange.com
ce.stackexchange.com
cestackexchange.com
cetackexchange.com
ceackexchange.com
ceckexchange.com
cekexchange.com
ceexchange.com
ceexchange.com
ceechange.com
ceehange.com
ceeange.com
ceenge.com
ceege.com
ceee.com
ceee.com
ceeecom
ceeeom
ceeem
ceee
""
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3 - <s>151</s> 147 bytes

Swift isn't the ideal language for golfing, particularly when it relates to string indexing. This is the best I could do:

```swift
func c(a:String,b:String){print(a);var q=Array(a.characters),i=1;while i<q.count{if "\(q[i])" != b{q.remove(at:i);c(a:String(q),b:b);break};i=i+1}}
```

Unfortunately, Swift needs spaces around `!=` (but not for `==`), and Swift 3 dropped the `++` operator. The trick for both of these is to convert to a character array which allows integer indexing, and using string interpolation of a character to convert back to a `String` (`"\(c)"`).

Ungolfed:

```swift
func c(a:String, b:String) {
    print(a)
    var q = Array(a.characters)
    var i = 1
    while i < q.count {
        if "\(q[i])" != b {
            q.remove(at:i)
            c(a: String(q), b: b)
            break
        }
        i=i+1
    }
}
```

---

#### Previous, non-recursive solution

```swift
func c(a:String,b:String){var q=Array(a.characters),e={q.removeFirst()},z="\(e())";print(a);while !q.isEmpty{"\(e())"==b ? z=z+b : print(z+String(q))}}
```

```swift
func c(a:String, b:String) {
    var q = Array(a.characters)
    var z = "\(q.removeFirst())"
    print(a)
    while !q.isEmpty {
        if "\(q.removeFirst())" == b {
            z = z + b
        }else{
            print(z + String(q))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Can some of the whitespace towards the end of the code be removed?

Comment: @ETHproductions unfortunately not, the ternary operator and the `while` need spaces to compile. I also played with typealiasing `String` and trying to set `print` to a closure, but they didn't save any space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 77 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.625 bytes

```
ḣ≬‡⁰≠Ǒ⟇↔Ṡ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4bij4oms4oCh4oGw4omgx5Hin4fihpThuaArIiwiIiwiY29kZWdvbGYuc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb21cbmUiXQ==)

### Explained

The very first explanation generated using [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire/), a currently work-in-progress explanation formatting assistant. Now with metadata!

```
ḣ≬‡⁰≠Ǒ⟇↔Ṡ+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ḣ           # ‎⁡Push first character of input, then all of input minus first character
 ≬     ↔    # ‎⁢Repeat and collect results of applying the following on the top of the stack until invariant:
  ‡  Ǒ      # ‎⁣  Find the first index of:
   ⁰≠       # ‎⁤     a character that isn't the second input
      ⟇     # ‎⁢⁡  Remove that character from the top of the stack
        Ṡ   # ‎⁢⁢Convert each item to a string via vectorised summation
         +  # ‎⁢⁣Prepend the first letter to each
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
f(x,v,i)char*x,*i;{for(puts(i=x);*++i;)*i-v&&puts(x,strcpy(i--,i+1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcy9DoIwFIbhnas4MkBbyuDcMLG4uJk4iENTCzaCJW0hNYRrr/wYz/jleY/IGyFCqJGnI1VYPLkhnhLFplob1A/OIlV4zEiWKYaJysck2VZPrTOi/yCV51RlR4zZHDqu3ghP0foG7O0OBcQXaR2U3Eobs6hGlkJqU8x243Zz5i8JHKq4lL@rYuiNbgzvtsotlfxXw16dZNtquGrTPg6bGhZ1WNUcvg)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes(32-bit) by c--

```c
f(x,v){char*i;for(puts(i=x);*++i;)*i-v&&puts(x,strcpy(i--,i+1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcwxD4IwEIbh3V9xMmAL7aCODROLi5uJgzo0tcXGIqRXDMbw160Kxhu/PO8pXikVoyE9u9OnukifWWEaT9ouILFFT0WW51bQzPJ7mo5rzzB41T6I5ZzZfEmpGGIt7Y3Q5@z7AvBwggKSncYApUSNiZgZggwWuKBiMmEyW3nVIOGYlPp3xwRa31Re1mMVPpX@V91UbbRzDewb787zUXUfNf@qIb6UcbLCyOv16g0)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 78 bytes

Damn you Martin Ender, I was almost first :p

```
(i=2;a={c=#};While[i<=Length@c,If[c[[i]]==#2,i++,c=c~Drop~{i};a=a~Append~c]];a)&
```

Unnamed function; straightforward implementation with a `While` loop and a few temporary variables.

Comment: [Oh, c'mon,](http://ppcg.lol/a/100517) we both know that Mathematica isn't imperative

Comment: <waves a white flag>

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 89 bytes

I thought this would be an easy challenge, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here..

Uses recursion and returns an array of strings

```
(c,i=1,r)=>f=a=>a[i]?a[i++]==c?f(a):f(g=a.slice(0,i-1)+a.slice(i--),(r=r||[a]).push(g)):r
```

```js
F=
  (c,i=1,r)=>f=a=>a[i]?a[i++]==c?f(a):f(g=a.slice(0,i-1)+a.slice(i--),(r=r||[a]).push(g)):r

G=_=>A.value.length>1 && (O.innerHTML = F(E.value)(A.value).join`
`)

G()
```

```html
<input id=A oninput='G()' value='alphabet'>
<input id=E oninput='G()' value='a'>
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 142 Bytes

```
a,b,l1=input(),input(),0
for n in range(len(a)):
    l2=l1
    l1=''.join([a[:len(a)-n]]+[x for x in a[len(a)-n:] if x==b])
    if l2!=l1: print(l1)
```

It takes a as the string and b as the char, then goes through each letter in the string and adds it to the list if it's the first one or the character. Then it joins and prints.

**EDIT**: Fixed the problem mentioned by @R. Kap where it included copies of the first character as well, and shortened it to 63 bytes in the meantime.

**EDIT 2**: Now I realize you have to print out each string along the way. Brilliant. Well, this code is no longer golfed, but rather driven to the hole on a moped.

Comment: As per [this post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7634/59363), I think you can make the first line `a,b=input()`, but you would have to use Python 2, which would make it so that you could remove the parenthesis with `print`. You would provide the input like this `'Hello, World', 'o'`.

Comment: Hmmm...for the first test case (`codegolf.stackexchange.com,e`) I just get the output `cececec`.

Comment: This solution doesn't output the intermediate strings

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 34 bytes

```
{a,b->a.inject{i,r->i+=r==b?b:""}}
```

Comment: Its so weird to get an old answer upvoted...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 91 bytes

```
function(p,k){for(var i=1;i<p.length;)p[i]!=k?console.log(p=p.slice(0,i)+p.slice(i+1)):i++}
```

<sup>Huge thanks to ETHproductions for the help!</sup>

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We don't allow programs that rely on existing variables, but you can turn this into a function returning an array: `function(f,t){a=[];a.push(f[0]);for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++)if(f[i]==t)a.push(f[i]);return a}`

Comment: Also, this doesn't actually answer the question; entries should create a list of the strings, and this seems to only output multiple copies of `t`.

Comment: @ETHproductions You're right, I'll try to re-do it. Here's what I have to far `function(p,k){for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(p[i]!=k){p = p.replace(p[i],'');console.log(p)}}` I'm trying to fix an issue where the length of my loop is decreasing while iterating. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think you could do `function(p,k){for(var i=0,l=p.length;i<l;i++)if(p[i]!=k){p=p.replace(p[i],'');console.log(p)}}`.

Comment: I'm getting the following with that function http://imgur.com/a/Oaeyr

Comment: Ah, try this: `function(p,k){for(var i=0;i<p.length;)p[i]!=k?console.log(p=p.replace(p[i],'')):i++}`

Comment: Nice! That works. Just need to change the starting index to 1 so we can keep the first letter of the phrase.

Comment: I think the best way to do that would be [this](http://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=utf-8&t=function%28p%2Ck%29%7Bfor%28var%20i%3D1%3Bi%3Cp%2Elength%3B%29p%5Bi%5D!%3Dk%3Fconsole%2Elog%28p%3Dp%2Eslice%280%2Ci%29%2Bp%2Eslice%28i%2B1%29%29%3Ai%2B%2B%7D), which is 91 bytes.

Comment: I was using slice before I realized I could just replace the character with an empty string. What's the advantage in using slice?

Comment: If you come across the first char later in the string, `.replace` will remove the first char instead. For example, `"cdedc","e"` would output `cedc cec ec`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 104 bytes

### Golfed:

```
(x,y)->{String q="(.["+y+"]*)",s=x;while(!x.matches(q))s+="\n"+(x=x.replaceFirst(q+".","$1"));return s;}
```

### Ungolfed

```
(x, y) -> {
        String q = "(.[" + y + "]*)", s = x; // Store pattern for matching, and start our 'list' of strings.
        while (!x.matches(q)) {              // While our string doesn't fit a valid 'Ceeeeee' pattern...
            s += "\n" + (                    // We append our list of strings with a newline and...
            x = x.replaceFirst(q + ".", "$1")// A version of the string where the next character that isn't our given character is removed through regex replacement.
            );
        }
        return s;                            // We then return the newline-delimited string.
    }
```

### Output:

```
Hello world!
Hllo world!
Hll world!
Hllworld!
Hllorld!
Hllrld!
Hllld!
Hlll!
Hlll
```

[See it here!](http://ideone.com/6hteAm)

Function is a lambda (BiFunction used in test code). Takes a String and a Character, and returns a String.

Comment: Hello from the future! Looks like the character input doesn't need to be regex-safe, so you'll have to do some escaping. Consider input `foo`, `^`.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 65 bytes

```
INPUT S$,C$?S$@L
IF I&&S$[I]!+C$THEN S$[I]=""?S$ELSE I=I+1
GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 52 Bytes

```
=LEFT(A1)&REPT(A2,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,A2,"")))
```

where `A1` and `A2` are the string and the substitute letter respectively

I realise that may not actually answer the question, the wording is functions *may return arrays* but I'm guessing I need all the intermediate steps. So I've added

## VBA, <s>142</s> 137 (-4) bytes

```
Sub x(a, b)
For i = 2 To Len(a)
c = Mid(a, i, 1)
If c = "" Then End 'or d = 1 / Len(c) but then we quit on an error
If b<>c Then a = Replace(a, c, "", , 1): i = 1: Debug.?a
Next
End Sub
```

Which I think is the right byte count but I'm not sure how extra lines are treated. called in the same way as the Excel version. Returns all the steps in the Immediate Window

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Line endings are counted as 1 byte, so the VBA byte count is correct.

Comment: There are unfortunately a couple of things wrong with this response. 1) the VBA answer fails to output the unchanged string and 2) the Excel response does not produce all lines of output

Comment: You can remove a good bit of whitespace to get this down to 125 bytes, `Sub x(s,v)`
`Debug.?s`
`For i=2To Len(s)`
`c=Mid(s,i,1)`
`If c=""Then End`
`If v<>c Then s=Replace(s,c,"",,1):i=1:Debug.?s`
`Next`
`End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
¬ËUoÈ¥Vª!YªY>E
â
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=rMtVb8ilVqohWapZPkUK4g==&input=LVIKJ01ha2UgYSAiQ2VlZWVlZWVlIiBwcm9ncmFtJyAnZSc=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Uq mDEF{UoXYZ{X==V||!Y||Y>E
Uâ

Uq mDEF{    Split input into chars and map...
  UoXYZ{      Filter on the original input...
    X==V||      Keeping chars same as 2nd input (V),
    !Y||        1st char,
    Y>E         and indices exceeding outer index
\n          Close all braces implicitly and save the result to U
Uâ          Take unique elements from U
```

Turns out that trying to use regex is way too verbose here.

The `-R` flag joins the resulting array of strings with newline, saving three bytes `<space>qR` at the end. Also, this code exploits the JS feature of `Array.map` and `Array.filter`, where the index is passed as the 2nd argument (`E` and `Y` in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 135 bytes

```
(lambda a:print(a[0])or[a.__setitem__(0,a[0][0]+a[0][1:].replace(x,'',1))or print(a[0]) for x in a[0][1:] if x!=a[1]])([input(),input()])
```

Comment: @Hat Wizard Because otherwise it would call [None, None, None, None, ...], and since lists aren't callable, it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3: <del>108</del> 99 bytes

```
def g(s,o):
 r,p=s[0],print
 for i in range(1,len(s)):
  if s[i]==o:r+=s[i]
  else:p(r+s[i:])
 p(r)
```

Then invoke the function with:

```
g('alphabet', 'a')
```

Output:

```
alphabet
aphabet
ahabet
aabet
aaet
aat
aa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCgMhEAB7X7GdK2eRkE7wJYeFIau3ICqrTV7ved3MMP0/r1Y/a/0oQcZhm3EKxHY/zlewXbhOBakJMHAFiTUTvm2hisM8K3CCcXLwvjk5/IM7UhnkOsqx3QWjYLNZGXUs/YpfmtqCjtqsGw)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is it possible to edit in a link to an online testing environment, such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run), so that others can verify your answer? It also looks like you can make a few golfs, such as removing `continue`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxCgMhEAB7X7GdK2eRkE7wJYeFIau3ICqrTV7ved3MMP0/r1Y/a/0oQcZhm3EKxHY/zlewXbhOBakJMHAFiTUTvm2hisM8K3CCcXLwvjk5/IM7UhnkOsqx3QWjYLNZGXUs/YpfmtqCjtqsGw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes

```
$o(…:⁰v≠TḢh⋎
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIkbyjigKY64oGwduKJoFThuKJo4ouOIiwiIiwiY29kZWdvbGYuc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb21cbmUiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
$o(…:⁰v≠TḢh⋎
$            # swap top 2 items
 o           # remove
  (          # loop
   …         # print without popping
    :        # duplicate
     ⁰       # last input
      v      # vectorise
       ≠     # not equal
        T    # truthy indices
         Ḣ   # remove head [0]
          h  # head
           ⋎ # bitwise or
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḣȥ(ȤJ¢£x;ḢYẊy¹=?yȥ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboW-x7uWHRiqcaJJV6HFh1aXGEN5EY-3NVVeWinrX3liaVLipOSi6FKF-xJzk9JTc_PSdMrLklMzk6tSM5IzEtP1UvOz-VKhagBAA)

##### Explanation

```python
Ḣȥ(ȤJ¢£x;ḢYẊy¹=?yȥ  # Implicit input
Ḣȥ                  # Extract the first character, and add it to the global array
  (     ;           # While loop
   ȤJ               # (condition)   Join the global array
     ¢              #               Print it with no newline
      £             #               Print top of stack with a newline
       x            #               Push x (initialised to 1)
         Ḣ          # (body)        Extract the first character
          Y         #               Pop and store in y
           Ẋ        #               Without popping, store the rest in x
            y       #               Push y again
             ¹=     #               Is it equal to the second input?
               ?    #               If it is:
                yȥ  #                 Add y to the global array
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 94 bytes

```
def f(n,s,d=1):
 print(n)
 if set(n[1:])-{s}:
  if n[d]==s:d+=1
  n=n[:d]+n[d+1:];f(n,s,d)
```

Happy to have broken 100 bytes but I'm sure it could be golfed down.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <strike>87</strike> 83 bytes

```
s=open(0).read()
p,c,s=s[0],s[-2],s[:-3]
for h in s:p+=s[:h==c];s=s[1:];print(p+s)
```

Explanation: I chose python 3 instead of python 2, because it allows to use file descriptors in `open` (and `0` is the descriptor of the standard input). In each loop iteration `p` keeps track of stored prefix. `s[:h==c]` works as follows: boolean expression `h==c` is casted into integer (0 or 1), and then the corresponding amount of characters from the beginning of `s` are taken.

P.S. The loop in the initial version was:

```
for h in s:
 if h==c:p+=h
 s=s[1:];print(p+s)
```

Comment: Defining a function will be much shorter. 62 characters: `def _(s,c):
 p=s[0]
 for h in s:p+=s[:h==c];s=s[1:];print(p+s)` (2 line breaks as needed)

Comment: This prints extra lines when `c` is encountered (e.g. `cegolf.stackexchange.com` is printed twice with `c='e'`)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES2015) - 86 bytes

```
let f=([a,...s],c,r=[])=>r[0]==a+s?r:f(a+s.replace(eval(`/[^${c}]/`),''),c,[a+s,...r])
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet? I can't seem to get this to work

Comment: It actually wasn't working to begin with. I forgot I intended to wrap the function with another. I've fixed it now. I'm on my iPad, procrastinating - don't even know how I'd add a working snippet lol

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>83</s> 79 bytes

```c
char x[];i;m(char*v,c){for(x[i]=*v;*v;)*++v-c?printf("%s%s\n",x,v):(x[++i]=c);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## sed, 76 (code) + 3 (-nr flags) = 79 bytes

```
N;s/(.*)\n(.).*/\2\1/
:L
h;s/.//;p;x
/^(.)(.\1*)$/q
s/^(.)(.\1*)./\1\2/
b L
```

Commented:

```
# Read in both lines, and swap the order so we can use
# back references to check for the special character
N;s/(.*)\n(.).*/\2\1/

:L

# Erase the first character (temporarily) and print the line
h;s/.//;p;x

# Terminate once only the second character in the buffer doesn't match the first
/^(.)(.\1*)$/q

# Erase the first non-matching character
s/^(.)(.\1*)./\1\2/

b L
```

Unfortunately, back references aren't permitted within character classes, so we're forced to repeat ourselves a bit on the last three lines.  If it were possible, we could replace `b L` with `t L`, and remove `/^(.)(.\1*)$/q` entirely, thus dropping this down to 65 bytes.

Usage:

```
$ cat in
Test Cases
s
$ sed -nrf foo.sed < in
Test Cases
Tst Cases
Ts Cases
TsCases
Tsases
Tsses
Tsss
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>94</s> 93 Bytes

```
b=list(input())
c=input()
i=1
while i<len(b):
 while b[i]==c:i+=1
 b.pop(i);print(''.join(b))
```

Thanks to @Challenger5 for pointing out that I had misread the question

Comment: You can use `[*input()]` rather than `list(input())`, and you can omit the parenthesis around `[b[0],input()]`.

Comment: Also, this fails for input `interesting` and `e` (the second `i` is kept).

Comment: @Challenger5 for the `[*interesting]` I am getting a syntax error: `SyntaxError : can use starred expression only as assignment target`. Also, sorry about the error; I had misunderstood the question, and am fixing it.

Comment: Just realised; in the above comment, I meant to put `[*input()]`

Comment: [TIO Link](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@kYKsQrZWZV1BaoqEZy1VQlJlXopGk@f9/akVibkFOKgA "Python 3 – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, <strike>107</strike> 82 bytes

Thanks to corvus_192 for a scala code-golf discussion link (appreciated!)

### Golfed

```
1.to(s.size-1)./:(s take 1)((p,i)=>if(s(i)!=c){println(p+s.drop(i));p}else p+s(i))
```

### Ungolfed

```
(1 until s.length).foldLeft((s.take(1), List[String]())) { case ((prefix, acc), i) =>
  s.charAt(i) match {
    case char if char != c => (prefix, acc :+ (prefix + s.drop(i)))
    case char => (prefix + char, acc)
  }
}._2.foreach(println)
```

Using `foldLeft` means we can 'accumulate' the prefix, and print a new line when the next character does not equal 'c'.  Short-hand for foldLeft is `/:`

Ungolfed, we can also accumulate the results and just print the results at the end (no side effects), plus the match statement makes it a little cleaner

Comment: You might want ot read this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 91 bytes

```
s=>c=>{var r=s;for(int i=1;i<s.Length;)if(s[i++]!=c)r+="\n"+(s=s.Remove(--i,1));return r;};
```

Anonymous function which merges each line of output into a string and returns the result, since the function `may return an array of strings` instead of `will return`.

Full program with ungolfed method and test cases:

```
using System;

namespace CeeeeeeeeProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, Func<char, string>> f =
            s => c =>
            {
                var r = s;
                for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; )
                    if (s[i++] != c)
                        r += "\n" + (s = s.Remove(--i, 1));
                return r;
            };
            
            // test cases:
            Console.WriteLine(f("codegolf.stackexchange.com")('e'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Test Cases")('s'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Make a \"Ceeeeeeee\" program")('e'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Hello World!")('!'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Hello World!")('z'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("alphabet")('a'));
            Console.WriteLine(f("upperCASE")('e'));
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, an anonymous function with no return type which will print the output to stdout line by line will count **105 bytes**:

```
(s,c)=>{Console.WriteLine(s);for(int i=1;i<s.Length;)if(s[i++]!=c)Console.WriteLine(s=s.Remove(--i,1));};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>89</s> <s>88</s>  <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```bash
z=$1
for((;${#z}-n;)){
echo "$z"
n=${#z}
z=`sed "s/^\(.[$2]*\)[^$2]/\1/"<<<"$z"`
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19lq2LIlZZfpKFhrVKtXFWrm2etqVnNlZqcka@gpFKlxJVnCxbnqrJNKE5NUVAq1o@L0dCLVjGK1YrRjI4D0voxhvpKNjY2IOUJXLX///8PSS0uUXBOLE4t/l8MAA)

Note that you can't write just `$2` instead of `[$2]` in the regex; if you do that, it will work most of the time, but it will fail if the second argument is a special character like `*` or `/`.

*Edit: Thanks to @ckjbgames for 3 bytes.*

Comment: You could squeeze all the code on to one line and separate instructions with semicolons and save about 2 bytes.

Comment: @ckjbgames I thought that I only had newlines that replaced either a semicolon or a space, so it would be the same number of bytes (it's clearer with newlines, so I like doing that if doesn't cost any bytes). But it turns out that there was one extra newline that added an unnecessary byte, which I've taken out -- thank you.  It's just one byte though, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You could also remove the newline before the closing brace and save 1 more byte.

Comment: @ckjbgames That doesn't work -- try it out.  If you take out that newline, you need to replace it with a semicolon. (If it works for you, what version of bash are you using?)

Comment: Actually, it would not save a byte. Sorry for my mistake there.

Comment: I appreciate the one byte you did save me, and the correction of my misimpression that a semicolon or newline was needed after the `for((...))` construct, before the `{`.

Comment: Also, in your variable assignment at the beginning, you do not need to quote `$1`.

Comment: @ckjbgames Thank you -- I put that in to take care of, for example, an asterisk in the argument, but I forgot that pathname expansion isn't done on the right-hand side of an assignment statement.

Comment: In code golf, it is a good thing to know that, most of the time, you do not have to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 123 bytes

```clj
(fn[[f & p]l](loop[[n & m :as r]p a f](println(str a(apply str r)))(if m(recur(if(= n l)(rest m)m)(if(= n l)(str a n)a)))))
```

Definitely not optimal. I tried getting rid of the two `if`s in the `recur`, but the inclusion of a `let` made it bigger!

Loops over the string, popping the first char. If it equals the supplied character, it's added to the accumulator, and dropped from the remaining string.

```clj
(defn ceee [[first-char & rest-phrase] letter] ; Deconstruct the first letter off right from the parameter list

  (loop [[next-char & rest-remaining :as r] rest-phrase ; Deconstruct the remaining string apart
         acc first-char] ; Keep track of the letters to show at the start

    (println (str acc (apply str r))) ; Print the prefix accumulator, then the remaining phrase

    (if rest-remaining ; Recur if there's part of the phrase left
      (recur (if (= next-char letter)
               (rest rest-remaining)
               rest-remaining)
             (if (= next-char letter)
               (str acc next-char)
               acc)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 84 Bytes

a REGEX based answer

```
for($a=$argv[$c=1];$c;$a=preg_replace("#^(.+)[^$argv[2]]#","$1",$a,1,$c))echo"$a\n";
```

You can use the second input as REGEX for chars that are not removed

[Examples](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/089d4ea939ecf6528d696aa33a556bbc69c3fa3e)

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 102 bytes

An Anonymous function that takes input as two strings and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""s$,v$
For i=2To Len(s$)If Mid$(s$,i,1)<>v$Then?s$:s$=Mid$(s$,1,i-1)+Mid$(s$,i+1):i=1Fi
Next
?s$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcqxCsIwEIDhPU8Ryg2GxkIci9GtUFCnvkBMr@2hJuLFUp8@dtHth//7uKtj8jm34flORcGgZxBNfEmyuy7KE4YNg2oHeaYe1tSkjdofZugmDEeGmsH@ltG0Nar8y9KomqxpSFxwSWLVOfvY4xjvQ8XJ@RsufnJhxMrHh8Qv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ä▬ä+QÜ├┌9◘
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8e16842b519ac3da3908&i=%22e%22+%22codegolf.stackexchange.com%22%0A%22z%22+%22Hello+World%21%22%0A%22a%22+%22alphabet%22%0A%22e%22+%22upperCASE%22&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
Q       print the input string without popping
1:/     split after the first character, and push both parts separately
        e.g. "H" "ello World!"
c,-     remove instances of the character from the second part
m       for each remaining character, run the rest of the program and print the result
  |-    remove the first instance of the character
  b+    copy both strings on the stack and append
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Q+++%09print+the+input+string+without+popping%0A1%3A%2F+%09split+after+the+first+character,+and+push+both+parts+separately%0A++++%09e.g.+%22H%22+%22ello+World%21%22%0Ac,-+%09remove+instances+of+the+character+from+the+second+part%0Am+++%09for+each+remaining+character,+run+the+rest+of+the+program+and+print+the+result%0A++%7C-%09remove+the+first+instance+of+the+character%0A++b%2B%09copy+both+strings+on+the+stack+and+append&i=%22e%22+%22codegolf.stackexchange.com%22%0A%22z%22+%22Hello+World%21%22%0A%22a%22+%22alphabet%22%0A%22e%22+%22upperCASE%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>84</s> 79 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$c)$s
for(;++$y-lt$s.length){if($s[$y]-cne$c){($s=$s.remove($y--,1))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY49C8IwFEX3/orX8LANbQVn6SBFcHFScBCHUF9bMW1CUpVa@ttjwI/Nu91zz3C1epCxDUnpsMpHp4URbYw2xZKjDSpl4mWS4JDJHu1cUlf3DR8vlVeOOJyysiNvjr7mfjfUqjvFXs/SBefT5KZghhVEe7I9FMKSjcAGjL3pVlwJBLCCPmGgjar9gwjoa7GNP6fgoIw8hwzCP/z54zetyRSr3ZoBuRc)

Works by just chipping out a letter, starting at the 2nd, if it doesn't match and prints the resulting string; otherwise just increments i and this goes until it falls off. Had to use the case-sensitive -ne because PowerShell is insensitive by default. It takes a string and a char.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 195 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;c:char;i,j:word;begin readln(s);read(c);i:=2;while i<length(s)+1do begin if c=s[i]then i:=i+1 else begin writeln(s);for j:=i to length(s)do s[j]:=s[j+1];Dec(s[0])end;end;write(s)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDsIgFET3nuIv21SNuAS7c@cRmi4o/JZPEBpAe/xKrXExyUxm5s0yKelO46zW9S0jJJ5yJD8JxZWRUdDR8iVELQacyENEqZ2vUi02V6laEG@vYjHkEOjm0E/ZlLphOsB@oRFUmzrqs8GSeEsNA3QJf/0SKePOHEMEWwaQA/xRBZQ62/PCsA3rxR1VlbpLX6PXYtMXUIbFn9f1QV5LiNLr8DzC8MrQsIP8AA)

String is in first line of input, character is in second line of input.

Comment: 150, `var s:string;c:char;i:word;begin read(c,s);i:=2;while i<=length(s)do begin if c=s[i]then inc(i)else begin writeln(s);delete(s,i,1)end;end;write(s)end.`. Input `c` before `s`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), 271 bytes

```
.text
.globl main
main:
lw $4 8($5)
lb $10 ($4)
lw $8 4($5) 
move $9 $8
i:
move $4 $8
li $2 4
syscall
k:
move $4 $9
addi $9 1
lb $2 ($9)
beq $2 $10 k
beq $2 $0 e
l:
lb $2 ($4)
sb $2 1($4)
addi $4 -1
bge $4 $8 l
li $4 10 
li $2 11
syscall
addi $8 1
j i
e:
li $2 10
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU67EoIwEOzvK65IIYUOYeIM0NFQ2ckPgGQgciRqHB9fH5OIjM3N7t7e7tmLmp3b3eXrDruBTEc4t0pDGCXQE5nAfMP2CVCHjKe4YSKJeo4i6AizeUhkhVdAlQsTgZFClqEA@7anlgimv20Bbd@rcMZjcuaDiwQ6eQ04FE0rSVEClavN99sIecTfHIFbDt2wVCPFcoE@Z3mD8/WP70Xum8@oQJY/R/pzOOeO5mD0UOm@GVs92drcKqJmlLWyozMf)

I've realized when not doing syscalls, the 'a' and 'v' registers are free, which allowed me to save a few bytes. It's also a huge code smell, but this is code golf, so that's irrelevant. Takes the input via command-line arguments (I could do STDIN equivalent, but that costs more), and outputs to system out.

A detailed version that explains what all this does can be found [here](https://tio.run/##jVZdb9s2FH3Xr7ioDSQBHCNOXSzxkAF5WLECK1AsBfaw9YGWaIu1RLokFdW/Pjv3kpKV9mV@CCKRvB/nnHvEcDTty8us1qrSnnbO08cPn54oODKRDtb11NcqUq8vvKbKGbsnZSu81HiOtaZWGUu7rozGWTJhWRTLqL/HYrlv3LaR5aKYSdDK6WAvItXqWeOIlTNhQdsukrEhogbOWqtAjdrqJiyR6xRrTlpp66JGYhNrUnSxuaBWKxtQaavTllJZOqLCSNGhNIMorlSpLiu1Hr3be9VKB3s3bju6YHgbaudyN6i3NUeEjs7rQMrvSzmCf56HUHN1I@/makVe7w2q92gF@48afT3r5rQ8L@CoJtu1W6BW0c3129VCTr/qSsIu6Y@u5b4ac8AR1aIAZmWSQ1aQH1tdr5@1X3BRpas0mmp2Cwm0Mz5EWt1MaggM@4q2p6jxh7rAoPFeVcZONePOBdg1ZZ3xnTbKXXh9RJPactmIMl@n1Xc/9h5Maxrlm9OC5ndpz70E6AJOckvzmCPHFZCfJXQBlcU2r07kdvT29noLRaiqQvCgIYjgXjHJAMmhKCXwUoheVJrO8OJaemZRSXeckzeWtfJoHbKf7L2b7l1SUTQ993h3OX93RfKb4fFBtPDP7Zei2dIcKF/O18NyPZDSa@oVq7HWEnRBIDsBnvOhw/MiOsOJxqlqfEk771pOD1E7zrOUcu5oPS3nbihn9WVJf8ug7mVQcaZyMiBpLrhTD6VhYEw5aM6EIbXVIOY8Tjh90PpIqnZNxaWaCDxaBxGBSWQd8t8j//xuyW8BoLCTs0W2DoP/FEMaa@@6fT0haQEOdHngbCZBUXbeQ1sTbloVsSnFZX0ZKHVcZYJmvNKjSPYjCQVgLTAwDH7j3HHDgm70K3VE7gA7mRLbNc2GoWLest9gogxUaTa54/W043Xu@OkUStU0gS5dF49djIIb3G9B@ruJ0qGO5RVrnua31/NfCN5mLLYKORottMbq5LEo75RIEOKSLx69aUFac8ox0sSs0Xhj@HFN42@GxwfC0jqP7hscBgQqN/0mGR4wSGUv6fPPWsz4ABnPdiwCfDYKKSETjWBbwLEscogiw2/RM5b3rXDnOghmi1haW2449k54CBshBlXsTJ5BOXgmWwTDnwnhRah/RbxY2Lg9jXIOGWrno7bTJmBPKNb3XqgoZloh3DlZd0yAIGX6bIwuzCG3Gh6lWfRFcdjQ69/swAhtVTCMwgkQJ4VN1caJHuPl/P6KHh54eBfpgyJzYgfjNLb0WmCb3y/PWrtPeQqwY/hpJUZzSxIur231N37F9nNIVckQoR3xjmFwXAdc4Q8aqvzatcdBBVvYvbWMU6aei1@OUW9I514dFn1vAjxqh24RML46Qh92kuTn2c12wPNFSeoKCCzG24RNtjetStuKh7pofoK8EZ@XL0eCWb4h618Zr994Hvm/6@sRqPUIVJA3q4lHR3XQZ5dlM0hssFSY8xEjXn58//n3v3jmMhtrul6NHOwHb2hy6EpnQpM6QUnqVkr8XwzIZK/52z388qyvVsPcTWDhJHwZu2BwrO6H6WZ4IIEFJxt9ALkaPbVPuf/AWQKJeazyvUQcDp8bLiKTqEJpjBwVahn8i3/tRcbkjlZjRbg0Lia6ngzk8F3g@TqrBKF65UG7YEWVqfiSWLn8cZqc78VZLNs0Qc955rMPAOYqd9rj9oC2cY86DdCm@9C58@IrmR8EFjAlQIkVzgnUHndB@cDArXjKF2eBPn368BEG@a0zfEHsAmcT0Nn2h/uTyHVgQ7yF0czXx9vxusUp9Gag@Gag@OXl5cn96ez@0Vafa2UP4b3zj00Dz35vQv3i/gM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 108 bytes

Takes the string as the first line of input and the character as the second.

```
listen to S
listen to K
say S
cut S
roll S in F
while S
roll S in N
if N's K
let F be+N

join S in O
say F+O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 53 bytes

```ruby
->(a,c){puts a;puts a while a.sub! /(?!^)[^#{c}]/,''}
```

Ungolfed

```ruby
->(a,c) do # Define a lambda with 2 arguments, the string and the character
  puts a # output the string unchanged
  while( # Start a loop
    # continue until this replacement did not replace anything
    a.sub!( # replace in place
      # the first occurrence of the character in the string
      # other than the beginning of the string
      /(?!^)[^#{c}]/, 
      # with nothing
      ''
    )
  ) do
    puts a # if replaced something, output the remaining string
  end
end
```

The double `puts a` seems redundant and annoys me, but couldn't figure out a way to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Å<4R@Γ↓ α¿εN~;è<
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8f3c345240e21920e0a8ee4e7e3b8a3c&i=codegolf.stackexchange.com%0Ae%0A%0ATest+Cases%0As%0A%0AMake+a+%22Ceeeeeeee%22+program%0Ae%0A%0AHello+World%21%0A%21%0A%0AHello+World%21%0Az%0A%0Aalphabet%0Aa%0A%0AupperCASE%0Ae&a=1&m=1)

### Approach

It uses repeated application of a regex-based replacement with callback.  For example, if the target char is `e`, then it uses the regex `.[^e].*`.  In the callback, it removes the character at position 1.  It repeats this until no further replacement is possible.