# List all possible titles for the Anno games

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity

In the [Anno video game series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_(series)) there are 6 games with a 7th one announced for early 2019. Their titles always feature a year in a specific pattern:

`Anno 1602, Anno 1503, Anno 1701, Anno 1404, Anno 2070, Anno 2205, Anno 1800`

- The digital sum is always 9.
- The years are four digits long.
- They contain at least one zero.

Within these constrains there exist 109 possible titles:

```
[1008,1017,1026,1035,1044,1053,1062,1071,1080,1107,1170,1206,1260,1305,1350,1404,1440,1503,1530,1602,1620,1701,1710,1800,2007,2016,2025,2034,2043,2052,2061,2070,2106,2160,2205,2250,2304,2340,2403,2430,2502,2520,2601,2610,2700,3006,3015,3024,3033,3042,3051,3060,3105,3150,3204,3240,3303,3330,3402,3420,3501,3510,3600,4005,4014,4023,4032,4041,4050,4104,4140,4203,4230,4302,4320,4401,4410,4500,5004,5013,5022,5031,5040,5103,5130,5202,5220,5301,5310,5400,6003,6012,6021,6030,6102,6120,6201,6210,6300,7002,7011,7020,7101,7110,7200,8001,8010,8100,9000]
```

Your objective is to list them all in any reasonable form in the fewest number of bytes.

Comment: How flexible is the output format? Is [this](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/0jYlNdkoKbE4VaPC1jDV2Mow1UTH0EBTXdfEwrpCo7g0V6NS09bW0i4xJwfI0vz/HwA) acceptable?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that's fine with me.

Comment: Are [lists of digits](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//yLc0yLczckRT4oG8OSQ@4bqgxrLGh///) allowed?

Comment: Are large numbers of spaces between number acceptable? `1008       1017     1035...`

Comment: @aslum I assume you mean a lot of spaces, not just one, right? Comment markdown doesn't allow for a good representation of that. And I would assume that's allowed, given that Luis's format above is allowed. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, currently my code puts a space for every non-9-sum number... so 8 between the first and second result... 11 between third and fourth, and 899 spaces between last two... but as long as output goes to a standard web browser all duplicate spaces will be ignored, much like the spaces where ignored in my comment above.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'd say no to lists of digits because they really do not look like years anymore.

Comment: @aslum Excessive spaces are fine.

Comment: Hmm I stopped around Anno 1404, my assumption was that the difference between the titles is always 99 but then it would have been 2097 and 2196...

Answer (score 20):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> 51 bytes

Outputs the valid numbers as the *names* of a list of 201's. Why 201? Because ASCII 0 is 48, and 4*48+9 is... yeah. Saved 6 bytes by aliasing `^` to `Map` and another 2 by using `1:9e3` as range.

```r
"^"=Map;x=sum^utf8ToInt^grep(0,1:9e3,,,T);x[x==201]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XylOydY3scC6wra4NDeutCTNIiTfM68kLr0otUDDQMfQyjLVWEdHJ0TTuiK6wtbWyMAw9v9/AA)

## Explanation

```r
# Create list of sums of ASCII char values of numbers,
# with the original numbers as the names of the list
x <- Map(sum,
  # Create a list from the strings where each element is the string split 
  # into ASCII char values
  Map(utf8ToInt,
      # Find all numbers between 1 and 9e3 that contain a zero
      # Return the matched values as a vector of strings (6th T arg)
      grep(pattern=0,x=1:9000,value=TRUE)
  )
)
# Pick out elements with value 201 (i.e. 4-digits that sum to 9)
# This implicitly only picks out elements with 4 digits, since 3-digit 
# sums to 9 won't have this ASCII sum, letting us use the 1:9e3 range
x[x==201]
```

Comment: ah, `grep`, why do I never remember that it casts to `character`...

Answer (score 17):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
{grep {.ords.sum==201&&/0/},^1e4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Or0otUChWi@/KKVYr7g019bWyMBQTU3fQL9WJ84w1aT2f0FpiUKahuZ/AA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> 64 bytes

```python
print[y for y in range(9001)if('0'in`y`)*sum(map(ord,`y`))==201]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kulIhLb9IoVIhM0@hKDEvPVXD0sDAUDMzTUPdQD0zL6EyQVOruDRXIzexQCO/KEUHJKBpa2tkYBj7/z8A)

---

Saved:

- -1 byte, thanks to Luis felipe De jesus Munoz
- -2 bytes, thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kulIhLb9IoVIhM0@hKDEvPVXD0sDAUDMzTUPdQD0zL6EyQVOruDRXIzexQCO/KEUHJKBpa2tkYBj7/z8A) by using the `ord sum == 201` trick from other answers.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
9ȷṢ€æ.ẹ9ṫ19
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//Oci34bmi4oKsw6Yu4bq5OeG5qzE5//8)

#### How it works

```
9ȷṢ€æ.ẹ9ṫ19  Main link. No arguments.

9ȷ           Set the left argument and the return value to 9000.
  Ṣ€         Sort the digits of each integer in [1, ..., 9000].
    æ.       Perform the dot product of each digit list and the left argument,
             which gets promoted from 9000 to [9000].
             Overflowing digits get summed without multiplying, so we essentially
             map the digit list [a, b, c, d] to (9000a + b + c + d).
      ẹ9     Find all 1-based indices of 9.
             Note that 9000a + b + c + d == 9 iff a == 0 and b + c + d == 9.
        ṫ19  Tail 19; discard the first 18 indices.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```powershell
999..1e4-match0|?{([char[]]"$_"-join'+'|iex)-eq9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/39LSUk/PMNVENzexJDnDoMa@WiM6OSOxKDo2VkklXkk3Kz8zT11bvSYztUJTN7XQsvb/fwA)

Constructs a range from `999` to `10000`, then uses inline `-match` as a filter to pull out those entries that regex match against `0`. This leaves us with `1000, 1001, 1002, etc.` We then pipe that into a `Where-Object` clause where we take the current number as a string `"$_"`, cast it as a `char`-array, `-join` those characters together with `+` and `I`nvoke-`Ex`pression (similar to eval) to come up with their digit sum. We check whether that is `-eq`ual to `9`, and if so it's passed on the pipeline. At program completion, those numbers are picked up from the pipeline and implicitly output.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>78</s> 73 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

Returns a space-separated string.

```javascript
f=(n=9e3)=>n>999?f(n-9)+(eval([...n+''].join`+`)&/0/.test(n)?n+' ':''):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCsIwDADQX/FkEsoywVOEbh8iwspMZaMkYst@v@7wTm9PR6rrb/u2wfytveeIFkXvFCebRGTOaINQQD1SwSczWwB48e6bLWGh63gbuWltaDSfdYEHAJ366la9KBf/YEai/gc)

#### How?

We iterate over the range \$[1008..9000]\$ with an increment of \$9\$, ignoring numbers that don't have a \$0\$.

All these numbers are multiples of \$9\$, so the sum of their digits is guaranteed to be a multiple of \$9\$ as well.

Because valid numbers have at least one \$0\$, they have no more than two \$9\$'s, which means that the sum of the remaining digits is at most \$18\$. Therefore, it's enough to test if the sum of the digits is odd.

Hence the test:

```javascript
(eval([...n + ''].join`+`) & /0/.test(n)
```

Comment: You can save a byte changing the `1008` to `999`, since it doesn't contain a 0 anyway, and `999+9 = 1008`.

Comment: Or even 2 bytes by changing it to ``f=(n=9e3)=>n<1e3?'':(eval([...n+''].join`+`)<10&/0/.test(n)?[n,,]:'')+f(n-9)`` (does contain a trailing comma though, so ``f=(n=9e3)=>n<1e3?'':(eval([...n+''].join`+`)<10&/0/.test(n)?n+' ':'')+f(n-9)`` with space delimiter including trailing space might look prettier)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! I'm actually trying to update this for a while, but I have like 500B/s of Internet bandwidth where I am tonight. :/

Comment: I know the feeling.. Lately our internet at home is crap for some reason.. Can't download anything above 10 MB, and sometimes have to refresh videos or pages with 10+ images a few times before it completely loads.. Really annoying when I'm working from home on Mondays/Tuesdays.. >.> Tomorrow someone comes to fix it (and I'm not leaving him until it's fixed xD)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 89 bytes

```javascript
[...Array(9e3)].map(_=>i++,i=1e3).filter(a=>(s=[...a+""]).sort()[0]<1&eval(s.join`+`)==9)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpRCsIwDADQu@xDEqrB4dfADDzHKC7MKh21GWkZePqqv4@3yi5lsbjVU9ZHaIvmoilQ0he0iYhuZvKBIVzQ01s2uPMYnTtG7n9Ez5hqMBAeofC/i@s6j1TUKuB09tf@EHZJUGjVmGc3I/OADdsX)

- -4 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions

## JavaScript (Node.js), <s>129</s> <s>127</s> <s>126</s> <s>124</s> <s>115</s> <s>114</s> <s>111</s> <s>110</s> <s>105</s> <s>97</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```javascript
[...Array(9e3)].map(f=(_,i)=>eval(s=[...(i+=1e3)+""].sort().join`+`)-9|s[0]?0:i).filter(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpRCsIwDADQu@wroS5M/JpQxXOM4sJsJaM2oy0DwbtXfd9v5Z3LkmWrfdKHb4umotFT1Ce0iYhuOfMbRn9CRy/eIFi4HwTtxe8codj/ATH2@Bum6xwVzRWQVpU0mxn78VOmwV2HsyAFidVnCNiwfQE)

#### Explanation

```javascript
[...Array(9e3)].map(f=(_,i)=>eval(s=[...(i+=1e3)+""].sort().join`+`)-9|s[0]?0:i).filter(f)
[...Array(9e3)].map(f=(_,i)=>                                                  )           // Create a 9000-length array and loop over it; store the loop body
                                    [...(i+=1e3)+""]                                       // Add 1000 to the index and split it into an array of characters (17 -> ["1", "0", "1", "7"])
                                                    .sort()                                // Sort the array of characters in ascending order by their code points ("0" will always be first) (["1", "0", "1", "7"] -> ["0", "1", "1", "7"])
                                  s=                       .join`+`                        // Join them together with "+" as the separator (["0", "1", "1", "7"] -> "0+0+2+9"); store the result
                             eval(                                 )-9                     // Evaluate and test if it's different than 9
                                                                       s[0]                // Take the first character of the string and implicitly test if it's different than "0"
                                                                      |    ?0              // If either of those tests succeeded, then the number doesn't meet challenge criteria - return a falsey value
                                                                             :i            // Otherwise, return the index
                                                                                .filter(f) // Filter out falsey values by reusing the loop body
```

First time doing code golf in JavaScript. I don't think I need to say it, but if I'm doing something wrong, please notify me in the comments below.

- -3 bytes thanks to @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz
- -6 bytes thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: `[...Array(9e3)]` instead `Array(9e3).fill()` saves 2 bytes

Comment: `.map(a=>+a)` instead `.map(Number)` saves another byte

Comment: You can remove the space at `(_, i)` to save a byte, and `s[0]+s[1]+s[2]+s[3]` can be ``eval(s.join`+`)`` to save an additional 4 bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Whoops! No clue how I missed that space there. Also, the `eval` trick is nuts, thanks a bunch for that one.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the `||` can be `|` in your answer.

Comment: If you use `.map()` only to generate the range, and keep the filtering separate, you can save 8 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpRCsIwDADQu@xDEqrB4dfADDzHKC7MKh21GWkZePqqv4@3yi5lsbjVU9ZHaIvmoilQ0he0iYhuZvKBIVzQ01s2uPMYnTtG7n9Ez5hqMBAeofC/i@s6j1TUKuB09tf@EHZJUGjVmGc3I/OADdsX "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctRCsIwDADQ20hKNZv4tY8MPMcYNswoGbUZbRl4@up@H7yVdy5L1q1ekj2lLZaKRcFob2gTIt5z5i8McnMzfniDB40hePX@rHT9K740VsnANHZ9h1VKBXYn2TnC8XnG1TQFHxzR4JprPw). Although you should either add `_=>` to the beginning to make it a function or make this a REPL solution.

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##FctBCsMgEEDR2zQzSCfduphAz1GCGVItBjsGlUBPbxP4m794mxxS1xL3dtf89j3wGShba5GnFxE9S5EfKM70lR0cT2rYIoWYmi/Xj4@Rmq8NHN78IQku5cwwzLTlqItZkE/R16w1J08pfyAAYv8D) `(n=999)=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>n+=9).filter(_=>/0/.test(_)&eval([..._+''].join\`+\`)==9)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
n=999
exec"n+=9\nif'0'in`n`>int(`n`,11)%10>8:print n\n"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/W0tKSK7UiNVkpT9vWMiYvM03dQD0zLyEvwS4zr0QDSOsYGmqqGhrYWVgVFAGFFPJi8pS08v7/BwA)

*2 bytes thanks to Dennis*

Uses an `exec` loop to counts up `n` in steps of 9 as 1008, 1017, ..., 9981, 9990, printing those that meet the condition.

Only multiples of 9 can have digit sum 9, but multiples of 9 in this range can also have digits sum of 18 and 27. We rule these out with the condition `` int(`n`,11)%10>8 ``. Interpreting `n` in base 11, its digit sum is equal to the number modulo 10, just like in base 10 a number equals its digit sum modulo 9. The digits sum of (9, 18, 27) correspond to (9, 8, 7) modulo 10, so taking those`>8` works to filter out nines.

The number containing a zero is check with string membership. `` '0'in`n` ``. This condition is joined with the other one with a chained inequality, using that Python 2 treats strings as greater than numbers.

Comment: I like how heavily golfed Python seems to often have enormously long autogenerated executables...

Answer (score 4):

## sed and grep (and seq), <s>72</s> <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
seq 9e3|sed s/\\B/+/g|bc|grep -wn 9|sed s/:9//|grep 0|grep ....
```

Comment: Some of these aren't four digits long (but I'm not sure what the final `grep` is, so maybe I'm running it wrong?)

Comment: @Sparhawk: The last grep ensures that the number is 4 digits long

Comment: @Thor Ah right. For some reason I parsed that as an ellipsis.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0QhOrMm00a3OCO/3EbFLtpQT880zixWx8jA0Na2uDRXI60oP9c1rzQXKJmpqZOak5qroG6gnhn7/z8A), 55 bytes

```
[i|i<-show<$>[1..5^6],201==sum(fromEnum<$>i),elem '0'i]
```

Thanks to @Laikoni, see the comments.

Readable:

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

[i | i <- show <$> [1000..9999]
   , sum (digitToInt <$> i) == 9
   , '0' `elem` i
   ]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and Haskell golfing in particular! You can save a few bytes by dropping `(-48+)` and comparing the sum against `201` instead of `9`. Incidentally this also allows you to use `1` instead of `1000` for the range.

Comment: Also your previous version without `main=print` was fine as per [this consensus on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12945/56433).

Comment: `9999` can be `5^6` instead.

Comment: Ha, there's always another byte to shave! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 82 bytes

```r
write((x=t(expand.grid(1:9,0:9,0:9,0:9)))[,colSums(x)==9&!apply(x,2,all)],1,4,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVQ6PCtkQjtaIgMS9FL70oM0XD0MpSxwCBNTU1o3WS83OCS3OLNSo0bW0t1RQTCwpyKjUqdIx0EnNyNGN1DHVMdHSUlDT//wcA)

Generates a matrix `x` of all possible 4-digit numbers, excluding leading zeros, going down columns. Then filters for column (digital) sums of 9 and containing zero, i.e., not `all` are nonzero. `write` prints down the columns, so we `write` to `stdout` with a width of `4` and a separator of `""`.

[Outgolfed by J.Doe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174054/67312)

Comment: Nice answer! I came up with a different route...

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>20</s> 18 bytes.

*-2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy and @ETHproductions*

```
A³òL² f_=ì)x ¥9«Z×
```

---

```
A³òL² f_=ì)x ¥9«Z×  Full program
A³òL²               Range [1000, 10000]
      f_            Filter by : 
        =ì)         Convert to array 
           x ¥9     Sum equal to 9?
               «    And 
                Z×  Product not 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qYXB0//9BwrPDskzCsiBtcyBmX8KseCDCpTnCqVrDuDD//w)

Comment: This is actually [28 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QbPyI1x1MjMyOSBtcyBmX6x4IKU5qVr4MA==&input=). Using a literal integer instead is 22 bytes but `A³ò9000 f_ìx ¥9©ZsøT` gets you back down to 20.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `ì` instead of `s` and `¬`, which has to be done in the filter: `f_=ì)x ¥9...`. Then you can save another by checking if the product of Z is zero with `«Z×`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qYXB0//9BwrPDskzCsiBmXz3DrCl4IMKlOcKrWsOX//8 "Japt – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₄4°ŸεW°ö9Q
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*
-3 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9vc2FiaWX//@KChDTCsMW4ypJXwrDDtjlR//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
₄4°Ÿ        # Create a list in the range [1000,10000]
    ʒ       # Filter this list by:
     W      #  Get the smallest digit in the number (without popping the number itself)
      °     #  Take 10 to the power this digit
       ö    #  Convert the number from this base to an integer (in base-10)
        9Q  #  Check if it's equal to 9
```

- If the smallest digit is \$d=0\$ it will become \$1\$ with the \$10^d\$ (`°`). And the number in base-1 converted to an integer in base-10 (`ö`) would act like a sum of digits.
- If the smallest digit is \$d=1\$ it will become \$10\$ with the \$10^d\$ (`°`). And the number in base-10 converted to an integer in base-10 (`ö`) will of course remain the same.
- If the smallest digit is \$d=2\$ it will become \$100\$ with the \$10^d\$ (`°`). And the number in base-100 convert to an integer in base-10 (`ö`) would act like a join with `0` in this case (i.e. `2345` becomes `2030405`).
- If the smallest digit is \$d=3\$ it will become \$1000\$ with the \$10^d\$ (`°`). And the number in base-100 convert to an integer in base-10 (`ö`) would act like a join with `00` in this case (i.e. `3456` becomes `3004005006`).
- ... etc. Smallest digits \$d=[4,9]\$ would act the same as \$d=2\$ and \$d=3\$ above, with \$d-1\$ amount of `0`s in the 'join'.

If the smallest digit is \$>0\$ with the given range \$[1000,10000]\$, the resulting number after `°ö` would then be within the range \$[1111,9000000009000000009000000009]\$, so can never be equal to \$9\$. If the result is equal to \$9\$ (`9Q`) it would mean the smallest digit is \$d=0\$, resulting in a base-1 with `°ö`; and the sum of the digits was \$9\$.

Comment: `₄4°Ÿʒ0å}ʒSO9Q`. Splitting filters are usually shorter

Comment: @Emigna Ah, I was looking for a shorter way for the range, but completely forgot about `4°`. Thanks. And you're indeed right that multiple loose filters (at the end) are shorter. Will also add it to one of my tip answers. Thanks for both bytes!

Comment: A strictly hypothetical solution is `∞4úʒ0å}ʒSO9Q` (12 bytes), but I don't think it should count as valid so I'll leave it here as-is.

Comment: And my other 13-byter (inspired by the ord sum == 201 trick) is `4°Lʒ0å}ʒÇOт·-`. Leaving this here, maybe someone can golf it further

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Added it to the answer. Found another 13-bytes alternative as well: `₄4°ŸʒW_sSO9Q*`.

Comment: `₄4°ŸʒD0åôO9Q`. Using a single filter is usually shorter.

Comment: @Grimy Oh, very smart using the `ô` to convert the number to a list of digits right away!

Comment: Alternative 12: `4°LʒW.$ÇOт·-`. Sad `.$` is a two-byte built-in.

Comment: Nevermind, here's a 10: `₄4°ŸʒW°ö9Q`

Comment: @Grimy Dang.. I don't even recognize my own answer in it anymore, haha. Very impressive! You've even beat Dennis' 11-byter Jelly answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>128</s> <s>117</s> 115 bytes

```java
v->{int i=109,r[]=new int[i],n=i;for(;i>0;n++)if((n+"").chars().sum()==201&(n+"").contains("0"))r[--i]=n;return r;}
```

-11 bytes thanks to *@nwellnhof*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NZDPasMwDMbvfQqTw5BJY9LdhnFhD7BeCruEHDw3WZU5cvGfjFLy7JnTdheB9OkTv0@DnnQ1nH4WY3UI7EMj3TaMIcXO99p07LC290HTMgOfDk9s4jIP500uIeqIhh0YMbVM1f6WFxmqXf229U2rqPu9W7HdkkLZOw8S97WksuTYA1BZFFyYs/YBuAhpBK7Ua717@VccxYwUoKgLzn1TVZiPSt/F5Il5OS8rySV92QzxZJlWxDG74Bg90nfm1vyR4ngNsRuFS1FcshQtwZAfIFJEK96919cgonvYgIQBStZy/ow7L38)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                              // Method with empty unused parameter & int-array return
  int i=109,                      //  Index-integer, starting at 109
      r[]=new int[i],             //  Result-array of size 109
      n=i;                        //  Number integer, starting at 109
   for(;i>0;                      //  Loop as long as `i` is not 0 yet:
       n++)                       //    After every iteration, increase `n` by 1
     if((n+"").chars().sum()==201 //   If the sum of the unicode values of `n` is 201,
                                  //   this means there are four digits, with digit-sum = 9
        &(n+"").contains("0"))    //   and `n` contains a 0:
       r[--i                      //    Decrease `i` by 1 first
            ]=n;                  //    And put `n` in the array at index `i`
  return r;}                      //  Return the array as result
```

Comment: What about `chars().sum()==201`?

Comment: @nwellnhof Ah, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 85 bytes

(just competing for the best abuse of R square brackets ... :P )

```r
`[`=`for`;i[a<-0:9,j[a,k[a,w[a,if(sum(s<-c(i,j,k,w))==9&any(!s)&i)write(s,1,s='')]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoAgDADQs/RTG0yoT0tPIoESBSsqcIV0@uWDl1VjiD5ud44Th@RMP1raQ6KjLjVvIO8J4swCTDsdVBC9t226PmgEW8aS@VlBaCDxXYdzpfoD)

Comment: Holy for loops, Batman!

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 49 bytes

*6 bytes saved using a more convenient output format as suggested by [J.Doe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81549/j-doe).*

*Thanks to [@Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) for a correction*.

```matlab
y=dec2base(x=1e3:9999,10)'-48;x(sum(y)==9>all(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/0jYlNdkoKbE4VaPC1jDV2MoSCHQMDTTVdU0srCs0iktzNSo1bW0t7RJzcoAszf//AQ)

Comment: I don't know anything about Octave, but it looks like you can leave the `disp` off...

Comment: @J.Doe OP has confirmed that that output format is acceptable. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

## APL(Dyalog), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
1e3+⍸(0∘∊∧9=+/)¨⍎¨∘⍕¨1e3+⍳9e3
```

*-4 bytes thanks to @Adam*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L9hqrH2o94dGgaPOmY86uh61LHc0lZbX/PQike9fUACKNg79dAKiKrNlqnGIF3/FcCgAAA)

Comment: 29: [`1e3+⍸(0∘∊∧9=+/)¨⍎¨∘⍕¨1e3+⍳9e3`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L9hqrH2o94dGgaPOmY86uh61LHc0lZbX/PQike9fUACKNg79dAKiKrNlqnGIF3/FcCgAAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>69, 87 bytes</s> 74 bytes

<s>`for($i=999;$i<9001;$i++){echo((array_sum(str_split($i))==9&strpos($i,"0")!=0)?$i:" ");}`</s>
`for($i=999;$i++<1e4;)echo!strpos($i,48)|array_sum(str_split($i))-9?" ":$i;`

Note this puts a space for every "failed" number, leading to some kind of funky spacing. This can be changed to comma separation, but will add another 4 characters: `?$i.",":""`

Got bigger because I wasn't checking for 0. Derp. Shortened by 13 by Titus!

Comment: I don't really know PHP, but does this code ensure that each year contains a zero?

Comment: This code does not check for zero in the number.

Comment: 13 bytes shorter: `for($i=999;$i++<1e4;)echo!strpos($i,48)|array_sum(str_split($i))-9?" ":$i;`

Comment: Here´s another byte: `?"$i,":""` er ... now the other way round: `?"":"$i,"`

Comment: Actually @Titus that adds a couple bytes. We don't need quotes around $i unless we're including a string w/ it.

Comment: That´s for the comma separated version: `$i.","` has six bytes; `"$i,"` has five.

Comment: Fair enough, though OP said the huges amount of spaces was fine, so no need for the comma.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>46 42</s> 41 bytes

```ruby
?9.upto(?9*4){|x|x.sum==201&&x[?0]&&p(x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/395Sr7SgJF/D3lLLRLO6pqKmQq@4NNfW1sjAUE2tItreIFZNrUCjQrP2/38A)

#### How it works:

- Iterate on strings ranging from '9' to '9999'
- Check that sum of ASCII values is 201
- Check if string contains a zero (without regex, a regex would be 1 byte longer)

(Thanks Laikoni for -2 bytes)

Comment: `9*3` can be just `9`, because checking against 201 already requires 4 digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

```
{0Na&$+a=9}FIm,t*m
```

Use an ouput-format flag such as `-p` to get readable output. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/2sAvUU1FO9HWstbNM1enRCv3////ugUA)

```
{0Na&$+a=9}FIm,t*m
             m,t*m  Range from 1000 to 10*1000
{         }FI       Filter on this function:
 0Na                 There is at least one 0 in the argument
    &                and
     $+a             The sum of the argument
        =9           equals 9
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
Select[9!!~Range~9999,Tr@#==Times@@#+9&@*IntegerDigits]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z84NSc1uSTaUlGxLigxLz21zhIIdEKKHJRtbUMyc1OLHRyUtS3VHLQ880pS01OLXDLTM0uKY////69bUJSZVwIA)

We test the range from 9!! = 945 to 9999, since there are no results between 945 and 999. Maybe there's a shorter way to write a number between 9000 and 10007,  as well.

`Tr@#==Times@@#+9&` applied to `{a,b,c,d}` tests if `a+b+c+d == a*b*c*d+9`, which ends up being equivalent to The Anno Condition.

Comment: In retrospect, 9!! isn't any shorter than 999 or something, but it beats 1000.

Comment: What is 9!! ? In guessing it isnt related to factorials.

Comment: @RobertFraser Double factorial: `9*7*5*3*1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/),  <s>103 100</s>  96 bytes

```
f()=>List.generate(9001,(i)=>'$i').where((i)=>i.contains('0')&&i.runes.fold(0,(p,e)=>p+e)==201);
```

-3 bytes by setting the value in the array to string, making the conversion once and not twice

-4 bytes by using runes instead of codeUnits

Pretty self-explanatory. generates a list of 9001 (0-9000) cells with the cell's index as value, filters the ones containing a 0 then the one having an ASCII sum of 201 (The result if all the ASCII characters sum to 9). These conditions implictly include that the year is 4 digits long because using 2 ASCII numbers (and the 0), you cannot reach 201.

[Try it on Dartpad!](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/76525a5c2f46e9a22683ff7b4532f897)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. :)

Comment: Thanks ! Been lurking for a while, can finally participate

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (with `seq`, `grep`), 39 bytes

```bash
seq 0 9 1e4|egrep '([0-4].*){3}'|grep 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMFAwVLBMNWkJjW9KLVAQV0j2kDXJFZPS7PauFa9Bixm8P8/AA)

Comment: @xobzoo suggested `seq 0 9 1e4|awk '/([0-4].*){3}/&&/0/'` to save two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 22 bytes

```
55_&(|/~a)&9=+/a:!4#10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/9/UNF5No0a/LlFTzdJWWz/RStFE2dDg/38A)

Comment: Nice! `55_&9=+/y*|/'~y:!4#10` for 21?

Comment: @streetster thanks :) the `'` in `|/'` looks wrong. the result includes 1116, 1125, 1134, etc which are not supposed to be there

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
55↓⍸(×⌿<9=+⌿)10⊥⍣¯1⍳9e3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39T0UdvkR707NA5Pf9Sz38bSVhtIaRoaPOpa@qh38aH1ho96N1umGhOtEAA)

Comment: that use of `<` is clever. you can make it even shorter with `⎕io←0` and `(` `)10⊥⍣¯1⍳9e3` -> `(` `)¨,⍳4⍴10`

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) (<strike>76</strike> <strike>63</strike> <strike>61</strike> 56 bytes)

```
for(n<-0 to 9000;t=n+""if t.sum==201&t.min<49)println(t)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFRCkBAEADQq0w@RKIhP2I/HMAhFqtWu7ObHaXk7OO9tGmnJayn2RgWbQnMw4b2BHOMrxzhKmiqETjAgIgjK6qyzB7ATbq9Uh22OTfe0tQPZbwssaOCS/lEfg)

- Thanks to Laikoni for the suggestions
- Two more bytes shed after applying Jo King's comment

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Do you have an idea what needs to be added to the header or footer section to get this code to run on TIO? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAr4hEKJR46LKkt/4REhgLuUpu79@8DtOv9CSRXF9DYQUArgq89zvHrifSmBW7kpo5XeoH3sjW9a/ECPNwpLCBbS8Sm9F50VbkBw "Scala – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni, didn't know I could run Scala in TIO. Fixed it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It looks like `t.sum==201` works instead of `t.map(_.asDigit).sum==9`.

Comment: You may find our [tips for golfing in Scala](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala) interesting. E.g. it looks like `s"$n"` can be `n+""` and `s"$t "` can be `t+" "`.

Comment: Since you're using the sum is 201 trick, the range doesn't need to start at 999

Comment: @JoKing, thanks, I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
k1k2r'∑9=n0c∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJUIiwiIiwiazFrMnIn4oiROT1uMGPiiKciLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 77 bytes

```
time {if [incr i]>1e3&[regexp 0 $i]&9==[join [split $i ""] +] {puts $i}} 9999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaE6M00hOjMvuUghM9bOMNVYLbooNT21okDBQEElM1bN0tY2Ois/M08hurggJ7MEKKagpBSroB2rUF1QWlIM5NfWKlgCwf//AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 38 bytes

-1 byte and bug fixed thanks to Quintec

```
echo(#~(4#10)(0&e.*9=+/)@#:])1e3+i.9e3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19DuU7DRNnQQFPDQC1VT8vSVltf00HZKlbTMNVYO1PPMtX4/38A)

Thanks to Laikoni for findng an even bigger bug!

Comment: 1000 can be `1e3` for a byte saved, right?

Comment: (Also, should it be `9e3` instead of `9e4`?)

Comment: @Quintec Yes, sure. I tried it, but forgot it (golfing on the phone)

Comment: @Laikoni  As in my Red answer, I forgot this, sorry! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 16 bytes

Returns an array of digit arrays.

```
L²õì l4 k_×ª9aZx
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TLL17CBsNCBrX9eqOWFaeA==&input=LVE=)

---

### Explanation

```
L                    :100
 ²                   :Squared
  õ                  :Range [1,L²]
   ì                 :Convert each to a digit array
     l4              :Filter elements of length 4
        k_           :Remove each Z that returns truthy (not 0)
          ×          :  When reduced by multiplication
           ª         :  OR
              Zx     :  When reduced by addition
            9a       :   And subtracted from 9
```

Comment: OP has ruled that digit arrays aren't valid output unfortunately :o(

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 45 chars, 90 bytes

```
f←{⍵×⍳(0∊x)∧9=+/x←⍎¨⍕⍵}⋄f¨1e3..5e3⋄f¨5e3..9e3
```

test afther some formatting:

```
1008  1017  1026  1035  1044  1053  1062  1071  1080  1107  1170  1206  1260  
  1305  1350  1404  1440  1503  1530  1602  1620  1701  1710  1800  2007  2016  
  2025  2034  2043  2052  2061  2070  2106  2160  2205  2250  2304  2340  
  2403  2430  2502  2520  2601  2610  2700  3006  3015  3024  3033  3042  3051  
  3060  3105  3150  3204  3240  3303  3330  3402  3420  3501  3510  3600  
  4005  4014  4023  4032  4041  4050  4104  4140  4203  4230  4302  4320  4401  
  4410  4500 
5004  5013  5022  5031  5040  5103  5130  5202  5220  5301  5310  5400  6003  
  6012  6021  6030  6102  6120  6201  6210  6300  7002  7011  7020  7101  7110  
  7200  8001  8010  8100  9000
```

possible alternative

```
r←f;i;x
   r←⍬⋄i←1e3⋄→B
A: r←r,i
B: i+←1⋄→A×⍳(0∊x)∧9=+/x←⍎¨⍕i⋄→B×⍳i≤9e3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
ȷ4µṢÄm3Ḍ)ẹ9ṫ4
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//yLc0wrXhuaLDhG0z4biMKeG6uTnhuas0//8)**

#### How?

```
ȷ4µṢÄm3Ḍ)ẹ9ṫ4 - Link: no arguments
ȷ4            - literal 10^4 = 10000
  µ     )     - for each in range (1,2,3,...,10000): e.g. 3042       or  5211
   Ṣ          -   sort (given an integer makes digits)    [0,2,3,4]      [1,1,2,5]
    Ä         -   cumulative addition                     [0,2,5,9]      [1,2,4,9]
     m3       -   modulo 3 slice (1st,4th,7th...)         [0,9]          [1,9]
       Ḍ      -   convert from decimal digits             9              19
         ẹ9   - 1-based indices equal to nine             [9,99,999,1008,1017,...,8100,9000]
           ṫ4 - tail from the 4th index                   [1008,1017,...,8100,9000]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü┌o☻≈;╫▄mI░↨Z
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81da6f02f73bd7dc6d49b0175a&i=&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
VM      Constant one million
        this program produces its output pretty quickly, but takes much longer to end
f       filter the numbers [1..n] using the rest of the program as a predicate
  $     convert to ascii decimal string e.g. "1234"
  |+    sum of ascii codes
  201=  is equal to 201 [result a]
  _E:*  product of the decimal digits [result b]
  >     [result a] is greater than [result b]
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VM++++%09Constant+one+million%0A++++++%09this+program+produces+its+output+pretty+quickly,+but+takes+much+longer+to+end%0Af+++++%09filter+the+numbers+[1..n]+using+the+rest+of+the+program+as+a+predicate%0A++%24+++%09convert+to+ascii+decimal+string+e.g.+%221234%22%0A++%7C%2B++%09sum+of+ascii+codes%0A++201%3D%09is+equal+to+201+[result+a]%0A++_E%3A*%09product+of+the+decimal+digits+[result+b]%0A++%3E+++%09[result+a]+is+greater+than+[result+b]&i=&a=1)

Comment: @Laikoni: I read the challenge wrong, and missed that requirement.  I've updated my submission, at the cost of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
♫♪↨Ç{▒ε*\Σ8=┌
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pmr4pmq4oaow4d74paSzrUqXM6jOD3ilIz//w)

#### Explanation:

```
  ↨              Range from 
♫♪               1000 to 10000
   Ç{            Filter out by
     ▒ε*         The product of all digits is not 0
        Σ8=┌     The digit sum of the loop index (0 based) is not equal to 8
```

Comment: Does MathGolf have an `ord` command to transform characters/digits to unicode values? If yes, you might be able to use the same `ord sum == 201` trick other answers use, which covers both the `length == 4` and `digit sum == 9` at the same time.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Unfortunately, it doesn't, but I've requested it

Comment: @JoKing I'm a bit late to the party, but both of these things have been implemented, and have been submitted for pulling to TIO. check out the README for instructions. I've had a very stressful month, but I'm trying to get everything implemented.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 57 bytes

```javascript
for(y=0;y<9e3;)/(?=([0-4].?){3}).*0/.test(y+=9)&&print(y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38/z8tv0ij0tbAutLGMtXYWlNfw95WI9pA1yRWz16z2rhWU0/LQF@vJLW4RKNS29ZSU02toCgzD8jR/P8fAA)

---

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 58 bytes

```javascript
for(y=999;++y<1e4;9-p-q-r-s|q*r*s||print(y))[p,q,r,s]=''+y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADA52jpHoIuYr0kOkgZWGTrrgSCf7fmPqd7HW8UMANj2D3dT7x8ae14SJbZGGOVKtPgR2sAIQEB19RTz7UihZhl6boFddKkeZ2FUP/9AA)

<s>You may change `print` to `alert` to test it in your browser. :)</s>

Comment: Maybe the first time I realize that submitting a whole program is even shorter than a function in JavaScript...

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 37 bytes

```
x@&{9=+/x*0in x}'(4#10)\'x:1000+!9000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v8JBrdrSVlu/QssgM0@holZdw0TZ0EAzRr3CytDAwEBb0RJI/v8PAA)

On mobile, will add explanation later. Couldn't get `0 in'` to work without the lambda which wastes bytes...

Comment: 36 - `x@&9=+/+y*|/~+y:(4#10)\'x:1000+!9000`

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 140 bytes

```lisp
(defun x()(loop for x from 1008 to 9000 for y =(map'list #'digit-char-p(prin1-to-string x))when(and(member 0 y)(=(apply #'+ y)9))collect x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoMgEEWvMkkXDmlIcFcXHoYiKgkwE5ymcHpFd@/95H0Xw8HniYtffxkqKoxEDCsVqLAWSjAa8wEhmIwxz95gxmR56KXAa1jCFkS73RbNyCXkUQvpQzptUJX67z6jzQsmn76@gIGmcEbLHFvP310npRzF6J3cwfm8CODNFw)

Comment: This does not ensure that each year contains at least one zero.

Comment: Edited, i must have overlooked that

Comment: It looks like you can drop the space in `map 'list`. Also there are two trailing newlines that do not appear to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 52 bytes

```julia
f()=[x for x=1:9^5 if'0' in"$x"&&sum(Int,"$x")==201]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P01D0za6QiEtv0ihwtbQyjLOVCEzTd1AXSEzT0mlQklNrbg0V8Mzr0QHxNO0tTUyMIz971CckV@uANT6HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 33 bytes

```
t@&"0"=*'t@'<'t:$&201=+/'i:$!9001
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/7/EQU3JQMlWS73EQd1GvcRKRc3IwNBWW18900pF0dLAwOD/fwA)

Will edit with explanation later.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>95</s> 91 bytes

```c
f(i){char*c;for(i=1e4;--i;*c+c[1]+c[2]+c[3]-201||index(c,48)&&puts(c))asprintf(&c,"%d",i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjRCoIwFAbgVwmhcY5t0MyLYPQk4sX4dXWgpkwDQXv2pTffxQeDt4/PnAMJr3j5VMKFIZE8bF87Y8SVuKCx7U51cGtNdbXbJrHrF4Ku76zU@J0nArOfxiRxDqSgi3NXaGH3y/ucPl4i8RroiD8)

-4 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>66 79</s> 74 bytes

```
drop 55[x>>=show|x<-sequence.replicate 4$[0..9],sum x==9,elem 0x]
```

Damn you with your type juggling, you can treat numbers as strings :(

Basically just an exact description of whats asked here. Just no spaces.

[Try it online! (Modifications for it to *run* were necessary, tio doesn't support pure functions in Haskell.)](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoQwFAXQrdzCQkGDxVgIE1dgZykWQR8ok595CaaYvcdzTsU/0roUoy4LCZ/iEsNsIZDs48LBqFAfwXkMw5qnSfLpnn/@dkx3IruTCOT1tatI@FRrL8S4tZwMspRjS5oM@rw1pbw)

Comment: Nice approach, but unfortunately lists of digits are not valid output. However, there a few ways you can save some bytes to make up for the additional ones you need for the final conversion to a string. First of all, a list comprehension is shorter than `filter` and you can drop the second space in `elem 0 x`.

Comment: A few more: Instead of using `map` the conversion to string can be put into the list comprehension. `concat.map` is common enough that there exists a build-in called `concatMap`, however the overloading of the bind operator `=<<` on lists has the same effect and is even shorter.

Comment: The default bind operator is `(>>=)`, what you showed is the reverse bind operator.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 52 bytes

```
9001$*
.
$.`=>$.`;
>|\G\d
$*
M!`\d{4}(?==1{9};)
G`0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9LAwFBFi0uPS0UvwdYOSFhz2dXEuMekcAFFfRUTYlKqTWo17G1tDasta601udwTDP7/BwA) Explanation:

```
9001$*
```

Insert 9001 `1`s.

```
.
$.`=>$.`;
```

Replace each `1` with the number of `1`s to its left, followed by `=>`, followed by the same number again, followed by `;`.

```
>|\G\d
$*
```

Convert `>` and subsequent digits to unary, thus calculating the digit sum.

```
M!`\d{4}(?==1{9};)
```

List all the 4-digit numbers with a digit sum of 9.

```
G`0
```

Keep those that contain a zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ȷ4ȷrDS9Ƒ>ẠƲƇḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//yLc0yLdyRFM5xpE@4bqgxrLGh@G4jP//)

-2 (yucky, yucky trivial) bytes thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 109 bytes

```
repeat n 8000[s: 0 p: 1 foreach t form d: 1000 + n[s: s + r: do t - 48 p: p * r]if all[s = 9 p = 0][print d]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMwDAS/sueGgAo5JIZ8olejg4kUGkgdI/v/rnwbZmdNpX9UInfToqkhYyWiWAMIJeCN8zFNxxdt0A/izgNMyCOqDhYgj@8zlnV8Cl4wvk6k@44VOzZXO4hjsSs3CHPvfw)

Comment: @Laikoni Sorry, apparently I've missed that part. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
f&}\0Tq201sCMT`M^T4
```

Output is an array of strings. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%26%7D%5C0Tq201sCMT%60M%5ET4&debug=0).

```
f&}\0Tq201sCMT`M^T4   
              `M^T4   Array of strings of numbers 0-999
f                     Keep the elements of the above, as T, where:
           CMT          Get the code points of each character in T
          s             Take the sum
      q201              Does the above == 201?
  }\0T                  Does T contain "0" ?
 &                      Logical AND the two previous results
```

The 201 trick is the same as used in other answers.

Previous answer, without using 201 trick, 22 bytes: `iRTf}0Tfq9sTjRTr^T3^T4`

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 114 bytes

```php
<?php
for($i=1e3;$i<=9e3;$i++)
    if(array_sum($a=[$i/1e3%10,$i/100%10,$i/10%10,$i%10])==9&in_array(0,$a))
        echo $i.' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhLb9IQyXT1jDV2Fol08bWEkxra2tmpmkkFhUlVsYXl@ZqqCTaRqtk6gMVqRoa6IBYBgZwFoQBJGM1bW0t1TLz4sEaNYCiiZqaqckZ@QoqmXrqCurW//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog 117 bytes

`b(X):-between(0,9,X).
w(X):-write(X).
y():-b(A),b(B),b(C),b(D),X is A+B+C+D,X=9,(A=0;B=0;C=0;D=0),w(A),w(B),w(C),w(D).`

Comment: Would you consider adding a link to a service like [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvNCsMgEITvfQqPK67Ba1qk@PMQ3kqltgiSlCSw5OmtW5gZmGG@77a29aN3qr1nSPKqczmolAUMzpjkdKH/Sls9CnA/gU/gJGbwHIEjSkyi7sIpr4KKmOyM4Ky5@eEwHK2RSIwRY8QYDWzqdy3edXk9W4MTxdBjjD8 "Prolog (SWI) – Try It Online") - (link is to your code, but I'm not sure if the footer is right since I don't prolog much.)?

Comment: [98](https://tio.run/##PcjdCkAwGAbgc1chpay9n@wQSfu5CIUTNVoJoXb5o5Ses@c493Vf6PIuBOoqmuztrd2yAiU6lkftP@IdyUAKpEEGZeyuWHLFNTfwp7vtnCWp/wxbgl5CQcOMDEUjatGIPIQH)

Comment: [91](https://tio.run/##JcndCkAwGAbgc1exlKK9n@wQof1chMKJGq2EULv8UXoOn/M6tmOl27sQqK9oto@3dk8LlOizPOqIkQQpkAYZyPYL5m4mueKaG/jLPXZJ48T/xj3GIKGgYaYMRSNq0Yg8hBc)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 35 bytes

```
echo@>55}.I.(4#10)(*/<9=+/)@#:i.1e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I9/BztS0Vs9TT8NE2dBAU0NL38bSVltf00HZKlPPMNXk/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 106 bytes

```cs
for(int i=999;++i<9999;)if(i.ToString().Sum(c=>c-'0')==9&&i.ToString().Contains("0"))Console.WriteLine(i);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEAV/ZemhzSINvYYYQbzqqYLnElNZaBPMpoKUfnuMN7294cEwllsbossLk39A/@bkZg2/JM/knxrsNDDDEVbgNCSy8Ap0h8tAXiCseQxRkE9ARimldzvaq@9AGgXJa@hTLEaBsl9mYc3Btk3XoDGqrv/uU/CpKFlUXYVYiMPk5C1SciXDCUKdty1/AA)

Ungolfed:

```cs
for(int i = 999; ++i < 9999;)               // from 1000 to 9999 (fulfills four digit parameter)
    if(i.ToString().Sum(c => c - '0') == 9  // if the sum of the digits is nine
            && i.ToString().Contains("0"))  //   and if the year contains at least one zero
        Console.WriteLine(i);               // write the year to the console
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum`, <s>40</s>  32 bytes

```perl
map/0/*9-(sum/./g)||say,1E3..9E3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUDfQF/LUlejuDRXX08/XbOmpjixUsfQ1VhPz9LV@P//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDYC0T2ZxiZVVaElmji1QFwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 58 bytes

jrook's solution is currently 2 byte shorter

```
val v=(9 to 9000).filter(x=>(x+"").min<49&(x+"").sum==201)

val v=(9 to 9000).map(_+"").filter(x=>x.min<49&x.sum==201)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LccxCoAgFADQvVN8GkIJxKJFyKCjWBkYppI/EaKz29LbXlyVVcUvh14RPOiM2m0R5hDgKUlZSJIIQA@Cc07Zbizqi2Q5kdzWNWWnceMgmn/xPqXseUdLuIxDkmj1lg8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 37 bytes

```
{{Sum@Ords@_=201and"0"in _}@S\1:9000}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7@6Org018G/KKXYId7WyMAwMS9FyUApM08hvtYhOMbQytLAwKD2f0BRZl5JdFp0bOx/AA)

Based on the [perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174063/31957).

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 59 bytes

Lambda that returns a `List<Int>` containing every valid year.

```
{(1008..9000).filter{"$it".sumBy{it-'0'}==9&&'0' in "$it"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEEX3PcWnSJssGsadFdOFO8FLdGFhMJ1KOxUk5Owx@lcPHrz/XDSw5PcYMIosZxiLbsCdN73cRAf4HM2R6ORcT0TWTRz0scb6wFq7bZ@vn8jatdQm7/umKQAW/HVKedoF88hSqrFC2Wtl0SDmd2asrRLyFw)

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~

```
{iiiii}dcdcc{i}ddc{d}iiicdciciiiiiicddddddcdciiciiiicdddddcdciiiciicddddcdciiiiccdddcdciiiiicddcddcdciiiiiicddddcdcdc{i}dddcddddddccdc{i}ddc{d}iiciccdc{i}dddcddddddcciiiiiic{d}iiicicicddciiiiiicdddddciciiiicddddddciciicdddciiiiicddddciiciicdddddciciiicddddciiiicdddciiiccddddciciiiicdddddciiicddciiiicddcdddciciiiiicddddddciicdciiiiicddddcddciciiiiiic{d}iiicicciiiiiicddddddcdcic{i}dddc{d}iicciicddcc{i}dddcdddddcddciciiiiicddddcddciiciiicdddcddciiicicddcddciiiicdcdcddciiiiicdddccddciiiiiicdddddcicddc{i}dddc{d}iiiciicdcdciiiiiicddddcdciiiiicddddddciiccddciiiiicdddcciiicdddddciicicdddciiiicddcicicddddciiciicddddciiicdciicdcdddciiciiicdddddciicciiicdddcddciiciiiicddddddciciciiiicdddddcdciiciiiiic{d}iiicciiicdddcciiiiiicdddcdddciciiiicddcdddciiciicdcdddciiicccdddciiiicddcicdddciiiiicddddciicdddciiiiiicddddddciiicddcdciiiiicddcddciiiicdddddciiicdcddciiiicdcdciicddddciiiccdddciiiccccdddciiicicddddciicicicddcddciiiciicdddddciciiciicddddcdciiiciiicddddddcciiiicddddcciiiiicdcddddciciiiccddddciicicicddddciiicdciicddddciiiicdddciiicddddciiiiicdddddciiiicdddcdciiiiccdddciiicddddciiiicddcddciiicicddcicdddciiiicdcdddciiciicdcdcddciiiiccddddciciiiccdddcdciiiicicdddddcciiiiicdddddcciiiicicdddddciciiciicdddddciicciiicdddddciiicddciiiicdddddciiiicddddciiiiicddddcdciiiciicddddciicdddciiiiicdddcddciiciiicdddccddciiiiicddcdddciciiiicddcddcdciiiiicdcddddcciiiiiicddddddcciiiciiicddddddciciciiiicddddddciicdciiiiicddddddciiicdddciiiiiicdddddcdciiciiiicdddddcicddciiiiiicddddcddciciiiiicddddcdcdciiiiiicdddcdddcc{i}dddc{d}iiicciiciiiiic{d}iiicicciiiiiic{d}iiiciicddc{i}dddcddddddcdciciiiiiicddddddccdc{i}dddcdddddcddcc{i}ddc{d}iiccic{i}dddc{d}iicicdc{i}ddc{d}iiicdcc{i}dc{d}iccc
```

Do I need the spaces?

Comment: Yes, there should be some delimiter between the years such that they are easily recognizable.

Comment: Also please add the byte count of your answer to the header and, if you want, add a TIO link: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVLdsQwCDtRD9Un2lfWs8ybs6d2bAwSbbKIPwwIIRj7@rRvf/183Pfl83kbDLjG13DZe5yMveO5G8vnmSfrCLmfB8idA7meF8jdsbMVyMJvHKzIcHSL7WBDm6@R1wAbPwhYKIET67aO4zQFmq9tiMznEHOCOSiQFeoO4s5l5LiyXthAiUNiIbJYgDe4oHmZ4ayX0R9EmVHoRUurkqYobitBSK43ZGUcW1FPIMpiO6ectJQqOhC3qJjSTykjCpgstWDuajGh7miB5a1aoVrU/EvosyxM1UKyUrnHUABlcASmImGIc6pD074xA@W2trb2Damw6oBJP6QovHAeQQkBXzm3sLMIvdei5SQjS2eE9FdVfBNUigAm4jv98a@K28xIYrlZdeTq3OsTgvp4pcHN3vrH23itI6LMK8nQ2qyiMa4DznnMe/zhPNvREff9Cw)