# Repeat every other character in string starting with second character

Tags: code-golf, string

**Requirements:**

- Take a single word as input with only lowercase alphabetical characters (a-z)
- Output a string where every other character is repeated, with the first repeated character being the second character in the string

**Example:**

Input: `abcde`

Output: `abbcdde`

**Winning Criteria:**
Standard code golf. Shortest number of bytes in program wins.

**Clarification:**
For languages with 1-based indexing the output must still match the above, `aabccdee` is **not** an acceptable solution.

Comment: May we start from `1` as the first character, for the benefit of languages with `1`-based indexing?

Comment: Sure, i just called the first character 0th so my title "repeat odd index characters" makes sense. As long as you the output is repeating "Every other" character starting from the second character I the string (which I call index 1) then it's acceptable

Comment: i'll update the post to reflect that

Comment: To clarify, what I'm suggesting is that `aabccdee` is also a valid output for your lone testcase.

Comment: that is not acceptable

Comment: Is trailing white space permitted?

Comment: The title seems too long, I guess it can be shortened to just `Repeat every other character`.

Comment: I suggest you use standard I/O rules instead of requesting to use stdin (and never saying to use stdout, by the way). Or is there some reason to avoid it?

Comment: Also, python answer is already a function that actually uses argument for input and return for output, so I'm assuming that you actually allow default I/O ways and are not restricting to stdin.

Comment: @val i wasn't aware of the standard io rules, this is my first submission. Feel free to edit the post with the "community standard"

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand the requirements. I'm not a native english speaker so maybe that's the problem : what does "every other character" means here ? 'Other' compared to what ? My understanding of the phrase "every other character" means to me that "abbccddee" is the right answer to the example...

Comment: @Neyt "Every other" is an English phrase that could mean all but one exception but in this case it does not.  It is similar to "alternating", for example "every other day" means "either all even days and no odd days or all odd days and no even days".  I don't think there is really any logic to it.  If you are still confused the ESL stack exchange is probably the place to ask about this further.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter Indeed, I don't see any logic behind this but thanks and good idea to post it on ESL (if not already) ^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḤÐe
```

A full program accepting a string which prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiWHJ6T@//9fPTEpOSVVHQA)**

#### How?

Utilises the fact that the implementation of the double atom, `Ḥ`, is multiplication by two, and that strings are lists of Python characters. In Python when a character is multiplied by two it becomes a Python string of length two (e.g. `'x'*2=='xx'`). Lastly the implicit output of a list composed entirely of characters and strings (or lists thereof) is its content all smashed together.

```
ḤÐe - Main Link: list of characters  e.g. input abcd -> ['a','b','c','d']
 Ðe - apply to even indices (1-indexed):
Ḥ   -   multiply by 2                     -> ['a', 'bb', 'c', 'dd']
    - implicit, smashing print            -> abbcdd
```

Answer (score 18):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 12

```
s/.(.)/&\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfT0NPU18txlA//f//xKTklNR/@QUlmfl5xf91iwA)

Comment: This is really lovely

Answer (score 14):

## brainfuck, 13 or 11 bytes

```
>,[.,[..,>]<]
```

Assumes EOF->0. :(

You can [try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTidaD4j0dOxibWL//09MSk5JTQMA)

(Assuming input also continues to give zeroes indefinitely after the first EOF, we can do it in 11 bytes:

```
,[.,[..>],]
```

though this eats memory.)

Comment: You may assume infinite time and memory for the purposes of code golf.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the "infinite time and memory" because BOGO sorting would be "allowed", which would be ridiculous. Imagine if a "check if a string is an anagram of another string" formula was "shuffle the second string, compare, and continue if unequal. If 2^n days have passed, where n is the length of the string, consider the strings non-anagrams". It would have an error rate less than the expected failure of a CPU while running a typical program.

Comment: @Mathgeek CPU failure is not usually a consideration for code golf, whereas program determinism is. And the expected runtime for Bogosort is O(n!), not O(2^n).

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[:2]+s[1:2]+f(s[2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0WhONrKKFa7ONoQRKVpFEcbWcVq/k/LL1IoVsjMU4hWSlTSUUpMAhPJEDIFSqUqxVpxKRQUZeaVKAB1av4HAA)

Takes the first two characters, then the second character, then removes the first two characters and recurses.

---

**39 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,c=2:s and s[:c]+f(s[1:],3-c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoVgn2dbIqlghMS9FoTjaKjlWO02jONrQKlbHWDdZ839afpFCsUJmnkK0UqKSjlJiEphIhpApUCpVKdaKS6GgKDOvRAGoW/M/AA)

Flips between taking the first two or first one character.

Comment: I really like these two answers, tbh

Comment: Oh, nice; two at a time!

Comment: I posted a [37 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199784/3852).

Answer (score 10):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>14</del> 12 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: b401 cd21 f7d9 78f8 cd29 ebf4            ...!..x..)..
```

**Unassembled:**

```
    START: 
B4 01   MOV  AH, 1      ; DOS read char from STDIN 
CD 21   INT  21H        ; put char in AL 
F7 D9   NEG  CX         ; toggle CX sign
78 F8   JS   START      ; if negative, loop to next char 
CD 29   INT  29H        ; DOS write char to screen again 
EB F1   JMP  START      ; loop until break/^C
```

A standalone executable DOS program.  Input via `STDIN` (pipe or keyboard interactive), output to `STDOUT`.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes (xnor's improvement)

```python
lambda s:`[c*11for c in s]`[7::10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiE6WcvQMC2/SCFZITNPoTg2IdrcysrQIPZ/QVFmXolGmoZ6YlJySqq6puZ/AA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
lambda s:`sum(zip(s,s,s),())`[7::10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKqG4NFejKrNAo1gHCDV1NDQ1E6LNrawMDWL/FxRl5pVopGmoJyYlp6Sqa2r@BwA)

Slices characters 7, 17, 27… out of a string like this:

```python
('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e')
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
       ^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^
→ abbcdde
```

xnor's `c*11` trick achieves the same thing, but with a string like:

```python
['aaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccccc', 'ddddddddddd', 'eeeeeeeeeee']
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
       ^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^         ^
→ abbcdde
```

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(c*3for c in s)[1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYSl1dLys/M08jWcs4Lb9IIVkhM0@hWDPa0MrKKPZ/QVFmXolGmoZ6YlJySqq6puZ/AA)

If returning a tuple of characters is OK (which it isn't), `lambda s:sum(zip(s,s,s),())[1::2]` is a 33-byte solution.

Comment: What a clever idea! I've posted a bounty and will keep it up for the week.

Comment: It looks like you can save more bytes with a different string to slice, though interestingly also sliced `[7::10]`: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiE6WcvQMC2/SCFZITNPoTg2IdrcysrQIPZ/QVFmXolGmoZ6YlJySqq6puZ/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
#~1 2$~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/lesMFYxU6pT/a3KlJmfkK6gnJiUlp6SkqivoWimkgbjJQM5/AA)

- `1 2$~#` Shape `$~` the list `1 2` (repeating it cyclically as needed) until it matches the length `#` of the input.
- `#~` Use this `1 2 1 2...` "mask" to Copy `#~` the implicit input elementwise.  That is, make 1 copy of the first char, 2 copies of the 2nd char, 1 copy of the third char, etc.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <s>33</s> 24 bytes

By noticing that obviously `f [] = []` also fits the pattern `f s = s` and removing one extra space, we get to

```
f(a:b:s)=a:b:b:f s
f s=s
```

from my starting point of

```
f []=[]
f (a:b:s)=a:b:b:f s
f s=s
```

Now my answer matches xnor's Haskell answer.

You can [try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SrJqljTFkQlWaUpFHMBsW3x/9zEzDwFW4WC0pLgkiKfPAUVheKM/HIglaaglJiUnKL0HwA).

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:t)=a:b:b:f t
f s=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SrJqkTTFkQlWaUplHClKRTbFv/PTczMU7BVyE0s8FUoKC0JLinyyVNQAfEV0hSilRKVdJQSk8BEMoRMgVKpSrH//yWn5SSmF//XTS4oAAA)

Comment: This feels pretty similar to mine and now I feel stupid if I don't golf mine further. But then we'll have equal answers... So what now?

Comment: @RGS [That's fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/20260), go for it. Duplicate answers come up a fair bit here and are a good sign that the mutually found solution is indeed well-golfed.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 16 bytes

```matlab
@(s)s(1:2/3:end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1izWMPQykjf2Co1L0Xzf5qGemJSckqquuZ/AA)

#### Explanation

Non-integer values are [automatically rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455299/does-matlab-accept-non-integer-indices) (with a warning) in colon index expressions.

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
q3e*1>2%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9A4TavY0M5I9f//xKTklFQA)

### Explanation

```
  abcde             q     read input
→ aaabbbcccdddeee   3e*   repeat characters x3
→  aabbbcccdddeee   1>    drop first 
→  a b b c d d e    2%    every other char
```

Esolanging Fruit saved 1 byte: `3f*s` → `3e*`.

Comment: Can you use `3e*` instead of `3f*s`?

Comment: It seems so! Good eye.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>43 41</s>  39 bytes

-2 thanks to mypetition (`s[:1]*i` can be `s[:i]` if we swap our order of `i`s)

```python
f=lambda s,i=2:s and s[:i]+f(s[1:],i^3)
```

A recursive function which accepts a string and returns a string.
Works in Python 2 too.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoVgn09bIqlghMS9FoTjaKjNWO02jONrQKlYnM85Y839BUWZeiUaahnpiUnJKalp6RmZWtrqm5n8A)**

At each call we return `s` if it is empty or take the first *up-to-i-characters* of the given string (`s[:i]`) where `i` starts out as `2` and append (`+`) the result of another call to the function this time using a new `s` of all but the first character (`s[1:]`) and a new `i` found by XOR-ing with three (`i^3`) - i.e. `2, 1, 2, 1, ...`

Comment: Really clever way of switching between 1 and 2!

Comment: `f=lambda s,i=2:s and s[:i]+f(s[1:],i^3)` saves 2 bytes

Comment: @mypetlion Good golf, thanks!

Comment: @mypetlion ...and it's just a short step from there to realising we can drop `i` entirely, which gives xnors `f=lambda s:s and s[:2]+s[1:2]+f(s[2:])`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
+pVu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=K3BWdQ&input=ImFiY2RlZmdoaWpsa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiI)

```
+pVu     :Implicitly map each character U at 0-based index V in the implicit input string
+        :Append to U
 p       :U repeated
  Vu     :  V mod 2 times
         :Implicit output of resulting string
```

Comment: What does the `-m` flag do?

Comment: @S.S.Anne, it enables the implicit map  mentioned in the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

## Scratch 3.0, 25 blocks/179 bytes

[image: Blocks]

As SB Syntax:

```
define f(n
set[i v]to(1
set[o v]to(
repeat((length of(n))/(2
set[o v]to(join(o)(letter(i)of(n
change[i v]by(1
set[x v]to(letter(i)of(n
set[o v]to(join(o)(join(x)(x
change[i v]by(1
```

Oh boy, here I go Scratching again! This was quite an interesting one to solve, and I quite enjoyed it. Thanks for the challenge.

The output of the function is shown in the top left corner.

Finally, [Try it on<s>line</s> Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/364315112/)

Comment: I really like this. Thabk you for the submission

Comment: 124 bytes.[TIO](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/364343020/) block syntax:http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&lang=en&script=define%20f(n%0Aset%5Bi%20v%5Dto(0%0Aset%5Bo%20v%5Dto(%0Arepeat(length%20of(n%0Achange%5Bi%20v%5Dby(1%0Arepeat((2)-((i)mod(2%0Aset%5Bo%20v%5Dto(join(o)(letter(i)of(n

Answer (score 5):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), 43 bytes

> '"""""'"""'""""'"'""""""""""'"'"'""""""""""

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X10JBNShGEhABJRgHCTu//@JSckpqQA)

Displayed here in variable-width font, per the traditional tribute to the language name.

Exits with error after printing the correct output.

Explanation:

```
'"""""'"""      while(1)
'""""           do 2 things:
'"'""""""""""   print(read stdin)
'"'"'"""""""""" print(print(read stdin))
```

Uses the fact that `'"` both prints and returns its argument, which can thus be directly fed to a 2nd print command.

Comment: That's definitely unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
3•y
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3%E2%80%A2y&inputs=abcde&header=&footer=)

```
3•  # Repeat each character three times
  y # Get every other character
```

Answer (score 4):

## Brainfuck, <s>52</s> 31 bytes

```
,[>>+<[<..>->-]>[<<.>+>->]<<<,]
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/l@jkJlXoFCjkFuaUwKkEksrgGRqXsp/nWg7O22baBs9PTtdO91Yu2gbGz07bSA71sbGRif2///EpOSU1DQA) or you can check my first submission, that I think is also simpler to understand:

```
+>+>>,[<<[-<->]<[->>+>>+<<<<]+>>>.>[-<.>]<,<[-<+>]>
```

Cell layout is

```
| 1 | aux | mult | inp | mult |
```

where mult is the number of extra times we have to print the current character. Feel free to drop me a line in the comments with feedback.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUpLCoAgFLyK@6dCe5mLiAu1BKkkIqGFd389oVnMP92xttLzzkMtaqjYX@GzH49IbdcfmECA9s554wyCCGZDThDEwEIWK4ueF0JAYI4pr1v5AA)

Answer (score 4):

## k4, <s>17</s> 13 bytes

edit: make use of `&` (where operator) which for each index i of an int-list L give gives L[i] copies of i. eg `&2 1 3` -> `0 0 1 2 2 2`

```
{x@&(#x)#1 2}
```

```
{           } /lambda with implicit arg x
    (#x)      /count x
        #1 2  /takes #x items of 1 2 (eg 3#1 2 -> 1 2 1)
   &          /&1 2 1 -> 0 1 1 2 
 x@           /index x
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 126 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Page and Ajax]Ajax:Open mind.Speak thy.Open mind.Speak thy.Speak thy.Let usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7I@f9fR88xK7FCRy8gMT0VyE4uUfC00gtOTs1LBTGiXStSS/NKYqNd80pSixRAihQS81IUQHpiQYSVf0FqnkJuZl6KXnBBamK2QklGpR42MQTLJ7VEobQYbJPe//@JSckpqQA)

Page reads the input one character at a time, and alternately prints it once or twice. Exits with error after printing the correct output.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>54</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

This looks incredibly long, I have no idea if something obvious is slipping under my nose... And already saved 5 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan! Check [his 43 byte Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198720/75323)! but here it is:

```
lambda s:''.join(c+i%2*c for i,c in enumerate(s))
```

You can [try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQqwxCqBUtahNBN2njlyZyFLVFp7fe8qW3npGWNeXmYYej3Spoq6BsnE9XRBJmwG7uDfiYAUcDSODoCS6r6kSRsqWMVIUXTGljHfvnAw)

Comment: Save 2 with `enumerate` and 2 more by using a generator (dropping the `[]`) - [TIO](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQqwxCNFYE1SaCbtLG/NBEjaK26PTWW77w5sPzNIdYHKywlUvdu1GQlrruT0@MusGhpWqUzkegTgMxWH5uG1W2mKQsIRJndCjUro0V/3w)

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for the tip!

Comment: Oh, another 1 by distributing over the addition and reordering to avoid `%` being treated as a format instruction: `c*(1+i%2)`->`i%2*c+c` (or `c+i%2*c`)

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 84 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
S	S LEN(1) . L LEN(1) . R REM . S	:F(O)
	O =O L R R :(S)
O	OUTPUT =O S
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNYwdbTLyA0hCsYyPRx9dMw1FTQU/BBMIMUglx9gXQwp5Wbhr8mF6e/gq0/UAFQXMFKI1iTy5/TPzQEaAJIOJjL1c/l///EpOSUVAA)

Comment: Oh, nice! A fellow Bell Labs language.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-ir` `-lp`, 4 bytes

```
(,⑩,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fQ@fRxJU6//8nJiWnpP7XzSz6r5tTAAA)

## Explanation

```
     # (Implicitly) take an input from the console
(    # For every item in the input:
 ,   # Print the first character, popping the stack
  ⑩  # Print the top of the stack w/o poping
   , # Print with popping, effectively doubling the second character
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

Uses the same regex as [@DigitalTrauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198722/58563).

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/.(.)/g,"$&$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcEBCoAgDADAv4jEBqX0APvL0imFOGnR99fdTR9pfq75bkMKW02m6dDw8OyUGWKAgLGtzi9@d2hZhkrn0KVBBUdnLuwQ7Qc)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

A recursive version.

```javascript
f=([a,b,...c])=>b?a+b+b+f(c):[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjOlEnSUdPTy85VtPWLsk@UTsJCNM0kjWtohNj/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpKCUmJaekKmlqcmERBwr/BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
€Ðιθ
```

I/O as a list of characters, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/52210).

<s>I have the feeling 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) might be possible, but I'm unable to find it.</s>
It is possible, by porting [*@emanresuA*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236924/52210) (so make sure to upvote him/her as well).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOawxPO7Ty34///aKVEJR2lJCBOBuIUIE5VigUA)

**Explanation:**

```python
      #  (example input = ["a","b","c","d","e"])
€Ð    # Triplicate each character (which remains a flattened list)
      #  → ["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"]
  ι   # Uninterleave this list into two parts
      #  → [["a","a","b","c","c","d","e","e"],["a","b","b","c","d","d","e"]]
   θ  # Pop and leave just the second part
      #  → ["a","b","b","c","d","d","e"]
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{"$_"*(1+$i++%2)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrVaSSVeSUvDUFslU1tb1UizVvP////qJanFJZl56eoA)

Takes input `$args`, transforms it `t`oCharArra`y`, pipes that into a loop. Each iteration, we repeat the character `"$_"` either 1 or 2 times based on a modulo-index. Those characters/strings are left on the pipeline, gathered up with a `-join` to turn it back into a single string, and output is implicit.

*-2 bytes thanks to Veskah.*
*-1 byte thanks to mazzy.*

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need quotes around `$args` for [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrVaJV5bSSVeSUtDJVNbW9VIs1bz////6iWpxSWZeenqAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Veskah Thanks - that was a leftover from when I was originally writing the submission.

Comment: one more [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrVaSSVeSUvDUFslU1tb1UizVvP////qJanFJZl56eoA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub /.(.)/,'\0\1'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvvbg0SUFfT0NPU19HPcYgxlC99n9BaUmxQlq0UmJSckqqUux/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 13 bytes

```
,[.<[>.>]>>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1rPJtpOzy7Wzk4n9v//xKTklFQA)

Handles odd and even length strings correctly. This takes an input and prints it once before checking if the previous cell contains the previous character. If so, it prints again and moves three spaces ahead, otherwise it just moves one cell ahead, and then it gets the next character.

Comment: This requires cells to the left of the tape.

Comment: @S.S.Anne While it is non-standard, multiple interpreters support it, including the ones on TIO and copy.sh (IIRC).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.scan(/(.(.?))/)*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivODkxT0NfQ09Dz15TU19TS1299n9BaUmxQlq0emJSckqqeux/AA)

Same byte count as the other answer, different approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>95</s> 81 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
Y's 1
O's ""
while S
let O be+roll S*Y
let Y be Y-1 or 2

say O
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: Could you replace the Y-1 or 2 with 3-Y?

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
B X_%2+1MEa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fSSEiXtVI29DXNfH///@JSckpqWnpAA)

-2 from Dlosc.

Comment: +1, very similar to my initial approach. You can use string repetition and a lambda expression to get down to 11 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fSSEiXtVI29DXNfH///@JSckpqWnpAA "Pip – Try It Online") (10 bytes in Pip 1.0 because `_%2` -> `%_`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>66</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>59</s></sup> 57 bytes

Saved <s>a</s> 3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```c
i;f(c){for(i=0;~(c=getchar());printf(&c))c*=i++%2?257:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7CoAwEAXA0yi7iqABEVyCZ4lPo1v4IaQTvXpMOcWg2YCUVDyBH38FUtvKR7DbGrG7QMxyBz2jpxLMqKzWdWEm0w9jJ286nJ6UJ3GGm7GsPw)

Comment: Save another by swapping `c` and `i` and initializing `i` at its definition.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <del>13</del> 12 bytes

```
,.<>,;/@/$;*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19Hz8ZOx1rfQV/FWuv//8Sk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisoqAA)

#### Expanded

```
  , . <
 > , ; /
@ / $ ; *
 . . . .
  . . .
```

Uses the very naive read-print, read-print twice approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 51 bytes

```
func[s][foreach[a b]s[prin rejoin[a t: any[b""]t]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco7DoAgDADQnVM0PQbHcG068GkjDmAKDp6@6uD68kyqb1KJg0ZwvXqhyaTDJJWdEmSedFrrYHKM1l9ZEVK/KSPyYmZXwJRLFQzfW4AYflL0Bw)

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, 6 bytes

```
♀J,⌡I►
```

Uncompressed:

```
2V2m-*M
```

### Explanation

Not a really good target for this challenge, I just feel that this is pretty fun to do.

Also the 1-indexed advantage seems to be a disadvantage here. If only W has a 0-index ...

```
% Note that W is one-indexed. (For the ease of the iterator protocols
% which have a 1-range as a built-in.)
 V2m    % Index of current item modulo 2
2   -   % Subtract 2 by the number (effectively yields
        % 1->1, 0->2 )
     *  % Repeat the character that many times
      M % Do this for every item in the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 16 bytes

GolfScript doesn't have item count so you will need to do it yourself.

```
1:&;{]&):&2%)*}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BKzbo6Vk3TSs1IVVOrVvX//8Sk5JRUAA)

### Explanation

```
# Implicitly pushed input
1:&;             # set count to 1
    {         }% # foreach item of input
     ]&):&       #     add count by one
          2%)*   #     repeat item by cnt % 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 34 bytes

```lua
print(((...):gsub('.(.)','%0%1')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ0NPT0/TKr24NElDXU9DT1NdR13VQNVQXVNT8////4lJySmpAA)

Takes input as an argument, prints result to stdout. Every two characters are replaced with themselves and second one appended.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{S:g[.<(.]x=2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqPVrPRkMvtsLWqPZ/cWKlQpqCUmJSckpqmtJ/AA)

Regex that matches every other character and substitutes it with itself string multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

-1 thanks to ceilingcat

```c
M;f(c){++M%3?c=getchar():0;M=~c&&f(putchar(c));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/9/XOk0jWbNaW9tX1dg@2TY9tSQ5I7FIQ9PKwNrXti5ZTS1No6AUIpasqWld@z83MTNPQ7M6TQPESUxKTkkFAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
while($c=$argn[$i++])echo$c,$c[$i%2];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VJJtVRKL0vOiVTK1tWM1U5Mz8lWSdVSSgXxVo1jr//8Tk5JTUv/lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 44 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e1o1r3x1v2e2o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f
```

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                     # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f1r3x1v2e               # Function 1
                           # Read a byte of input
                           # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            1o             # Otherwise, output it once
              1r3x1v2e     # Read another byte of input
                           # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
                      2o   # Otherwise, output it twice
                        1f # Jump back to the start of function 1
1x2f0a                     # Function 2
                           # Add 0 to the register
1f                         # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 66 bytes

```
[S S S T    N
_Push_1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S S S T S N
_Push_2][T  S T T   _Modulo][S N
S _Dupe][S N
S _Dupe][S N
S _Dupe][S N
S _Dupe][T  N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][T T   T   _Retrieve_input][T  N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoAwEAPPySvma21d0FtBweevdjXkMJnc@3HFOduITEA2uEBUxEsSn6@qjLTGun/Ezmx9bPEA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = 1
Start LOOP:
  n = (n+1) modulo-2
  Integer c = STDIN as character
  Print c as character to STDOUT
  If(n == 0):
    Go to the next iteration of LOOP
  Print c as character to STDOUT
  Go to the next iteration of LOOP
```

Comment: I really would like to master loops and conditional in WhiteSpace. Haven't quite been able to get one working yet.

Comment: @ouflak I can certainly recommend to use the [vii5ard compiler](https://tinyurl.com/smgmlxy) when you're developing in Whitespace. It allows you to debug through the code, and see the values on the stack and heap in the memory-tab. You can even set breakpoints. Also, maybe the more in-depth explanation [in this Whitespace interpreter challenge of mine](https://tinyurl.com/w43l2vh) might clarify a thing or two in comparison to the tutorial linked in the title.

Comment: @ouflak For a loop you basically mark a location with a Label, and you Jump to that label later on. Here for example an infinite loop printing a 1 every iteration: `NSSN SSSTN TNST NSNN` (create label `(empty)`; push 1; pop and print as integer; jump to label `(empty)`). For an if-statement you'd have to make the value either 0 or negative, and use the conditional jumps. You usually do have to duplicate the value if you still need it later on however, since the conditional labels will pop the value.

Comment: @ouflak If you have any questions in particular, or want me to turn a provided pseudo-code into a Whitespace program with explanation, feel free to contact me again. PS: Unfortunately you can't save / link from the vii5ard compiler, which is why I have TIO links in my answers. I never create the programs in TIO though, always in vii5ard.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>76</s> <s>68</s> <s>56</s> <s>48</s> 44 bytes

Thanks to [Malivil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198717/repeat-every-other-character-in-string-starting-with-second-character?page=2&tab=votes#comment472740_198899) for 12 bytes !

```javascript
s=>s.split``.map((v,i)=>i%2==1?v+v:v).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ04RKJdRXFKuruCxhUiYqu/56LyJj9YVyG3mRAFJhr7bmh5pz9sWsNQ9kYKduBpgO7nllY@NHyTnJhVLTQSs8/XUrYzb5AQ)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your submission seems to take input by inserting it into the code.  The challenge requires that input be taken from standard in that would be the input field on TIO.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter Sorry about that, i've added an edited version.

Comment: I don't know javascript well enough to tell you since it is language specific.  The input box feeds its contents to stdin, which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396020/) explains how to read in javascript.  If you want help doing it short you can ask in chat and some other javascript users will likely help you.

Comment: For what it is worth most challenges allow you to submit just a function as well as a complete program.  That is the agreed upon default.  Most js answers do that since it tends to be shorter.

Comment: You can save a few more bytes by changing `v.repeat(2)` to `v+v`

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter by refering to [this submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198767/75522) i was able to add the function definition in the header as well as the function call in the footer. which works great.

Comment: Actually you can save more by using the newer syntax for those empty string functions, like [this](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ04SOSqivCGZX0SxhUjZUdn17L3nxNRTiNsvWI/aKtprKDzXnzOtZa5kI0NKwIi6HjLILmPRRdq5zodx01Mqf4boVQP8B "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: 38 bytes: s=>[...s].map((v,i)=>i%2?v+v:v).join``

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 18 bytes

```
>,[>,]<[<]>[.>..>]
```

Requires 0-termination for EOF. Prints two trailing null bytes for odd-length strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTifaTifWJtom1i5az05Pzy72///EpOSUVAA)

Comment: You should fix your answer rather than leave it invalid.

Comment: @JoKing Still figuring that out :).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 13 bytes

```perl
s/.\K./$&$&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXy/GW09fRU1FTT/9///EpOSU1H/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Bubbler*

```apl
∊⊢⍴⍨¨1 2⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@od27ao7YJ@o96VzzqmKFhqGD0qHcLiNO5SBNI/QdJPuroetS1CCJ@aAWykv//0xTUE5OSU1LVAQ)

A train that takes a string and returns a string (or any list technically).

#### Explanation:

```apl
  ⍴⍨         ⍝ Reshape
    ¨        ⍝ Each of
 ⊢           ⍝ The input
     1 2     ⍝ To the array 1 2
        ⍴⍨   ⍝ Reshaped to
          ≢  ⍝ The length of the input
∊            ⍝ And flatten the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 26 bytes

```powershell
$args-replace'.(.)','$0$1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Ytyi1ICcxOVVdT0NPU11HXcVAxVD9////6iWpxSWZeenqAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 11 bytes

```
2co{J[-j}\m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fKDm/2itaN6s2Jvf//8Sk5JTUNAA)

```
2co # Split into chunks of 2 {"ab" "cd" "e"}
{
 J  # Duplicate pair of chars
 [- # Take the tail (returns empty for length 1 strings)
 j  # Swap to correct order for concat
}\m # For each pair, and then concatenate
```

## Burlesque, 8 bytes

```
2co)+.\[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fKDlfU1svJvr//8Sk5JTUNAA)

Works for even length strings only

```
2co # Same as above
)+. # For each group append the last char again
\[  # Concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 46 bytes

```forth
: f 0 do dup dup 1 type i 2 mod type 1+ loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy7DsIwFEN3vuIoKyoi4TFQiZk/6AxNAkhB9yqUga9Pk8Jg2ceyHCVPj@4em5VyIrLFC/6jiyzTVwNPHC/xP7BrkojS17ni2mzpNwa6M6Z@jJl@9TZcb6MPBm35ElISBsnJ/xvrdvvDsUKZAQ)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f              \ start a new word definition
  0 do           \ loop from 0 to string-len - 1
    dup dup      \ duplicate the current character address twice
    1 type       \ output the current letter
    i 2 mod type \ if odd, output again, if even do nothing (0 type = output nothing)
    1+           \ increment current character address
  loop           \ end loop
;                \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [.+?](https://github.com/EdgyNerd/DotPlusQuestion/blob/master/README.md), 11 bytes

```
(.(.))
\1\2
```

The first answer in my new language. It's a simple language based around python regex substitution

## Explanation

```
(.(.)) Replace each pair of characters with
\1\2   matching group 1 (both characters) followed by matching group 2 (the second character)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RbsIwDEXf/RWWECIZXUTK20S@pO1DC4FGlNRKsk18fRaPquLNvj73yPRM4@yPObsHzSFhfMYKgwUK8w0Nr6oPt59GdyrS5JLYtX4nAdwVJ@sFY3JbG6O/AJ0nw4GimYQEO0X7St9FdVfKnBzgd3STRUcf9Wl1ceFaHlCPPp3H/6xhoqtYxOdFWJD4PbwD67jXC80w4d6gBly@YbsjYw484xBsf39Rn0xtkILzSZRyMRTBukrIOQsllJTQ6rbO/XC@2D8) (The second command line argument is input)

Comment: Nice approach! Isn't `\0`/`$0` possible in Python or your language? I.e. `.(.)` and `\0\1`?

Comment: Sadly not, python's regexes are pretty limited compared to most other flavours

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 36 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS=".|";ORS=e}$0=NR%2?RT:RT RT
```

```
BEGIN{RS=".|";ORS=e}  This reads one character at a time,
                      which can be retrieved by the RT variable.

$0=NR%2?RT:RT RT      If NR=1 (mod 2), i.e., True, assigns "RT" to the output.
                      Otherwise, assigns "RT RT", which is RT concatenated to itself.
                      This conditional simply doubles the even occurrences.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9GydofyEitVTGw9QtSNbIPCrEKClEICvn/PzEpOSUVAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```
WV(UWa!*h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PEwjNDxRUStD8////4lJySmpaekA)

#### Explanation

I love it when I can abuse built-in numbers for some other purpose.

```
WV(UWa!*h)
     a      First command-line argument
   UW       Unweave into a list of two strings, each containing every other character
        h   100
      !*    Logically negate each digit
  (      )  Index into the list using each of those values
WV          Weave the resulting list of three strings back together
```

For instance, if the input is `abcde`:

```
   UWa      ["ace"; "bd"]
      !*h   [0; 1; 1]
  (      )  ["ace"; "bd"; "bd"]
WV          "abbcdde"
```

Comment: [9](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJAPlVXIEphWDMiLCIiLCIiLCIteHAgJ1tcImFcIjtcImJcIjtcImNcIjtcImRcIjtcImVcIl0nIl0=) by porting my Vyxal (there's got to be a better way)

Comment: @emanresuA Hm... that's an interesting I/O format, but I think if it just uses the `x` flag without `p` it should be fine. However, since Pip `-x` is a different language, this solution ought to be posted separately. Feel free to do so yourself; also, an easy golf is `@>` -> `S`.

Answer (score 1):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 13 bytes

```
¤+ōČōōČ
```

### Explanation

```
  ōČ    Take a character and print it.
    ōōČ Take a character and print it twice.
¤+      Repeat this forever.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 34 bytes

```
s=>fori=0i<#s i++write(s[i]*1+i%2)
```

A pretty simple solution to the problem.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7v9jWLi2/KNPWINNGuVghU1u7vCizJFWjODozVstQO1PVSPN/moZSYlJySqqS5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ×ι⊕﹪κ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKIZm5qcUamToKnnnJRam5qXklqSkavvkppTn5Gtk6CkaaIGD9/39iUnJK6n/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ          Input string
⭆           Map over characters and join
       ²    Literal 2
      κ     Current index
     ﹪      Modulo
    ⊕       Incremented
   ι        Current character
  ×         Repeated
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 13 bytes

Prompts for string:

```
((⍴s)⍴⍳2)/s←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5raDzq3VKsCSQe9W420tQvBkoBlfwHSv5P41JPTEpOSVUHAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Unix TMG](https://github.com/amakukha/tmg), 59 bytes

```
p:parse((c={1}))parse((c={1 1}))\p;c:smark any(!<<>>)scopy;
```

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, 44 bytes

This was easy, but also fun!

```
{@eachargv.0}{@echo_}{@if__ is mod2}{@echo_}
```

Loops through all the characters, and checks if the index of the character (`__`) is not a multiple of 2 (odd). If it isn't a multiple of 2, outputs it again.

---

**Ungolfed:**

Just in case you are curious.

```
{@each argv.0 as char key key}
    {@echo char}
    {@if key is not multiple of 2}
        {@echo char}
    {@/}
{@/}
```

- The `as char` is optional, using the variable `_` by default, to hold the array item/character from the string.
- The `key key` is optional, using the variable `__` by default, to hold the index.
- All the `{@/}` ae optional and safe to remove.

---

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5fc880374f58b72c4dc3ee2c573349e7a218aed8
You can check and try both golfed and ungolfed versions.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 88 bytes

```powershell
$c={param($i)$c=0;$o;$i.toCharArray()|%{if($c%2-eq1){$o+="$_$_"}else{$o+="$_"}$c++;};$o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXZtrogsSgxV0MlUxPIMbBWybdWydQryXfOSCxyLCpKrNTQrFGtzkzTUElWNdJNLTTUrFbJ17ZVUolXiVeqTc0pToXxlWpVkrW1rWuBRtSCTNbzzCvLz07VUE9MSlbXBAA)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 102 bytes

```powershell
function b($i){$c=0;$o;$i.ToCharArray().ForEach{if($c%2-eq1){$o+="$_$_"}else{$o+="$_"}$c++;};write $o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCsIwDADQXxklQkdxqNeyg4h@gffRxZQGyqLZZMjot1cvHh@8p6ykc6Kca43vCReWqRktcLsB9gcP4oG7u1xS0LNq@Ni2u4leA6aNowXcnfb0Ov62uN7AAIMplGf62xRA53zxq/JCDUipNYz4oPgF)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```c
i=1;f(c){for(;-~(c=getchar());i^=1)printf("%c%1$c"+i*2,c);}
```

Using original input rules.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg7CoAwEAXAPqcQUdj1U8R2yVWE@DS6hR@C2IhePTrloJ2BlNRZCQS@wx5J2pfg5unE4iMxi/bO8hF1OwPlJUpbIK@16hqwPOnvbPW60bXryOY22S8Qi3mSHzBOHw)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 54 bytes

```c
i=1;f(char*s){for(;*s;i^=1)printf("%c%1$c"+i*2,*s++);}
```

Using acceptable input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCsMgEADvvkKkAVdbqL0u@UrAbmKyh5qyJrmEvN1K5zbM0GMmqpX7gMnSEsUVONMqFl1BHvoAX@G8JWs66sKNjGf3urviPeBVW9GfyNkeK4@gTqUb7Y1vGicD@HeZtl2yfqK66g8)

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoMwEADveUUICtmkhdbr4leEuJp2D41lo17Et8fg3GYYen6ISmGMlr5BXIYjLmK579Bl5KHv4C@c1mhNS@27IeP54bL3gGepXf8CJ7svPIE6lK7UM4w0zQbwdpnXTZJ@oTrLBQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string are all alphabetically sorted, you can use:

## Python 3, 42 bytes:

```
lambda x:''.join(sorted(x[1::2]*2+x[::2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSl1dLys/M0@jOL@oJDVFoyLa0MrKKFbLSLsiGsTQ1Pyfll@kkKmQmacQrZSopKOUmAQmkiFkCpRKVYq14lIAgoKizLwSjTSNTKBOAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
q2/{_La+1=}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f6KevVP2/0Ei/Ot4nUdvQtlb1f62SElehkm6dqp/W/8Sk5JRUrrT0jMysbC4uAxAAAA)

### Explanation

```
q2/{_La+1=}%
q2/           Read the input and split it into groups of 2 characters.
   {      }%  For each group:
    _           Copy it.
     La+        Append an empty string.
        1=      Get its second element.
              Join the results.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 12 bytes

```
00000000: d52e 76e5 2e07 e5cd 0380 38f6            ..v.......8.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBRSTI1SFczNUk0VjFINzBVSTZNTFAyMLQwUjC3SzBSQgJ5emR4EWOj9/5@YlJySCgA)

```
  push de
Z:ld l, $76
  push hl
  ld l, G
  push hl
G:call $8003
  jr c, Z+1   ; halt on EOF, else fallthrough
```

## Explanation

Z80golf is a small Z80 computer hooked up to `$8000=putchar, $8003=getchar`. (`putchar` prints byte A; `getchar` reads a byte into A or sets the carry flag on EOF.) Our code is placed at `$0000` and all registers start at 0, including PC. The rest of memory is filled with zeroes.

Let's run through some sample input: `uvwxyz`.

We push three addresses to the stack: `$0000`, then `$0076`, then `G`.

Then (here's label `G`), we call `getchar()`, and on EOF jump to the HALT instruction (`$76`) hidden in the argument to `ld l, $76`.

Otherwise, control flow falls through a sea of NOPs into `$8000`. This is hardcoded to perform `putchar(A); ret`, so we print `u` and return back to `G`.

The next time we get here, we print `v` and return to `$0076`, amid the NOP sea: control flow runs back to `$8000`, we print `v` again, then return to `$0000`, where the code starts over.

Repeating this process, the output is `uvvwxxyzz` → HALT.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 9 bytes

```
2/{1/~.}%
```

```
2/{1/~.}% #Repeat every other character
2/        #Split string into bits of size 2
  {    }% #For every of those elements, do block
  {1/  }  #Divide into elements of size 1
  {  ~ }  #Pop from their array
  {   .}  #Duplicate the last element
```

Probably possible to shave a byte or two by refining the block. Unfortunately ) doesn't decouple properly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvlJiUkpaapvTfSL/aUL9Or1b1/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>9</strike> <strike>8</strike> 7 bytes

And of course, the simple solution always prevails, and comes to me after I thought I'd done something clever :/

-1 byte because I literally put my laptop away and then remembered that `s` was a thing

```
%2ts*L3
```

Explanation:

```
%2tjk*L3  
          # Implicit Q = eval(input())
%2        # Every second character of:
  t       #   All but the first character of:
   jk     #     Joined on the empty string:
     *L3  #       Each character of Q * 3
```

### Previous version (9 bytes)

```
r9m,h=!Td
```

Falling behind a lot of other golfing languages unfortunately

Explanation:

```
           # Implicit T=10, Q=eval(input())
r9         # Run length decode
  m        # map over (implicit) Q
   ,h=!Td  # create a pair of:
    h=!T   # 1 + (T = not T) and
        d  # the character
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v8gyVyfDVjEk5f9/pcSk5JRUpX/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Chevron](https://ch.superloach.xyz/?inp=YWJjZGU%3D&src=Pl5fXz5eYQpeYX5zPj5ecwpeX18-Xm4KMD4-XmkKXmkrMT4-XmkKLT4rNj9eaT5ecwpeYSxeaX5jPj5ebApebl5sPl5uCi0-LTQ_Xml-bwpebl5sPl5uCi0-LTYKPl5u) - 96 bytes

(link goes to interpreter)

```
>^__>^a
^a~s>>^s
^__>^n
0>>^i
^i+1>>^i
->+6?^i>^s
^a,^i~c>>^l
^n^l>^n
->-4?^i~o
^n^l>^n
->-6
>^n
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 88 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @x INT=len(@)/2*2WHILE @x>0SELECT
@=stuff(@,@x,0,substring(@,@x,1)),@x-=2PRINT @
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1199237/repeat-every-other-character-in-string-starting-with-second-character)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
.(.)
$0$1
```

Port of [*@DigitalTrauma*'s sed's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198722/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9PQ0@TS8VAxfD//8Sk5JRUrpLU4hIuMDMtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisgoA)

**Explanation:**

```python
.(.)  # MATCH:
.(.)  #  Every pair of characters,
      #  where the second character is saved in capture group 1

$0$1  # And replace it with:
$0    #  The entire match, so both characters
  $1  #  Followed by the character from capture group 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 30 bytes

```python
s->s.replaceAll(".(.)","$0$1")
```

Same approach as [my Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199829/52210), which was a port of [*@DigitalTrauma*'s sed's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198722/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY7LDoIwEEX3fMWkcdEm0ujaaOIHyMalcVFLwWIpyAz4Ct@O1XRr3Ezmcc@9U6lBpVV@mbRTiLBT1r8SAOvJdIXSBrLPCLCnzvoSNI8NilXYj0koSIqshgw8rGHCdIOyM60L8NY5ziSXgs3ZbDFbMjGtPkTbn1wgIjg0Noc6BEfvwxGUiKkPJFPLpifZhhM5z73UnKmTzg0T3x9@q8gg/RV9rYrybKuLq33TXjukfrjdH8@Ijsk4vQE)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 91 bytes

```
(defn d[s](apply str(map #(str(first %)(second %)(second %))(partition-all 2 2(into[]s)))))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
(defn dup-alternate-chars[s]
  (apply str (map #(str (first %) (second %) (second %)) (partition-all 2 2 (into [] s)))))
```

Test harness:

```
(println (d "abcde"))
```

which prints "abbcdde".

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcgxCsMwDEDRPacQKQF56JLrhAyq5YCLIhtJHXp6Nxn7p8fP0t4fK2Mgl0OBN9@RepcveBie1OGBt45qHrAk9JKb8p8SdrKoUZs@SQRWWLFqtG33dDdN2O0aooAMM70ylzmlMX4)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-1 thanks to Bubbler

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`)

```apl
⊢⌿⍨1 2⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsb/R12LHvXsf9S7wlDB6FHvFiDjUeei/5pcj/qmAuXTFNQTk5JTUtVR@er/AQ)

`≢` the length

`2⍴⍨` use that to cyclically **r**eshape `[1,2]`

`⊢⌿⍨` use that to replicate the letters

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qG@qp/@jtgkGXGlAUuP/o65Fj3r2P@pdYahg9Kh3C5DxqHPRf00uoDqgfJqCemJSckqqOipf/T8A). Straightforward is better, I guess.

Comment: @Bubbler Yeah. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rabbit~](https://github.com/Ghilt/Rabbit), 13

```
_[.0:.>:.:.>]
```

Explanation:

```
_ - Move to input
 [.0 - start loop with input 0, and loop until you hit 0
    :. - print
      > - move along input
       :.:. - print twice
           > - move along input
            ] - end loop if we have reached past input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
StringReplace[a_~~b_:>a<>b<>b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ikKDMvPSi1ICcxOTU6Mb6uLineyi7Rxi4JiGL/F9uG5EOURCvreOYVlJa45RflxqpxBQDFSqKLHZR17Yod0hyUY9XqgpMT8@qquZQSk5JTlHQgdCqIAeYocdX@BwA)

For every non-overlapping pair of characters, appends the second character.

`""<>MapAt[#<>#&,#,;;;;2]&` doesn't work on an empty input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 17 bytes

```
irs[l!s[p:o0]po]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zqDg6R7E4usAq3yC2ID/W7v//xKTklFQA)

This is pretty much a direct translation of the description of the challenge.  It reads in the all the input, then loops over the list printing each character once or twice.

```
ir                - read input as codepoints onto the stack, reverse the stack
  s               - save a codepoint to the backup cell, just has to be non-zero
   [           ]  - loop while the stack isn't empty
    l!s           - load the backup cell, flip 1/0, save it back
       [   0]p    - if/then, true for even numbered chars
        p         - pop (delete) the if/then test boolean
         :o       - duplicate top of stack and print as char
              o   - print the top of stack as a char
                > - switch stacks to avoid auto-printing
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 39 bytes

```
For(I,2,1.5length(Ans),3
sub(Ans,1,I)+sub(Ans,I,1-I+length(Ans
End
```

Same as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188988/ddoouubbllee-ssppeeaakk/235283#235283) except for the first line. Input is taken in `Ans`. Output is stored in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 chars

```apl
⊢(/⍨)1 2⍴⍨⍴
```

```apl
           ⍴   monadic: shape of the right argument (number of elements)

      1 2⍴⍨    repeat numbers 1 and 2 as many times as the right argument

⊢              the right argument

 (/⍨)          replicate each element of the left argument as many times as 
               specified by the corresponding elements of the right argument
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYs09B/1rtA0VDB61LsFyAKSXI/6pgLl0hTUE5OSU1LV//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
3Ḅz
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UolS7IKlpSVpuhZLjR_uaKlaUpyUXAwVWbA0MSk5JRXCAQA)

Port of emanresu A's Vyxal answer.

#### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
dŻɗ⁺×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuharUo7uPjn9UeOuw9OXFCclF0OFFyxNTEpOSYVwAA)

##### Explanation

```python
3Ḅz  # Implicit input                      ->  "abcde"
3Ḅ   # Repeat each character three times   ->  "aaabbbcccdddeee"
  z  # Uninterleave into two parts         ->  ["aabccdee","abbcdde"]
     # Implicit output of last item        ->  "abbcdde"
```

```python
dŻɗ⁺×  # Implicit input                    ->  "abcde"
d      # Cast to list of characters        ->  ["a","b","c","d","e"]
 Ż     # Push the length range             ->  ["a","b","c","d","e"]  [0,1,2,3,4]
  ɗ    # Pop and push each item mod two    ->  ["a","b","c","d","e"]  [0,1,0,1,0]
   ⁺   # Increment each value in the list  ->  ["a","b","c","d","e"]  [1,2,1,2,1]
    ×  # Multiply the two lists together   ->  ["a","bb","c","dd","e"]
       # Implicit output of joined list    ->  "abbcdde"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 26 bytes

```arturo
$=>[replace&{/.(.)}"$0$1"]
```

And non-regex:

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 41 bytes

```arturo
$=>[i:0loop&=>[&if=1i%2[++<=]prints'i+1]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yum4rJ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Grass](https://github.com/TryItOnline/grass), 47 bytes

```
wWWWWWwWWWWWWwwWWWWwwWWWWWwwWWWWWWwWWWWWWwwwwww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy9KLC7@/788HAQgZHh5OYKEUQg5EPj/PzEpOSUVAA)

Exits with an error after printing out the string.

Ungolfed version:

```
w             (Function takes one argument)
WWWWWw        (Take one character from stdin)
WWWWWWww      (Take another character from stdin)
WWWWww        (Print first character, or error if no characters left)
WWWWWww       (Print second character, or error if no characters left)
WWWWWWw       (Print second character again)
WWWWWWwwwwww  (Call this function again)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `sequences.repeating`, 19 bytes

```factor
[ 3 repeat <odds> ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU2v0GBPP3crheLUwtLUvOTUYr2i1ILUxJLMvHQksdSKkqLEYoXMfISYQnZqUV5qjoI1F5dSYlJySqrS0tKSNF2LzdEKxgoQMxRs8lNSiu0UYiEyq5ITc3IUCooy80ogAgsWQGgA)

Repeat each character three times and take every other character starting with the second one. Port of emanresu A's [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236924/97916).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), 62 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(c if i%2==0 else 2*c for i,c in enumerate(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADAr@wl1IiIukTgT7qorbRRq6gder15nYlfOQMva0zV673e5rGHgbwJMV6BWDogD9TNWk@Ad0aYewc@JKChFQPy@2AyBWVWqsZEXKSXwlh3oGjyAw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
n2@h
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJuMkBoIiwiYWJjZGUiXQ==)

```
n2@h
n @  # For every
 2   # Second character
   h # Double
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 32 bytes

```zsh
for a b (`fold -1`)printf $a$b$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVEhSUEjIS0/J0VB1zBBs6AoM68kTUElUSVJJen/f0MjYxNjU1MTYxMzk/8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
▽+1◿2⇡⧻.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4pa9KzHil78y4oeh4qe7LgoKZiAiYWJjZGUiCmYgImEiCmYgImFiIgo=)

```
▽+1◿2⇡⧻.
       .  # duplicate
      ⧻   # length
     ⇡    # range
   ◿2     # modulo two
 +1       # increment
▽         # keep
```