# How many petals around the rose

Tags: code-golf, integer

## How many petals around the rose

How many petals around the rose is a dice game you can play with your friends. Similar to ["can I join the music box"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199153/75323), there is a person that knows how the game works and the others have to discover the rule.

In this game, someone rolls some dice (usually two or more) and then people have to call "how many petals are around the rose".

## Algorithm

If you want to play it by yourself, you can [play it over at TIO](https://tio.run/##Zc49CoAwDAXg3VO8sVUH8WcRehjBFAvSlrQOnr5aFRGcQr73AvF7XJzt0kwanuK0BlGyCxTkWOARKDTnoh0jRzD2miE3AKNvVQrdLe9dpdBeQuunNfxb/SlMcWP7YPJsbBTvC2Ko0ctCpnQA). Just hide the header (which is where the rule is implemented) and try passing different arguments (from 1 to 6) in the function.

**spoiler, what follows *is* the rule you are invited to find by yourself!**

> The "roses" here are the dice, and the "petals" are the black dots that are *around* a central dot. Because only the odd numbers have a central black dot, only numbers `1, 3, 5` matter for the petals. Those numbers have, respectively, `0, 2, 4` dots around the central dot, the "petals".

[image]

## Input

Your input will be a non-empty list (or equivalent) of integers in the range `[1, 6]`.

## Output

The number of petals around the rose.

## Test cases

[Reference implementation](https://tio.run/##Zc49CoAwDAXg3VO8sVUH8WcRehjBFAvSlrQOnr5aFRGcQr73AvF7XJzt0kwanuK0BlGyCxTkWOARKDTnoh0jRzD2miE3AKNvVQrdLe9dpdBeQuunNfxb/SlMcWP7YPJsbBTvC2Ko0ctCpnQA) in Python, that also generated the test cases.

```
1, 1 -> 0
1, 2 -> 0
1, 3 -> 2
1, 4 -> 0
1, 5 -> 4
1, 6 -> 0
2, 1 -> 0
2, 2 -> 0
2, 3 -> 2
2, 4 -> 0
2, 5 -> 4
2, 6 -> 0
3, 1 -> 2
3, 2 -> 2
3, 3 -> 4
3, 4 -> 2
3, 5 -> 6
3, 6 -> 2
4, 1 -> 0
4, 2 -> 0
4, 3 -> 2
4, 4 -> 0
4, 5 -> 4
4, 6 -> 0
5, 1 -> 4
5, 2 -> 4
5, 3 -> 6
5, 4 -> 4
5, 5 -> 8
5, 6 -> 4
6, 1 -> 0
6, 2 -> 0
6, 3 -> 2
6, 4 -> 0
6, 5 -> 4
6, 6 -> 0
3, 1, 5 -> 6
4, 5, 2 -> 4
4, 3, 5 -> 6
1, 4, 4 -> 0
5, 5, 2 -> 8
4, 1, 1 -> 0
3, 4, 1 -> 2
4, 3, 5 -> 6
4, 4, 5 -> 4
4, 2, 1 -> 0
3, 5, 5, 2 -> 10
6, 1, 4, 6, 3 -> 2
3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3 -> 4
3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2, 5 -> 10
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

Comment: Suggestion: Since you offer to let people play it themselves with the TIO link, consider giving a small warning of some sort before explaining what the solution/rule is. I was a bit confused after reading both paragraphs and then poking in different numbers thinking there would be some additional rule to figure out, only to find that the results were precisely as described.

Comment: @Klaycon I don't understand what you mean! Can you please try to elaborate?

Comment: The intro presents the game as having some rule that must be discovered. The reader is then invited to try and find the rule themselves by visiting the TIO link, collapsing the header, and trying inputs themselves - but immediately following this invitation is an explanation of what the rule is, without any indication as such. For me at least I didn't realize that explanation was the "rule" and proceeded to try figuring it out, leading to some confusion and lost time when there seemed to be nothing more to it.

Comment: @Klaycon that actually makes a lot of sense, I edited it into the challenge. I hope it makes it more clear now.

Comment: Could you put actual spoiler tags to hide the rule?

Comment: @JiK now I have, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Veskah input is in the range 1-6 so you don't need to worry about 0

Comment: D'oh, meant output. E.g., for `(1,2,4)`, can we return nothing instead of `0`?

Comment: @Veskah you have to return 0, sorry.

Answer (score 30):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(n**3&6for n in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZPBboMwEETvfIXFoYKISmVtVlEkeuwX9JbmQBujRCIQgSO1Qnw7xVh2p1yQh7Fn3y74/mMuXSvnuvyYm@r2ea5Ecxget6Td7eQT110vWnFtRZPORg9mKJMoOeaZyE@ZeEkzJwiFXAR5odApFqG84OAQphGmEaYRphGmEaZJl0ZeEAoZzkiXFhybxl5wcBSyKWRTyKaQTSGbQrbCpSkvCIUMBIVLC45N23vBwWFkY2RjZGNkY2RjZOPtEHEmtiXEtc2jb780linC/n0YI9LKdX@O85Obetsp0ub8X4k8NOAw/nUv15O0erT5Adi/LdzTZ6VRX47v/UMf4mqIM/FWNcOybjsjFj1F9lKYTNtrsd6JQyTu/bU1SR2PZhLPr2KsE5NOYuyPdlGW@jQJ/X3XX0af43T@BQ)

(test cases shamelessly borrowed from [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200407/58563))

#### How?

Given \$1\le n\le6\$, the number of petals can be computed with:

$$p=n^{2k+1} \operatorname{and}6,\:k\in\mathbb{N}^*$$

where \$\operatorname{and}\$ is a bitwise operator.

This can also be written as:

$$p=2\times\left\lfloor\frac{n^{2k+1}\bmod 8}{2}\right\rfloor$$

And is based on the fact that, for any \$k\ge1\$:

$$n^{2k+1}\bmod 8=\cases{
n&\text{if $n$ is odd ($1$, $3$ or $5$)}\\
0&\text{if $n$ is even ($2$, $4$ or $6$)}
}$$

More specifically, choosing \$k=1\$:

$$p=n^3 \operatorname{and}6$$

As Python code, the resulting expression is just as long as the nice `n%-2%n` [found by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200407/58563). But because it ends with a digit, we can get rid of the space just before the `for`, saving a byte.

```
 n | n**3 | as binary  | AND 6
---+------+------------+-------
 1 |    1 | 00000 00 1 |   0
 2 |    8 | 00001 00 0 |   0
 3 |   27 | 00011 01 1 |   2
 4 |   64 | 01000 00 0 |   0
 5 |  125 | 01111 10 1 |   4
 6 |  216 | 11011 00 0 |   0
```

Comment: May I ask how you got to this formula? Were you playing around with the bits?

Comment: @RGS _Playing around with the bits_ sounds like an accurate description. Given that I wanted to find something either shorter than `n%-2%n` or just as long but ending with a digit, there were actually not so many (reasonable) things to try.

Comment: Nice method! I posted a bounty. Amusingly, I had tried to brute-force for shorter expressions than mine, but missed yours because the intermediate step of `6**3=216` was above my cutoff. Searching now without cutoff, I don't find any other solutions except your other odd exponents as you note.

Answer (score 18):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 11 bytes

```
5
33
3
33
3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w35TL2JjLGEz8/29samrEZWZoYgbkGRkZGgEpM0MjUyNTAA) Link includes test cases. Input can be in almost any format really as only the `5`s and `3`s count. Explanation:

```
5
33
```

A `5` has as many petals as two `3`s.

```
3
33
```

Speaking of `3`s, they have two petals, so make them count twice.

```
3
```

Count the petals.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(n%-2%n for n in l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZNRa4MwFIXf/RUXoaBgYd7EUArucb9gb10f3BZZwaZFU9gQf7szhmRnvkiOJzn3u1dz/7FfNyPmtn6bu@b6/tlQdxwe18zs9rwz1N56MnQx1OWz1YMd6izJTmVB5bmgp7zwglGIRXAQEp1qETIIFR3GNMY0xjTGNMY0xjTh0zgIRiHiGeHTouPSVBAqOhLZJLJJZJPIJpFNIlvl02QQjEJEgsqnRcelHYJQ0VHIppBNIZtCNoVsCtnUdog4E9cS4rrm0XdfGstUcf8hjhFpxbq/xPmJTb3tFHlz/q9EGRvwGP@6F@tJXj3e/AAqvK38M2TlSV@Pr/1DH9NmSAt6abphWZubpUVPibsUttDuWqx34pjQvb8Ym7XpaCfaP9PYZjafaOxPblHX@jyR/r7rD6s/03z@BQ)

The core expression `n%-2%n` evaluates to zero for even `n` and to `n-1` for odd `n`.

```python
       | n%-2   n%-2%n
-------+--------------
n even |    0        0  
n odd  |   -1      n-1
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```r
function(l)l%%2%*%(l-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHM0dV1UhVS1UjR9dQ83@aRrKGsY6CERgZgkljTc3/AA)

*-3 thanks to [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder)!*

Returns a 1x1 matrix with the result.

---

Old answer, since there are a handful of explicit ports:

```r
function(l)sum((l-1)*l%%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHs7g0V0MjR9dQUytHVdVI83@aRrKGsY6CERgZgkljTc3/AA)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHM0dV1UhVS1UjR9dQ83@aRrKGsY6CERgZgkljTc3/AA "R – Try It Online") with matrix multiplication.

Comment: @RobinRyder thanks! I should have tried that, don't know why I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  4 bytes

-3 using [Giuseppe's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200387/53748)!

```
Ḃ×’S
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjqbD0x81zAz@//9/tLGOgpmOgqGOgpGOgimEjAUA)**

#### How?

We know that 3's and 5's "score", that they score one less than their pips, and that \$1-1=0\$ so:

```
        throw   1  2  3  4  5  6
  x=throw - 1   0  1  2  3  4  5
  y=throw % 2   1  0  1  0  1  0
score = x * y   0  0  2  0  4  0
```

So:

```
Ḃ×’S - Link: throws, list of integers in [1,6]   e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Ḃ    - (throws) % 2                                   [1,0,1,0,1,0]
  ’  - (throws) - 1                                   [0,1,2,3,4,5]
 ×   - multiply                                       [0,0,2,0,4,0]
   S - sum                                            6
```

Comment: Have been meaning to ask you this: where/how did you get to know the implicit things you know that some jelly atoms do? as an example, quite often you use dequeue on integers, which first implicitly converts to the range `[1, .., n]`.

Comment: Being told by Dennis / Lynn / Miles or looking at [the code](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py)

Comment: ...[Dequeue](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py#L1439) is `lambda z: iterable(z, make_range = True)[1:]` for example.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```perl6
{sum $_>>³X+&6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0V0El3s7u0OYIbTWz2v/WXMWJlQppCtHGOgpmOgqGOgpGOgqmEDL2PwA)

Uses [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200429/76162) of \$n^3\&6\$. If HyperWhatevers worked, then something like `(**³+&6).sum` should be possible for 13 bytes.

My old regex based solution:

```perl6
{sum m:g/3|5/X-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0VyHXKl3fuMZUP0LXsPa/NVdxYqVCmkK0sY6CmY6CoY6CkY6CKYSM/Q8A)

Match 3s and 5s from the input, subtract one from each and sum them together.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org), 32 bytes

```python
lambda d:sum(r%2*~-r for r in d)
```

Port of [Giuseppe's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200387/53748).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHFqrg0V6NI1UirTrdIIS2/SKFIITNPIUXzf0FRZl6JRppGtLGOmY6hjpGOKQjHamr@BwA)**

Comment: Fine - roses in dice.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
1#.2&|*<:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1jNRqtGys/mtypSZn5CsYKdimKZjpKBjqKJjogBjGEHETkLixjoIRGBmCSaiUoYGCrQJY0gwmYwoh/wMA)

- `1#.` Sum of applying the following to each element...
- `2&|` Remainder when divided by 2
- `*` Times...
- `<:` Number decremented by 1

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
³&6
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=syY2&input=WzMsIDYsIDEsIDIsIDUsIDIsIDVd)

Saved 2 bytes using [Arnauld's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200429/58974) so be sure to `+1` him if you're `+1`ing this.

### Original, 5 bytes

```
fu xÉ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZnUgeMk&input=WzMsIDYsIDEsIDIsIDUsIDIsIDVd)

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <sup>29</sup> <sup>28</sup> 26 bytes

```
/3|5/{x+=$0-1}END{print+x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9f37jGVL@6QttWxUDXsNbVz6W6oCgzr0S7ovb/f2MuMy5DLiMuUxAGAA)

*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

*-2 bytes thanks to user41805*

`+x` is needed so that inputs with no odd numbers still return 0.

Comment: Taking input as lines is allowed +1

Comment: It appears `/3|5/` works, and you should be able to remove the space after `print`

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>55</del> <del>53</del> 51 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>array_sum(array_map(fn($v)=>$v%2*~-$v,$a));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7Py1PQyVR09YusagosTK@uDRXA8LKTSzQAMmVAeVUylSNtOp0Vcp0gEo1rf@nJmfkK6ikaUQb65jGAvkA)

-2 bytes thanks to @RGS

Comment: You might be able to golf this considerably if you check, for example, [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200387/75323)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my options are limited to either looping through the array or using array functions. I've plumped for the latter. The only way to apply a function to each element is to use `array_map` or maybe `array_filter`. My petal choosing lookup could be shorter, but not by much.

Comment: Yeah, I only managed to get [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7Py1PQyVR09YusagosTK@uDRXA8LKTSzQAMmVAeVUylSNtIBMXUNNHaBiTev/qckZ@QoqaRrRhjpGsUA@AA) by using Giuseppe's formula.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>40</s> <s>33</s></sup> 32 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to [RGS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75323/rgs)!!!

```python
lambda d:sum(i%2*~-i for i in d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZNBa4QwEIXv/opBKGhxoU5iWBbssb@gt@0ebI1U2HUXzUKL2L9ujSHpqxfJ8yVvvhnN7dt8XjsxN@XbfK4u73VF9WG4X5L2gR9/di01155aajuq09nowQxlEiXHPKP8lNFTmjnBKMQi2AuJTrEI6YUKDmMaYxpjGmMaYxpjmnBp7AWjEOGMcGnBsWnKCxUciWwS2SSySWSTyCaRrXBp0gtGIQJB4dKCY9P2XqjgKGRTyKaQTSGbQjaFbGo7RJyJbQlxbfPo2y@NZYqwfx/GiLRi3Z/j/MSm3naKvDn/VyIPDTiMf92L9SSvHm9@AOXfFu7ps9KoL8fX/q4PcTXEGb1U52FZd1dDi54ieylMpu21WO/EIaJb33YmaeLRTLR7prFJTDrR2B/toiz1aSL9ddMfRtdxOv8C)

This turns out to be a total rip off of [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)'s Python answer so update him instead.

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZNRa4MwFIXf/RUXYaDDwryJoRTc437B3ro@uBmp0NqiKWyIv90ZQ7IzXyTHk5z73au5/5jzrRNzU37Ml@r6WVdUH4bHNWmf@Dlpd3na3Hpqqe2oTmejBzOUSZQc84zyU0YvaeYEoxCLYC8kOsUipBcqOIxpjGmMaYxpjGmMacKlsReMQoQzwqUFx6YpL1RwJLJJZJPIJpFNIptEtsKlSS8YhQgEhUsLjk3be6GCo5BNIZtCNoVsCtkUsqntEHEmtiXEtc2jb780linC/n0YI9KKdX@O8xObetsp8ub8X4k8NOAw/nUv1pO8erz5AZR/W7inz0qjvhzf@4c@xNUQZ/RWXYZl3d0MLXqK7KUwmbbXYr0Th4jufduZpIlHM9HulcYmMelEY3@0i7LUp4n0911/GV3H6fwL) :)

Comment: @RGS Nice one - thanks!

Comment: thanks, but now [Jonathan Allan golfed one byte more](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200394/75323) by using clever bitwise operations... I always forget about the `~` trick.

Comment: @RGS Was just converting the `(i-1)` to `~-i` ...

Comment: yeah I know, I just never remember that trick by myself.

Comment: @RGS It's very useful (and `-~i` for `(i+1)`) when brackets are needed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```hs
f x=sum[n-1|n<-x,odd n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDc6T9ewJs9Gt0InPyVFIS/2f25iZp5tQVFmXolKbmKBQppCdLSxjoIpGBnF6kSb6SgY6iiY6CgAGcZAPlDSCIwMwSRUyAzGN4WQsbH/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>50</s></sup> 48 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [xibu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90181/xibu)!!!

```c
s;f(l,p)int*p;{for(s=0;l--;)s+=*p%2*~-*p++;l=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/dCoIwFAfw@57iEATbPCPdh10MexHrIgwjMBu5O7FXt@XSWjDG4H/O75xV/FJV49iZmjRo6bV1zJq@vj9IV6Sm4dzQLimY3Qj25MwmiWmKzgzj7XRtCe1XvgFcVspj0SsEgZANBrYMUmDblX34uCbrTwJ8D5vzoV0j1ESiyyg1ARCl8oBE0NMRwcgi5JtGjkInFkeWuXdyPwvBD/UPGSjxK0V5hGl0csHUhMlpdzG1iMVTf5tFJRGZo1MLqctdIPO5WId7/nCs/ldF8A6dfsPD@AI)

Inputs an integer array pointer preceded by its length.

Comment: I'm assuming it's standard to allow C submissions to take the length of the array as input? +1

Comment: @RGS In C, only `char*` arrays (strings) have a sentinel value at the end. So the only way to know the size of other arrays is to be passed the length.

Comment: I thought you could do something with `sizeof` or something like that..?

Comment: That's not going to work with a pointer and that's done at compile time so how's a function going to work taking different sizes of arrays?

Comment: I'm not against you taking the length as input! I just don't know much C and that is why I'm asking

Comment: I normally work with C++ so never use raw pointers in the wild. But a big thing right now is spans, which is basically a pointer and length. Turns out that's very speed efficient too! :-)

Comment: And the very first span was `std::string_view` which replaces the `'\0'` terminated C string with a pointer and a length! Not only faster and more memory efficient but way more useful for things like substrings too! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105081/discussion-between-noodle9-and-rgs).

Comment: You can save 2 Bytes by using K&R style for the declaration of p. [TIO](https://tio.run/##Xc/dCoIwFAfw@57iEATbPCPdh10MexHrIgwjMBu5O7FXt@XSWjDG4H/O75xV/FJV49iZmjRo6bV1zJq@vj9IV6Sm4dzQLimY3Qj25MwmiWmKzgzj7XRtCe1XvgFcVspj0SsEgZANBrYMUmDblX34uCbrTwJ8D5vzoV0j1ESiyyg1ARCl8oBE0NMRwcgi5JtGjkInFkeWuXdyPwvBD/UPGSjxK0V5hGl0csHUhMlpdzG1iMVTf5tFJRGZo1MLqctdIPO5WId7/nCs/ldF8A6dfsPD@AI)

Comment: @xibu Good 'ol K&R! Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: As the only defined values in this challenge are [1..6], you can use 0 as your sentinel value and save 5 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NT8QgEIbv/RWTmiZ8dI3ReBHxV3jcCwLdDqllQ1kPbta/jkOJ3pjhfd5n7OFkbSlBTQzXLJBfp5hY0A9KoOJBaoHDo/g5CJRSoQ7qVu5wtcvFeXjdslvw435@6zqC4dPgWlvApJMdwc4mgRA0fHG4dgD1S6C2ZlmiZS204bePu5vzEUTQqDqKnhNtJta/zz556vMwOOLPl7y9HNd@3BVcUbKeq0BIWT3qHxy2Y6ZYs3MqllKbHJG1TSVrGetdXH3f5j/U7QY6ijdD8p7eqruV8lSefwE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ÉÏ<O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOfhfhv///@jjXUUzHQUDHUUjHQUTCFkLAA)

*-7 byes thanks to Expired Data*

*-1 byte thanks to Grimmy*

As promised, someone who knows 05AB1E better than I came and golfed it somehow.

### 11 bytes

```
ε2%}Iε1-}*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FYj1VrPc1sNdWu1/P//jzbWUTDTUTDUUTDSUTCFkLEA)

I'm sure someone who knows 05AB1E better than I do will come along and golf this somehow. Really simple:

```
ε2%}   # Map the code 2% (mod 2) to each element of the implicit input
Iε1-}  # Map the code 1- (sub 1) to each element of the explicit input
*O     # Multiply the two lists and sum
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKenjZb////RxjoKZjoKhjoKRjoKphAyFgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: Everything in 05AB1E vectorizes, and `É` is a built-in for `%2`, `<` is a built-in for `-1`.

Comment: 4 bytes: [ÉÏ<O](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOfhfhv///@jjXUUzHQUDHUUjHQUTCFkLAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
Tr[(Mod[#,2]#//.0->1)-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6QoWsM3PyVaWccoVllfX89A185QU9cwVu1/QFFmXomCQ7pDtbGOgpmOgqGOgpGOgimErP3/HwA)

Comment: `Mod[#,2].(#-1)&`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Sum(x=>x--%2*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldQxa8MwEIbhPb/CS8EuccAn3S2JvRQ6ZevQORgHBK0CsUMNpb/dxQnt/N5y0ydxPEhfP9b9mJbXW@4PxzROh5Snblusszi3y6ntTru322c5t91c10/yPFfLfrN5ueTx8jHs3q9pGo4pD@W5zMNX8X/Fd7Mtmp@q2rOo8Gjg0cijyqMGo8IFhAsIFxAuIFxAuEDgAoELBC4QuEDgAoELRC4QuUDkApELRC4QuYByAeUCygWUCygXUC5gXMC4gHEB4wLGBczXA67Hpb6/4Krv6HsPrk0aV@H5yiG4BH2fWVx7@1jszrI2hqu35bHVfTqO2d8Zfcz15PIL)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-BASIC, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

I found some 12 byte solutions

```
Ans-1:sum(Ansnot(fPart(Ans/2
```

The previous is the same byte count as below due to the line separator costing a byte

```
sum((Ans-1)2fPart(Ans/2
```

The above solutions use NfPart(Ans/N as a modulus operation to judge even/odd, giving us a list of dice that can have petals.  Multiplying that by the original list -1 restores the petal counts to the list which can then be summed

```
2sum(Ans=3)+4sum(Ans=5
```

The original 13 byte solution simply compared the list once against 3 and separately against 5 before summing those results independently to get the petal count

All the above solutions take input as a list in Ans

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>23</s> 16 bytes

```julia
l->sum(l.^3 .&6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLBaoUwEEX3fsWsioJ9NJNkeBtLP6I7sVDos1ishRqhf2@NIdPbuBBvbubmzJiPbZ5ezc8@dvt8/7hun/V8ebF0uZNmD7c1rF1d1b1pyQwtPTRtEozCHoKzcOj4Q7gsRB3GNMY0xjTGNMY0xjSb0jgLRmG1xqY0dWKaZCHqOGRzyOaQzSGbQzaHbD6luSwYhVUCn9LUiWnXLEQdQTZBNkE2QTZBNkE2KYeIM4ktIW5sHv34p/EYr/uvOkakted@g/OzxXnlFLmo/zvCaAMJ41/39qzk0@PiAkhe9emds5pqW6flnZ6PC1@NX98UaFrovP4VHc9T/KSxDr0ZGuo6Cj0P1W15238B)

-7 Bytes thanks to [Maria Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/maria-miller)

Comment: 16 bytes: `l->sum(l.^3 .&6)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>66</s> <s>60</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

*Two bytes saved by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162)*

```
({(({}[()])<>)<>{<({}[()])><>([{}])<>}{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo1pDo7o2WkMzVtPGDoiqbWBcOxs7jejqWpB4bXVtreb///9N/xv9NwaShgA)

This challenge seems to ellude a straight forward solution in Brain-flak.  It was quite fun to golf.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```java
r->{int s=0;for(int i:r)s+=i%2*~-i;return s;}
```

First time code golfing, hope I posted this right.

-2 Bytes by removing unneeded curly brackets

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDLTsMwEEXX7VdcRUKKyUMVEpua8Ad00yViMXHTyiV1KtspQpX59TB2KIjN3Hkce0b3SBeqjrv3SfXkHF5Im@sS0MZ3dk@qwyaWqQGVc3x9gxaSe2HJYQODZrLV8zUCrlnJ/WAjBr22whWNvnu4/6q0tJ0frYGTYZLx4Xlse63gPHmWy6B3OPHufOutNgdeQvbgxLz79iWhwUqCigJPDR6lSNOZ@aPamWr/U5Fb3BCVEJUIBngCbD@d7071MPr6zCf43uSEAlmZcWx/MxWzNTKwmu4jGZaL2tQqj@Vs0BVUoi0ZDoK9WoSfE2YNybwwfQM)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and good job here!

Answer (score 2):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
►S≡5u
```

Uncompressed:

````
(S2m*J

(      % Decrement input
 S     % Swap a copy of the input up
  2m   % Modulo the value by 2
    *  % Multiply them
     J % Find their sum
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your W submission. What is the `d` next to the language name?

Comment: @RGS It's a flag to decompress the source; it's currently an obscure flag but is kept for backwards compatibility. (I forgot to remove the flag, whoops!)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 15 bytes

```perl
$\+=$_%2*$_&6}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJV7VSEslXs2stvr/f2MuMy5DLiMuUxD@l19QkpmfV/xftyAHAA)

Takes the input list as one entry per line.

Answer (score 2):

### [Roj](https://github.com/RojerGS/Roj), <s>134</s> <del>92</del> <del>88</del> <del>86</del> 65 bytes

Considerably easier than the previous challenge. Takes numbers in separate lines and end input with the input `0`. Outputs via return value. (Dramatically saved 42 bytes by using dynamic input)

```
O=0;i=1;while i do readint i;if i==3 or i==5 do O=O+i-1 end end;O
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, <s>37</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```bash
sed s/5/33/\;p|tr -cd 3|wc -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RaFY31Tf2Fg/xrqgpqRIQTc5RcG4pjwZyPj/35jLjMuQy4jLFIQB)

---

Shortened by 1 byte: Thanks to @user41805 for pointing out that OP is allowing the program to require one number per line, which lets me eliminate the `g` flag from the sed command.

---

Shortened by 4 bytes thanks to @Neil! The change is to use sed to print the output twice, before counting characters, eliminating the need to double the character count.

---

I was going to use the formula `n%2*(n-1)`, but then I saw that everybody else had the same idea, so I decided to do something different.

Input is a list of integers between 1 and 6, inclusive, on stdin, with one number per line.

Output is on stdout.

**The 30-byte version:**

Uses @Neil's idea of using sed to print the line twice, eliminating the need to double the number.

**The 34-byte version:**

One byte shorter: instead of multiplying by 2, I now add the number to itself.

**How the 35-byte version worked:**

1. Replace every instance of `5` by `33`.  (The number of `3`s is now half the desired answer.)
2. Delete all characters except `3`.  (This even eliminates the `\n` at the end of the line.)
3. Use `wc` (without the `-c` option this time) to print the number of lines, the number of words, and the number of characters, separated by spaces.
4. Use `dc` to double the number of characters, ignoring the number of lines and the number of words.

**How the original 37-byte version worked:**

1. Replace every instance of `5` by `33`.
2. Replace every instance of `3` by `33`.  (In particular, every `5` in the original string has now become `3333`.)
3. Delete all characters except `3`.  (This even eliminates the `\n` at the end of the line.)
4. Count and print the number of characters in what remains.  (Every `3` in the original string has been replaced by `33`, every `5` has been replaced by `3333`, and everything else has been removed.)

*In looking through the various submissions, it turns out that @Neil's Retina answer had used the same method as my original 37-byte version (but he was earlier).  I wasn't sure at first, since I've never used Retina, but @Neil confirmed it.*

*The newer versions work somewhat differently, though.*

Comment: Yes, my Retina answer does use the same approach; the first two pairs of lines correspond to your `sed` substitutions while the final line is roughly equivalent to `grep -o 3|wc -l` (although obviously for a single character your `tr` approach is golfier).

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I thought when I read your answer. Retina looks like an interesting language; I'll check it out.

Comment: Seeing your latest answer makes me wonder - can you make `sed` print each line twice, thus doubling the number of `3`s?

Comment: Interesting idea, @Neil -- thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks, @Neil!  That saved 4 bytes!

Comment: ["Taking input as lines is allowed"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200386/how-many-petals-around-the-rose?answertab=votes#comment476840_200399), so you should be able to save 4 bytes at least

Comment: @user41805 Thank you for pointing that out. But I must be missing something obvious -- I see that this lets you eliminate the `g` flag from the sed command, but where are the other 3 bytes coming from?

Comment: You can double the count by having `wc -c` also count newlines to save more than 3 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
+/⊢|¯2|⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/UdeimkPrjWqA9P@0R20THvX2Peqb6un/qKv50HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfw/TcFQwVjBVMEEiI250hTMFIzA0FjBBAA)

A port of [xnor's double modulo trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200407/78410).

#### How it works

```apl
+/⊢|¯2|⊢
    ¯2|⊢  ⍝ Input modulo -2; 0 if even, -1 if odd
  ⊢|      ⍝ That modulo input; 0 if even, n-1 if odd
+/        ⍝ Sum
```

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
2∘|+.×-∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3@hRx4wabb3D03WBDMP/aY/aJjzq7XvUN9XT/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCsYIxV5qCoYKRgomCGZBlCmSZAtnGAA)

#### How it works

```apl
2∘|+.×-∘1
      -∘1  ⍝ Decrement input
   +.×     ⍝ Dot product with
2∘|        ⍝ Input modulo 2
```

Comment: Good job using three vector dot product

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sum{|x|x**9&6}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlGvuDS3uqaipkJLy1LNrLb2v4aBnp6esZmmXm5iQXVNUU2BQrShdpG@mQ6QVDXTSYtG5sbGxtb@BwA)

Actually using the same idea as Arnauld, only with bigger numbers. Read his explanation and upvote him.

Comment: Might as well take a single array as input instead of splatting the 2 arguments, since some other answers are doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 50 bytes

```
procedure f(a)
n:=0&n+:=!a-1=(2|4)&\z
return n
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNI1GTK8/K1kAtT9vKVjFR19BWw6jGRFMtpoqrKLWktChPIY8rNS8FSUtuYmaehiaXAhCUF2WWpGqkaUQb6iiYxmpiCppgCBoDVYKREYaUmY4CSIuOApBhjE0jRIERRDvURpDbAA)

### Explanation:

```
procedure f(a)         # the argument a is the list 
    n:=0 &             # sets the sum to 0 and  
    n+:=!a-1=(2|4) &   # add to n (n+:=) each element of a decreased by one (!a-1),
                       # if it now equals 2 or 4 (=(2|4)) and
    \z                 # loop (in fact checks if a variable z exists - since it 
                       # doesn't, backtracks to get the next element of a, if any)
    return n           # returns the sum
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 13 bytes

```
{+/(2!x)*x-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc87DoMwEEXRrThVIBGKPL8i7IeGghYJZe2OLjPNK3zm53059jG27/X@TPI459e59N/YnlNvfW29CaGEEU7E2gQVVFBBBRVUUUUVVVRRRQ011FBDDTXUUUcdddRRRwMNNNBAA43am3O8pue9VjPysedxdYVmQ@2XtKqNuzfyCwLmb/UWoaj5PP4)

Essentially same as [Jonah's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200395/75681)

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 8 bytes

A port using Arnauld's formula.

```
⌠3ⁿ6&⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9RzwLjR437zdQe9Sz0Pbf4//9oQx0jHeNYAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 34 bytes

```
=SUMIF(A:A,3)/3*2+SUMIF(A:A,5)/5*4
```

`SUMIF` does much of the work for us.

Feel like there should be a solution using `SUMPRODUCT`, but have not found it yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes

```
psf{2.%}?d++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZG7DoJAEEV7v4KQGAvByOzshGQT/AMbS7UxYizQ@AiV4dvRmcUrNuTmsmfODhzaR1M/723dN9fLa5aFsNumeZWGkO/72/P0osW0Wx3n835z7tp1X2RJkeRVspx8EiE5TaSJ0XlNrEliR2AJLIElsASWwLqBJU2E5OI5N7DWGSuaJHYML8PL8DK8DC/D6weWNRGSiw4/sNYZW2qS2Am8Aq/AK/AKvPK3L1bRi8GuN8cb/eCY43/HSlsafmfHCizsxqP/1qYxMxpY2DWj7reDM4DsBY3/hnwrH59xxBs)

```
ps     # Parse input to array
f{2.%} # Filter for mod2 == 1
?d     # Decrement each
++     # Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
(Ç¥Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Nc@9EcIwDIbhnklSpLH@luFS0AAFHA07MAjHIkmflYzznlT4O9t6bMvPy/t@ez2uvU/bZ/3t397PbW7LaaSQShrpZIwUjGAEIxjBCEYxilGMYhSjGMMYxjCGMYxhHOMYxzjGMY4JTGACE5jARPWTt3q9lz@yui/3W3Ze3Wmeq64k63VivD5qkX@Uoz5LroK5H2P5Aw)

**Explanation:**

```python
(     # Decrease each value in the (implicit) input-list by 1
 Ç    # Inverted filter this list by (so keep those which are falsey):
  ¥   #  Modulo-2
   Σ  # And sum each remaining item
      # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 48 bytes

```
func[b][s: 0 foreach a b[s: a - 1 *(a % 2)+ s]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RdBNasMwEIbhfU4xBAr9IVCPpFlkkUN0K2ahxDYttEmwm/O79otEF/qQNY@kkaehXz6GPvtuPC7j43rJZ8/zUd5lvE1DuXxKkfO2UOQgnbw@F3kSfXmT2Wdf/k3e5U4631LJQEYykbamYhSjGMUoRjEBEzABEzABEzAREzEREzEREzEJkzAJkzAJkzCGMYxhDGMYa/3UU1O7r74otvPqelc7b92Fuq91pbXedqy3rzWrb9StLlq/jHnahrvk@/R1/ZX8c/vu17@9P5z2MkpxX/4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
ＩΣ＆⁶ＸＡ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8Mps6Q8szjVMS9Fw0xHISC/PLVIwzOvoLREQ1NHwVgTBKz//4@ONtRRMAIK6CiY6CiY6iiYxcb@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @Arnauld's Python answer, as Charcoal supports vectorising those operations. Explanation:

```
     Ａ  Input array
    Ｘ ³ Cubed (vectorises)
   ⁶    Literal `6`
  ＆     Bitwise And (vectorises)
 Σ      Sum
Ｉ       Cast to string for implicit print
```

Since `＆` is commutative, the `⁶` is placed first in order to keep it separate from the `³`.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

Port of [Arnauld's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200429/6484).

```
0\{3?6&+}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbaxgpmCoYKRgCsKx/w1iqo3tzdS0a/X//wcA)

Comment: Aaaah, beat me to posting the 10-byter - took me a good while to notice I had to toss the 0 up front to get it to work. I spent a while getting the block to fit five bytes, and figured the cube answer just a tad too late. Well done!

Comment: This appears to use hard-coded input. Is it meant to be a function, a full program or just a snippet? If it  is a function then shouldn't it be reusable?

Comment: @JoKing this takes input via [one of the methods allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/6484).

Comment: So it's a function then? Can you reuse it? I have doubts as to whether it counts as a function when not surrounded by `{}`

Comment: I don’t think it really matters whether it’s a function, since the [input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/2455#2455) / [output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/2455#2455) methods allowed are the same. Worst case, I can change it to inputting an array of bytes from STDIN, but that’s not gonna look pretty on TIO since byte values 1‑6 are unprintables.

Comment: That rule specifies functions can take the same input as full programs, not the other way around

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
b;f(int*a){b=(b=*a++)?b%2*~-b+f(a):0;}
```

Input as 0-terminated array `a`.

Recursive function.

*-10 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwEEX3nkIEYSaOYBPjoiI9SNtFoqRkUVtK6SbYq6ejyxIH/ua/95mxvo1jjLZ34Oe3MBjsAHYQpqrwZEspvrWtHBg8Nv0SWcnvxs/wefgJs5DlfM8X1w6KcrrMeyloUx2sX85XDJoUNQv@1y1pkmmgGCXAWu9sOjpQS136k@KNZEHu4W6DegsL2GdL/AE)

Comment: Using a 0-terminated list would [save 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwEEX3nkIEIaMj2GjchJyk7SKJpLiollC6kfTq6ZhlMQN/897/jO0e1sbo0UjHlvXdaNjd5plXvTSq0W0rwbfK1Lz5doaQlyFSr3zqZWWfbZmh2IuS7uUJO1bV823NpcJUdex4db3DLnDAPsA/HlEgPxcDqRNx4MxmwguOOJ1/GmjDqcBzekpSpFABZBHiDw).

Comment: Going recursive saves [7 more bytes](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwEEX3nkIEYSaOYBPjoiI9SNtFoqRkUVtK6SbYq6ejyxIH/ua/95mxvo1jjLZ34Oe3MBjsAHYQpqrwZEspvrWtHBg8Nv0SWcnvxs/wefgJs5DlfM8X1w6KcrrMeyloUx2sX85XDJoUNQv@1y1pkmmgGCXAWu9sOjpQS136k@KNZEHu4W6DegsL2GdL/AE).

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, <s>101</s> 90 Bytes

```
@Set _=0
@For %%A in (%*) Do @For %%B in (3,5) DO @IF %%A EQU %%B Set /A _+=%%B-1
@Set _
```

11 bytes saved using Neil's suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure that the output of `SET _` counts as acceptable. But you can save some bytes by removing `@ECHO OFF` and putting the `@` at the start of each line and after `)DO @`. You can also loop over `3` and `5` using a simple `For` loop without `/L`, although doing arithmetic on the value would probably be shorter still.

Comment: Correct in the savings using @ and dropping /L. old habbits die hard. As for using 
 set to output the result, I can't say I understand why you think it wouldn't count.

Comment: I have this vague memory of seeing some answer (on a different question and in a different language) where this was an issue, so I thought it was best to seek clarification.

Comment: @Neil thanks for the worries, I would say I don't really mind :) the point is clearly computing the answer

Comment: golfed another 19 bytes off: lingering environment changes (`SET`) causing inaccurate results are not part of the answer's concern. https://pastebin.com/MikFWfG9

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 32 18bytes

```
1.."$args"|?{$_%2}
```

Example input 6 will output

```
1
3
5
```

Saved 14 bytes thanks to @mazzy

Comment: Hey, thanks for your submission! You may want to consider including a [tio](https://tio.run) link, or at least a screenshot of the results of your program for a couple of test cases! :D Ping me when you do that!

Comment: @RGS done it. Please verify! I have run it in tio and It works.

Comment: I don't understand your example output for input 6. I wanted you to include a link for your code. Try checking the other answers: the vast majority has a link in the end that you can click, to try their code.

Comment: I don't know how to add a tio link with code.

Comment: It is easy. In the [tio.run](https://tio.run) site, you choose the programming language you were using and put the code there. Then, on top of the page, there will be a couple of buttons. A triangle pointing to the right can be used to run the code. The button to the right shows a link. If you click that, you can copy a link to the code on tio! Then you just have to include it in your answer by substituting the link in this text: `[Try it online](your link here)`

Comment: you can save some bytes in your solution [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPT0klsSi9WKnGvlolXtWo9v///2YA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks so much!

Comment: While nice and short, this isn't up to spec. Goal is to take a list of numbers and for each odd, add `$_-1` to a running total. See [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200670/78849)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 29 bytes

```powershell
$args|?{$_%2}|%{$i+=$_-1}
+$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uMa@WiVe1ai2RrVaJVPbViVe17CWS1sl838tF5ehnp4ZSLwSKGwN41TYaqhU6qjEa1orgWkFXTsFJW0FDTWVNAWHCs3a2v8A)

Takes input via splatting

Comment: How can I test your submission with 3 or more inputs? :)

Comment: @RGS [Like this](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uMa@WiVe1ai2RrVaJVPbViVe17CWS1sl838tF5ehnp4ZSLwSKGwN41TYaqhU6qjEa1orgWkFXTsFJW0FDTWVNAWHCs1aoD6VCgVbBQ1DHSMdYx0THVMdMyBprMkFUfEfAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
Σm←f%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zi3EdtE9JUjf7//x9trGOmY6hjpGMKwrEA)

Direct port of my Haskell answer.

```
   f%2 Take the odd numbers
 m←    Decrement them
Σ      Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 34 bytes

```javascript
r=>r.map(i=>d+=i&1&&i>>1<<1,d=0)|d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9RC4IwFEbf@xV7mkoq3k0lyO2PRA/DZUwsZYZP/fc1JhjRcHD5ng6Hc3uxiLnVanply8l0zGjGdf4QU6wYl0emMGCsOIemgVSyInlL047PeRxu@TDe4y6@QIrgmqQoQhlHRZScD/8ACQF0A4gfKEOGagNKP1DvGqg1uPumgo@r7be2xupC0dZI3IFbuttHnXAlq3V/O8wH)

Comment: `i>>1<<1` -> `i&~1`, but since it only applies to odd numbers you can just `i^1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
~∷‹∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwifuKIt+KAueKIkSIsIiIsIlsxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA1XVxuWzIsIDRdXG5bNSwgNl0iXQ==)

```
~    # Filter by
 ∷   # Odd? 
  ‹  # Decrement
   ∑ # Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
’ḋḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZGxDgFBEIZ7T3GthHCzsxOVx/AGGvECuqNR6KgkVKJTkpxQEQ9y@yLLzJ7faeTPv/vNt3Mm4@l0FmMotlW5qspFrG7nx@W1qa6HUOyy7jALxf61HoXF6bkM8/vj2GvHmHeyXM/6rU8iJKeJNDE6r4k1SeoILIElsASWwBJYV7OkiZBcuudq1jpjRZOkjuFleBlehpfhZXh9zbImQnLJ4WvWOmMHmiR1Aq/AK/AKvAKv/O2LVfRhsOvLcaIfHHP879rAlobf2bUcC7vm6L@1qck0Bub2zKT77eAMIDug5r8h38qn3zTiDQ)

```
’      Decrement each number,
  Ḃ    and take each number mod 2.
 ḋ     Return the dot product of both vectors of results.
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 16 bytes

Prompts for vector of integers

```
+/2 4[(3 5⍳⎕)~3]
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5r6xspmERrGCuYPurdDJTTrDOO/Q@U@Z/GZahgpGCsYKJgqmAGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rR` , 13 bytes

```
÷0&(¦32⑼|54⑼™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8HYDNY1Dy4yNHk3cU2NqAiQftSz6/9/Y1NTov25REAA)

On days like these, kids like you, should be grateful that SBCS's exist. Because otherwise, this'd be 21 bytes.

Input is taken as a number with no commas. So a roll of `5, 5, 3` would be inputted as `553`.

### Explanation

```
÷           # Item split the implicit input.
0&          # Store 0 in the register.
(           # For each item in the stack:
    ¦       #   Switch statement:
    32⑼     #   If the item is 3, add 2 to the register.
    |54⑼    #   If the item is 5, add 4 to the register.
    ™       #   End switch statement.

# -rR prints the value in the register rawly. In other words, as a number.
```

Comment: What are the rR flags for?

Comment: @RGS `-rR prints the value in the register rawly. In other words, as a number.`

Comment: @RGS more accurately: at the end of the program, whatever is stored in the register will be printed as if `⑻.` had been appended to the program after autocompletion of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rabbit~](https://github.com/Ghilt/Rabbit), 31

```
_[.0{.51}{+.2}{.53}{+.4}>]_+++:
```

Explanation:

```
_                               - Move to input
 [.0                    >]      - Loop over die rolls
    {.51}{+.2}                  - If die roll is 3 add 2
              {.53}{+.4}        - If die roll is 5 add 4
                          _+++: - Move out of the way, flush and print addition result
```

51 and 53 is ascii for 3 and 5

Answer (score 1):

## [Pure data](https://puredata.info/), 401 bytes

```
#N canvas;#X obj 0 0 inlet;#X obj 0 0 list split 1;#X obj 0 0 i;#X obj 0 0 outlet;#X msg 0 0 0;#X obj 0 0 t l;#X obj 0 0 del;#X obj 0 0 expr $i2+$i1%2*($i1>>1);#X obj 0 0 i;#X connect 0 0 4 0;#X connect 0 0 5 0;#X connect 1 0 7 0;#X connect 1 1 5 0;#X connect 1 2 6 0;#X connect 2 0 3 0;#X connect 4 0 8 0;#X connect 5 0 1 0;#X connect 6 0 2 0;#X connect 7 0 8 0;#X connect 8 0 7 1;#X connect 8 0 2 1;
```

Pure Data is a graphical programming language for audio processing.

Here is what my the source looks like:

[image]

It is pretty unreadable since I saved bytes by placing all elements at coordinate `0 0`.  Here it is reorganized so you can read the elements.

[image]

It is important to note that execution in pure data sometimes depends on the order in which objects were created, which is not visible in images like this.  For this answer to work The `inlet` object must be connected to the `0` message *before* the `t 1` object.  This shows up in the source code as that connection being earlier on.

Most of the program is just list processing.  The logic is actually handled in the `expr` block

```
#X obj 0 0 expr $i2+$i1%2*($i1>>1);
```

Here `$i1` is the current element and `$i2` is the result of the last `expr`.  So this bitshifts the element down by one, which is intended result for odd numbers.  To make even numbers we then multiply it by its 2 modulus, which is zero for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers.

---

Thanks to [0 '](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20059/0) for working on this with me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
g2%k1-S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbL041Usw11gyE8qOCCZdHGOgqmsRAeAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's MathGolf answer.

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
D2%s1-z*S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrXYxUiw11q7SCIXyo8IJl0cY6CqaxEB4A)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanations

```python
g2%k1-S  # Implicit input
g  k     # Filter for those which are:
 2%      #  Odd
    1-   # Subtract one from each
      S  # Sum

D2%s1-z*S  # Implicit input
D2%        # Duplicate and mod by 2
   s1-     # Swap and subtract one
      z*   # Multiply
        S  # Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ɗ$⁻×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lQzklOTclMjQlRTIlODElQkIlQzMlOTcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDMiUyQzMlMkM0JTJDNSUyQzYmZmxhZ3M9Uw==)

##### Explanation

```python
ɗ$⁻×  # Implicit input
ɗ     # Mod each item by 2
 $    # Push the input again
  ⁻   # Decrement each item
   ×  # Multiply elementwise
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 29 bytes

```javascript
r=>r.map(i=>d+=i%2*--i,d=0)|d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/yNauSC83sUAj09YuRds2U9VIS1c3UyfF1kCzJuV/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0oY6CYaymjoK6gq6dgoG6pjUXpgIjQgqM4QqMsCswIWSCKVyBCXYFZnhNMAaaAEYIpxpiU2cG9C3QNUDjCDkaaKIRGBmCSWO87jMGGwhRaQohUd3xHwA)