# Tips for golfing in Scala 3

Tags: code-golf, tips, scala

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Scala 3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/)? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Scala 3 (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Also see [Tips for golfing in Scala](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala)

Comment: I'm willing to award a bounty if any answers this question. (100 if it's trivial or if it expands on one of the tips I've put here already, and 200 if it's really good). [Bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19322/95792)

Answer (score 2):

## Use [parameter untupling](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html)

Parameter untupling allows you to write functions accepting a single tuple as input as if they were functions accepting 2 parameters. Basically, you can replace these

```scala
list.map{case(a,b)=>a+b}
//and
list.map{case(a,b)=>Seq(a,b)}
//or
list.map(t=>t._1+t._2)
//and
list.map(t=>Seq(t._1,t._2))
```

with this, which is both shorter and more beautiful.

```scala
list.map(_+_)
//and
list.map(Seq(_,_))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use @main and toplevel functions

If you need to make a full program, use the `@main` annotation on a toplevel main method.

```
@main def m={code}
```

It's a lot shorter than these 2 approaches:

```
object M extends App{code}
object M{def main(a:Array[String])={code}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Optional braces

In match expressions, at least, you can save a byte by using indentation-based syntax.

```
a match
case b=>c
case d=>e
```

is 27 bytes, while the below code is 28.

```
a match{case b=>c case d=>e}
```

As a side note, `match` also gets special treatment when it comes to chaining. The following Scala 2 code:

```
("foo"match{case x=>x})match{case x=>x}
```

can now be written without the parentheses:

```
"foo"match{case x=>x}match{case x=>x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Leave out `new` with [universal apply methods](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/creator-applications.html)

You can call constructors without using `new` (like Kotlin), treating all classes as if they have `apply` methods in their companions. This saves 4 bytes every time you instantiate something, since `new Foo()` becomes just `Foo()`.

This also applies to givens (although you rarely need them for code golf):

```scala
given foo as Foo=new Foo() //bad
given foo as Foo=Foo()     //better
given foo as Foo           //great
```

Answer (score 1):

## Numeric Literals

Edit: As @stewSquared pointed out, this only works in experimental releases now

You can now write a [number literal](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/numeric-literals.html) for any user-defined type with a given/implicit instance of the `FromDigits` trait, such as `BigInt` and `BigDecimal`.

In Scala 2, to pass the number 9,999,999,999,999,999 to a function accepting `BigInt`s, you would have to use `BigInt("9999999999999999")`, but now you can just directly say `9999999999999999` without using the apply method or constructor explicitly.

You can also use underscores, scientific notation, hex, etc., just like any normal number literal, as long as the `FromDigits` instance for that type supports that notation, of course. Both `BigInt` and `BigDecimal` are okay with underscores, but only `BigInt` allows hex, and only `BigDecimal` allows scientific notation (with decimals).

Comment: It would be interesting (and worth mentioning) if `1e9` typechecks when used as `BigInt`, since scientific notation is usually treated as a float literal, not int, and typechecked as such. Hex is also a thing when used for large enough integers.

Comment: @Bubbler Yup, fixed it. Unfortunately, they only allow the same format as ordinary `Int`s and `Double`s (afaik)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true in 2022 with Scala 3.2.0. Ohhh wait it's an experimental feature that can't be used in the main release.

Comment: @stewSquared Aww, didn't notice that. When I wrote the answer, either experimental features were still available in the main release or this wasn't considered an experimental feature. I'll edit the answer to state that

Answer (score 0):

## Use match types for recursive functions that pattern match

Making a typealias with a match type is sometimes shorter than using a proper function. For example, take this implementation of the KI calculus (not an actual thing). The type doesn't need `:Any`, so you save 7 bytes in all (`type` is 1 byte more than `def`).

```scala
//A normal function
def r(t:Any):Any=t match{case(('K',x),y)=>r(x)case('I',x)=>r(x)case t=>t}
//With match types
type R[T]=T match{case(('K',x),y)=>R[x]case('I',x)=>R[x]case _=>T}
```

Admittedly, in this particular example, you could use auto-tupling, `->`, pattern-matching function literals, etc. to make the def shorter, but this is just one case. When you're not dealing with tuples, or the return type is more complex than just `Any`, or you have multiple parameters, this tip becomes more useful.

## Use type constructors for two-argument functions

When you define a type with two type parameters, you can treat it like an infix operator. Not so for methods. Suppose you have the following two definitions

```
def>(a:Int,b:Int)=...
type +[A,B]=...
```

When you invoke `>`, you can call it with `>(a,b)`, whereas for `+`, you can call it like `A+B`. You can use any other operator you want if you want a specific precedence.

Answer (score 0):

## New Control Syntax

In most cases, the new control syntax doesn't shorten code (and is actually more verbose), it comes in handy in for comprehensions. If your expression or pattern ends or starts with a parentheses or double quote, you can save a byte or two:

```scala
for((x,y,z)<-Seq((1,2,3),(3,4,5));y<-"foo")yield y+x  //Old-style syntax
for(x,y,z)<-Seq((1,2,3),(3,4,5));y<-"foo"yield y+x    //New control syntax
```

It's not as useful as some other things, like parameter untupling, but I often find myself using for comprehensions for function calls like `f(foo)` or `Seq(1,2)`, which end in parentheses.

See it run in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/E00ZMRqzTpiwQG04sfwu4A).