# Find the "Bittiest" Number

Tags: code-golf, binary

### The Challenge

Given a list of integers, the "bittiest" number among them is the one with the most bits on - that is, the largest amount of bits set to 1 in its 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

Write a function (or a program) that takes as input a list of integers between \$ -2^{31} \$ and \$ 2^{31}-1 \$ (the range of 32-bit signed integers) and returns as output the "bittiest" number among them.

You may assume the list has at least one item.

### Test Cases

```
1, 2, 3, 4 => 3
123, 64, 0, -4 => -4
7, 11 => either 7 or 11
1073741824, 1073741823 => 1073741823
```

Good Luck!

This is code golf, so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: From the `123, 64, 0, -4` example, I'm assuming you're representing negative numbers with a leading `1` bit?

Comment: Yes, standard two's complement representation.

Comment: Also, in that test case, why isn't the answer `123`? Aren't the representations `0b01111011, 0b01000000, 0b00, 0b1100`, so `123` has more `1`s?

Comment: I specified the input is given as 32-bit signed integers. Two's complement of `4` is 30 consecutive ones followed by 2 zeroes (`11111111111111111111111111111100`)

Comment: If our language has no 32-bit signed integers should we accept integers (and perform manipulations) or may we accept a list of ones and zeros (what a 32-bit signed integer actually is under the hood)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan A 32-bit signed integer is a primitive data type - a building block of software. It's very unlikely a language doesn't support it, but if it really doesn't you may use an unsigned 32-bit integer in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation or a 4-byte array (per number).

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this doesn't actually have a scoring criterion...

Comment: @UnrelatedString As always in code golf, the shortest program to fulfill the request wins. I'll add that explicitly to the question.

Comment: May we output all "bittiest" numbers, e.g. `[7, 11]` for the 3rd test case?

Comment: I'd suggest adding larger test cases where it matters that we're using 32-bit signed integers for two's complement, and not say 16 or 64.

Comment: @Bip, one of the standard rules around here is not to assume anything about the functionality of a language.  There are languages where integers are unsigned, other sizes, or don't exist at all.  It's not necessarily a primitive data type.

Comment: I think a clearer way to specify the challenge without [making language assumptions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/20260) is to say the input is a list of integers between `-2^31` and `2^31-1`, and we output one whose 32-bit signed representation has the most 1's.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you intend for languages that don't have 32-bit signed integers, or where integers aren't that by default. For negative numbers, should the input be a negative number in whatever form the language provides? Or do we take in the bit representations of the 32-bit signed integer, say as four-bytes or the integer with that representation in our language's encoding?

Comment: Sounds like we've to output the _h"onest" number_ :p

Comment: @Xcali as I've written, "you may use an unsigned 32-bit integer in two's complement representation or a 4-byte array (per number)". Use any representation you like as long as it goes from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1 using two's complement for negatives.

Comment: I'm confused with the clarification. Python 3, for instance, uses unbounded integers by default. Does "any other representation" then allow us to represent a number as a list of 32 bits, using two's complement for negative numbers? If so, we could just `sum` each input value to gets its count of 1's.

Comment: 1) Can we input/output in string format? 2) Suggested testcase: `2147483647` and `-1073741824` yields `2147483647`

Comment: Just say "highest (binary) Hamming weight"

Comment: @qwr But then its inverse would not be the "itty-bittiest number".

Comment: I've read the Q & comments and I don't understand where clarity is needed. Also, all those who had close-voted the question did not comment on what needs clarifying.

Comment: @BMF Yeah, I don't understand what more I can clarify - and who do I ask to reopen the question. Seems like the question is closed for good.

Comment: @Bip it's a shame because this is one of those simple challenges that newbie golfers/programmers like myself might find fun

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the challenge anymore. The questions in the comments have all been answered from what I could see. I've voted to re-open (just like with the close-votes, five are necessary to re-open it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 8 bytes

```
%Ø%B§µÞṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//JcOYJULCp8K1w57huar///9bMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgLTRd)

### Explanation

```
     µÞ  | sort input by
%Ø%      | modulo by 2^32 (Ø% is a quick for 2^32)
   B     | converted to binary
    §    | sum
       Ṫ | get the last
```

Edit: thank you all for the kind response to my first question! I think I've fixed it now, it seems to work for all test cases.

### Original code

```
2*31
B%¢S€iṀị
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer! Don't usually see first posts in Jelly :p

Comment: I think the `%¢` should be before the B. And you can use `§` instead of `S€`.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is that `iṀ` will search for the maximum of the *original* list.

Comment: While you edited the answer, the "Try it online" link still uses the previous, incorrect code. Consider updating it.

Answer (score 26):

## x86 Machine Language, 18 bytes

```
31 D2 AD F3 0F B8 F8 39 FA 77 03 87 FA 93 E2 F2 93 C3
```

The above bytes define a function that accepts the address of the array in the `esi` register and the number of elements in the array in the `ecx` register, and returns the "bittiest" number in the array in the `eax` register.

Note that this is a custom calling convention that accepts arguments in the `ecx` and `esi` registers, but it is otherwise much like a C function that takes the length of the array and a pointer to the array as its two arguments. This custom calling convention treats all registers as caller-save, including `ebx`.

The implementation of this function pulls some dirty tricks, which assume that the array has at least 1 element, as provided for in the challenge. It also assumes that the direction flag (`DF`) is clear (`0`), which is standard in all calling conventions that I'm aware of.

In ungolfed assembly-language mnemonics:

```
; ecx = length of array
; esi = address of first element in array
Find:
    31 D2          xor    edx, edx                ; start with max bit count set to 0
Next:
    AD             lods   eax, DWORD PTR [esi]    ; load the next value from the array, and
                                                  ;   increment ptr by element size
    F3 0F B8 F8    popcnt edi, eax                ; count # of set bits in value
    39 FA          cmp    edx, edi                ; if # of set bits in value is less than
    77 03          ja     SHORT Skip              ;   the running maximum, skip next 2 insns
    87 FA          xchg   edx, edi                ; save current # of set bits (for comparisons)
    93             xchg   eax, ebx                ; save current array value (for comparisons)
Skip:
    E2 F2          loop   SHORT Next              ; decrement element count, looping until it is 0
    93             xchg   eax, ebx                ; move running maximum value to eax
    C3             ret                            ; return, with result in eax
```

The key feature of this code is, of course, the x86 `popcnt` instruction, which counts the number of set bits in an integer. It iterates through the input array, keeping track of both the value of the maximum element and the number of set bits that it contains. It checks each value in the array to see if its number of set bits is higher than any value it has seen before. If so, it updates the tracking values; if not, it skips this step.

The `popcnt` instruction is a large (4-byte) instruction, but there's nothing that can be done to avoid that. However, the very short (1-byte) `lods` instruction has been used to load values from the array while simultaneously incrementing the pointer, the short (2-byte) `loop` instruction has been used for loop control (automatically decrementing the element counter and looping as long as there are more elements remaining to go through), and the very short (1-byte) `xchg` instruction has been used throughout.

An extra `xchg` had to be used at the end in order to enable use of the `lods` instruction, which *always* loads into the `eax` register, but that trade-off is more than worth it.

### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNdb5swFH0ev@LKFRKkzhKg27SkdKq67EOa@tBU06YSRQSc1BsBhM2EFuWvL7ONaUnDUo0o2D4@59zry3XUj5IwXe12NOXwgaaxJSfR1zApCcMQZSnjIKAe5DVmGxsDxCNpZFFhILF6UfEKq7Ham89Dtp7PLRSkAa@yIgEwTcVTQ5AiRWsedE0qbvqjAzzgSRazpAPPszxKeSL9Qm1LO2jROk/kVO3/K3rAf4T1dPqT5qbfQaii@1XyvE@LtqizChXthdqv3btPmeX1oq7Ef1i3WCNA/gKBJQh2G8cCjyUeH@LvFU4P8FDi4T5f@EcIwNLNYcOgJ7ogLzkUZEUZJwVQBpOrb9AbPPGbSl1@XDf9/EQ3gvbKrlurILws0rrVtrsTmkZJGRM4Zzym2cv7C8M4icmSpgQub24uv8@/TK4/3n6ywqKwhdpi9DfJlmo50POeXNiG8SujMdwSxp@7Abju/SonESexvg95IcClhTaA6kyXWQHKiYIPw7EYzhvTMZye1iXf6BM2apOZMcJCB@9AjEjWHNm4iXxHZ7X5VoUsObMQbGVAQ9/IgrAy4SKiusoPh2hKP26nGnD58y/AjMFkopmwlosErMbIfzyozCmoJm5Qvb0Sf09l1wJeIVsE2BqGITNZhzS1dHEeaghc1Hd4NxMJbsDB4GLwMJzBdnxIcxqaKyivzzAMMfS7qa6mvsHgOJ0MTzP6ant/vzmgpngyjDTCLbbqi72OUicRn0aN@NFkqD9Rt8LRCqelcI4qXK1wWwr3qMLTCq@l8Ga6SfT9Gcrb8ydaJuGK7Xb9tef@BQ)

My first attempt was a 20-byte function. So far, 18 bytes is the best I have been able to come up with. I'm curious to see if anyone else can beat this score!

The only route of improvement that I see would be if a `LOOPA` instruction existed. Unfortunately, it doesn't—the only condition codes supported by `LOOP` are `E`/`Z` and `NE`/`NZ`. But maybe someone else can stretch their mind further than me!

Comment: `xchg   edx, edi` could be a more efficient `mov   edx, edi` for no change in code size, but that's not worth editing for.  This same machine code also works in 64-bit mode, with 64-bit pointers / count, and still an array of uint32_t.  I don't see any further savings, but maybe we're both missing something.

Comment: In 64-bit mode, this code can be called from C as `int bittiest(int dummy_edi, const int32_t *arr /*RSI*/, int dummy_edx, size_t size /*RCX*/);` following the x86-64 System V calling convention except for clobbering EBX. (Avoiding that would cost extra bytes for r8d, or push/pop).  You could save a byte by returning in EBX instead of EAX: [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020)

Comment: @Peter I assume you mean that `mov edx, edi` would be more efficient than the equivalent `xchg`, without requiring any more bytes to encode? Yeah, that's a good point. I didn't even think of that. I would never use `xchg` for anything but code golf, and since I was already planning to use it for the 1-byte encoding using the accumulator, I just over-eagerly used it everywhere. Indeed, the code works well with 64-bit; I had originally written it that way, then decided that there was no good reason to pay the instruction size penalty. In 64-bit mode, though, you get more caller-save registers.

Comment: Yes, clumsy phrasing on my part when I re-read it, but it parses like "`xchg edx,edi` could have been (replaced with / instead) `mov edx, edi` (which is more efficient)".

Comment: Regarding returning in `EBX`, I felt like that was pushing things a bit *too* far, since literally every x86 calling convention that exists returns results in `EAX`. I don't mind defining my own calling conventions for passing parameters, but I like to stick as close as possible to something that is reasonable, even when golfing. Maybe that's just my own idiosyncrasies. It really bothers me when people submit golfing entries that rely on compiler-specific behavior, like omitting a "return".

Comment: Oh yeah, I strongly dislike C answers that omit a return because that makes them unusable in real life (optimization enabled) in the answer's language.  It has to be *really* clever in some other way for me to upvote in that case.  But as I argued in the codegolf tip I linked, imagine you're writing a whole program in pure asm, and this is one function.  You 100% can call functions that use arbitrary conventions. (Providing a couple different return values can be a *good* thing, e.g. `strcmp` mismatch position as well as +/0/-. It's stupid that C doesn't do that.)

Comment: Return in EBX might hurt most hand-written golfed asm programs overall, but I see it as perfectly valid to leave the return value anywhere the caller can use it conveniently.  (e.g. a boolean in FLAGS like \*BSD and MacOS syscalls).  And to clobber as many regs as I want.  But I don't have any problem with you choosing different standards for what you think is sane or the kind of problem-space you want to golf in; that's just how *I* think about it, in a way that makes sense to me while still agreeing with you about that lame trend to golf in "unoptimized-gcc" instead of standard GNU C.

Comment: I would have used two CMOVs instead of the branch, but it saves no bytes.

Comment: @peterferrie The `CMOV` instruction is encoded with 3 bytes, thus two `CMOV` instructions would have increased the total byte count of the submission by 1. `CMOV` is rarely a win when optimizing for size, as we do when playing code golf, *especially* when a one-byte `XCHG` instruction can be used (the one-byte form is the special encoding available when one of the operands is the accumulator register).

Comment: Also, I'm with @PeterCordes about returning in `ebx` as being completely okay in the rules. You should go ahead and take your extra -1 byte for this great answer!

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>49 48 47</s>  45 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @user81655*

```javascript
a=>a.sort(g=(p,q)=>!p|-!q||g(p&p-1,q&q-1))[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxCoMwFIDhvad4LpLAixoNFgrxCj2AOASroUVMYmKn3D2Vdin@8/e/1Fv5cXvawFbzmNIsk5KdKrzZAtGSWHRUdpmNLHMxamJzyzi63DFOaV8NaTSrN8tULEaTmfQcoUZoEMRAKXwrS7jvwe7hBs3lzOuDtgKhQmC/5Y8zcfZXBM4Plj4)

#### How?

We `.sort()` the input list with a recursive function that, given `p` and `q`, clears the least significant bit set in each variable until one of them is equal to 0 (or both of them simultaneously). This allows to order the list from most to least bits set. We then return the first entry, i.e. the "bittiest" one.

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                 // a[] = input list
  a.sort(            // sort a[] ...
    g = (p, q) =>    // ... using the recursive function g:
      !p | -!q       //     -> +1 if p = 0 and q ≠ 0,
                     //     or -1 if q = 0,
      ||             //     or  0 if p ≠ 0 and q ≠ 0, in which case ...
        g(           //     ... we do a recursive call:
          p & p - 1, //       clear the least significant bit set in p
          q & q - 1  //       clear the least significant bit set in q
        )            //     end of recursive call
  )[0]               // end of sort(); return the first entry
```

Comment: Would `!p|-!q||g(p&p-1,q&q-1)` work?

Comment: @user81655 Nice! The main difference is that `q` is considered to have less bits set than `p` when they actually have as many bits set. But this is compatible with the challenge rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

Saved many bytes thanks to Adam and ngn.

```apl
{⊃⍒+⌿⍵⊤⍨32⍴2}⊃⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR13Nj3onaT/q2f@od@ujriWPelcYGz3q3WJUC5LpWvT/Ud9UoLo0BUMjYwUzEwUDhUPrTbjggjoKRjoKxjoKCCFzBUPD/wA)

Comment: Is the byte count correct? The code line above has 15 characters and TIO shows 17 characters

Comment: @Graham I accidentally subtracted 2 twice, now it should be okay.

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>80</s></sup> 77 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!

```c
#define b __builtin_popcount(f(n,l
f(n,l)int*l;{n=--n?f(n,l+(b))<b+1)))):*l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJhb4IwEIa/8ysuLCYUSiboZiYyPyz7FZMYgbI1Y8VYTMgMv51dW1DUNaGlfd57C3eX@Z9Z1nUPOSu4YJDCdpseeVlzsd1X@6w6itopHEFLS8@Ei9oto5OIfV@s9ZHnpISsUi8gOJYI225/QJmjpFBSwBUEgZMFOIrqoABwiGEa4bICEYHncaKxGjq6cOyJnOQ2BYevcbaXtk0olB88IZHVWsrjZ8eFQyxjrA6gZrKefiTofQoohBRmFOZtdC0IekGI8HlOYUrBvxOFRrSgEAQX5momDdOXUWNplvDWRRil5L@sKhwdQB77nWu2FEY0uKbBNQ2vaUhG17Fmz7Ka5ebCmfolCotekH3tDi7OLPtmB6OwN817uGle3vB5Uvkd7Wc2xg3VAlMukbOmL5l@XQ0fNlx8@bbzia6rUg/Fv2QRrUwmNU@iMQYQPRZ32HRWTbGhbmIkxqh@hPqWMCTn9PxriM0G/itMcpjIjcBsSHrOFotjmfSWrdV2fw)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZJhb4IwEIa/8ysuLCYUSiboZiYyPyz7FZMYgbI1Y8VYTMgMv51dW1DUNaGlfd57C3eX@Z9Z1nUPOSu4YJDCdpseeVlzsd1X@6w6itopHEFLS8@Ei9oto5OIfV@s9ZHnpISsUi8gOJYI225/QJmjpFBSwBUEgZMFOIrqoABwiGEa4bICEYHncaKxGjq6cOyJnOQ2BYevcbaXtk0olB88IZHVWsrjZ8eFQyxjrA6gZrKefiTofQoohBRmFOZtdC0IekGI8HlOYUrBvxOFRrSgEAQX5momDdOXUWNplvDWRRil5L@sKhwdQB77nWu2FEY0uKbBNQ2vaUhG17Fmz7Ka5ebCmfolCotekH3tDi7OLPtmB6OwN817uGle3vB5Uvkd7Wc2xg3VAlMukbOmL5l@XQ0fNlx8@bbzia6rUg/Fv2QRrUwmNU@iMQYQPRZ32HRWTbGhbmIkxqh@hPqWMCTn9PxriM0G/itMcpjIjcBsSHrOFotjmfSWrdV2fw), returning the first rather than last occurence.

Comment: nice use of __builtin_popcount, I bet this one is the fastest and can be used to compile to the smallest machine code.

Comment: @att Nice recursive one - thanks! :-)

Comment: I was working on [this](https://tio.run/##bYxBDsIgFET3nOJHYwINNVG7Q72ImgZoVZL2twJdEc6O0Lh0FrOYN3m6fmmd0tagHpauh7Pz3WDU/n0lmhr0FfLSIwu294tFaFu1mMEbbOdp1tOCnmZa/5uRiUhUsUAliwYcCx83WU8ld7zhmomftZIipvIYpUHKIBDIKYO8PS7hwOHI4cShiWIla802H550s@vuuOGgsrVhTJCYvg), but your's is much golfier. +1

Comment: @Anunay: `__builtin_popcount` is fast, especially if you compile for a target that can do it in one instruction (like `-march=native` on modern x86), but this is recursive and is calling it at least twice per number I think?  Along with being doubly recursive.   For smallest machine code, Cody's iterative x86 machine code answer is clearly going to be better than even `gcc -Os -march=haswell` or `clang -Oz -march=haswell` compiling this, and probably also faster: one popcnt and one cmp/branch per iteration.  Although Cody's does use the slow `loop` instruction...

Comment: @Anunay: I checked on https://godbolt.org/z/1zW5Pq: clang -Oz compiles it to just a `ret` because there's no `return` statement; this answer is taking advantage of that silly hack of gcc evaluating an expression in the return-value register in debug builds.  But once we fix that so we can enable optimization we get quite a bit of code, gcc `-Os -march=sandybridge` compiles it to 69 bytes of x86-64 machine code, clang -Oz to 66.  A simple iterative C implementation would make smaller asm, maybe at worst double Cody's 18-bytes of hand-golfed x86-64 machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Anunay is talking about [this code](https://tio.run/##bZLRboIwFIbveYoTEhKKJQN0W2ZFL5Y9hRIjULZmUAhgQmZ4dtZSUFBJaGm///ynnNPI/o6irgtJRhhJzBRzxHhtpeSS5KWZ@Q7htk0yP9xmO@ZzHK4zFPrHY3hmac34sciLKD/z2kz3PEAk9NM9C0jbFaWwMaUVpBjEDBzBRQPxSGO5wcAHh4hpA5zAYsFQj@XTRyemblRGrGMw2U6M@lrXEQaZABGt1aRHdmLcRJoylhtQ06p29oHwvrgYPAxLDKuWzAXuIPAEfFthcDDYDyJPid4xuO6NWT2rFOuTYWWpJu/ehStlxf5onph9AHoZVpZaYphQd07dOfXm1EOTdLQpaFTTWCVcyl@aHD36OZWWGGn0S0sl0Q/Nl3doPj7F@yoLPFkvdRE3tgtUv3hMm6Fn/edmPNmY@Xa4607fWKkeu38ro7BSpex5QKYYgA@YP2B1tWosbtRdTCVikqeECnKtz1NDcdvA3oIRg1EduKhGha/Vor5fBYNlq7XdPw), before Cody posted.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, I forgot to look at edit history and timestamps for major changes to *this* answer.  Makes sense it was from before there was a machine-code answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, this was before there was the machine code answer, I actually tried to code golf in assembly (to assemble to x86) when i found out about popcnt from this.

Answer (score 7):

## [C++ (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>145</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>135</s> <s>134</s> <s>133</s> <s>130</s> <s>128</s> 116 bytes

145->141 thanks to user
128->116 thanks to ceilingcat

```
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
int i,b,v,c;main(){for(;std::cin>>i;b<c?b=c,v=i:0)c=std::bitset<32>(i).count();std::cout<<v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoIwEEX3fkUTN20oyCua0IffQkfBSaAlMLAx/roVjetzzr0wTWkPEOMRxynMpB3SclroBkmSPewBPTGUTm4S1Nii5@LZhZmr3WgaQG8tKqfh6gzIzWCTCzA/9t25k65Ky1FkEFZPXPyzsJLWm3rFWJQVO9csZ2n9hm5o@yWmu2P29@LyAQ)

Comment: [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYzLCoMwFAX3fkWgmwRN8UUL5vEv5hrtBY3SRLsQf71pqdDlGWYOLAsfAGK8oINx7aw0GLwNOvkDnH142nbSydSio2xHFwhmRuUZZJsQrweOlvrQNQ2g0xrZ/hvnkaxK7SkyAcpfYV5doExgT40EthsFYlMojuPM5zVIuYkjxqKsyK0mOeH1G/qxHXzkX0dBmhb3Dw) by removing spaces after `#include` and by declaring `c` with `i,b,v`. Also, you can use a method instead of accepting input from STDIN and printing it.

Comment: Thanks @user was able to strip another byte after adding your suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to the site, nice first answer! :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>41</s> <s>38</s> 29 bytes

Correct code with much fewer bytes :) { Thanks @vrintle }

```
{it.maxBy{it.countOneBits()}}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/TXODGPxpM)

---

```
{it.maxBy{it.toByte().countOneBits()}}
```

[Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Isc4eXZOB)

---

```
{it.maxBy{it.toString(2).count{it=='1'}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoJAEIbP7VPMzR1YpTUpiDQIOgRBh55gi6wh3RUdoxCf3bYQ6vbxffwzd8cF2SFvLZSGrEToREENH3IpJiNoBbGCmYIE1U/GXswTBVMF4X9YKNAaBUa5q7fmfIMOyFYtQ5iJhyngRMx0aZYg936w2lnO0DfwsIZ06Iij0jw3rw@wO3JN9ipjjM6utexlmgY66Pt@qHzhwsrxoPx@QfTlDQ)

Comment: Welcome to the site, nice first answer! However, it fails on the second test case. [Here is a 50 byter](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoJAEIbP@RRzcwdWaU0KIg2CDkHQIXqATbKW1lV0jEJ8dptCqNvH9/HP3Euyxg1566DQxgmEzrOmoUMuvMkISkIkYSYhRvmTEYt5LGEqIfgPCwlKoYdhXtZbnd2gA@OqliBIvYe2cDZE5tIsQex5sNo5SpEbMKwhGTpDYaGfm9cHqDyxFshwpNq4q4gwzMrWEdck8ZXf9/1QcSHrxHhZfN8hcnkD "Kotlin – Try It Online") alternative to it ;-)

Comment: -3 bytes: {maxBy{it.countOneBits()}} (you can make the type List<Int>.() -> Int? instead)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ΣžJ%b1¢}θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OKj@7xUkwwPLao9t@P//2hDI2MdBTMTHQUDHQVdk1gA)

```
ΣžJ%b1¢}θ  # full program
        θ  # last element of...
           # implicit input...
Σ          # sorted in increasing order by...
      ¢    # number of...
     1     # ones...
      ¢    # in...
           # (implicit) current element in list...
   %       # modulo...
 žJ        # 4294967296...
    b      # in binary
           # implicit output
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be modulo 2^32 instead of 2^31?

Comment: @xigoi Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think _Makonede_ correctly uses `žI` instead of your suggested `žJ`. The challenge speaks of _signed_ 32-bit integers, so the range \$[-2147483648,2147483647]\$. The \$2^{32}\$ you suggest would be for _unsigned_  32-bit integers, with the range \$[0,4294967295]\$.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen If I'm not mistaken, the two's complement representation of a signed integer n is an unsigned integer that equals n for positive n and 2^32 + n for negative n.

Comment: Here's a simple C program to test it out: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44LVSivBCQGpBRyEzPzNDQVqrkUgAAoYGwUX6KQp2CroGtiDRYrKAKKpmkoqZYq6SjkaVpz1f7/DwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xigoi Ahh. I was thinking in the wrong direction when I made my comment earlier. Thanks for the added C program as example, now it's clearer what you meant and where my error lies. In that case the 05AB1E program above is indeed slightly incorrect, but can be fixed without changing the byte-count by changing the `žI` to `žJ`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the tip, and doesn't that also invalidate [the Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216654/94066) that I based this off?

Comment: You should tank @xigoi, not me. :) And yes, that Python answer is also incorrect in that case. The `2**31` should be `2**32`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Apparently a lot of answers made this mistake, but mostly it doesn't affect the byte count.

Comment: @xigoi I see, haha

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{*x@>+/2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlqrwsFOW98opqL2f5qCoZGxgpmJgoGCrgkXkKdgpGCsAGKZKxga/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```r
function(x)x[order(colSums(sapply(x,intToBits)<1))][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCsyI6vygltUgjOT8nuDS3WKM4saAgp1KjQiczryQk3ymzpFjTxlBTMzbaMPZ/mkayhqGRsY6CmYmOgoGOgq6JpuZ/AA)

[-2 thanks to Robin Ryder](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCsyK6PCMzOUMvN7FCIzk/J7g0t1ijOLGgIKdSo0InM68kJN8ps6RY085AUzP2f5pGsoaZjrmOoaGm5n8A)

-1 thanks to Dominic van Essen.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCsyK6PCMzOUMvN7FCIzk/J7g0t1ijOLGgIKdSo0InM68kJN8ps6RY085AUzP2f5pGsoaZjrmOoaGm5n8A "R – Try It Online"), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @RobinRyder i assumed `sapply` wouldn't return a matrix for length one input!

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCsyI6vygltUgjOT8nuDS3WKM4saAgp1KjQiczryQk3ymzpFjTxlBTMzbaMPZ/mkayhqGRsY6CmYmOgoGOgq6JpuZ/AA)...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen very nice, thanks.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You should add that as a [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4024/86301)!

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é·║⌂╞8Q⌡ë♀NM╟¥É▌╦!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82faba7fc63851f5890c4e4dc79d90ddcb21&i=%5B1,2,3,4%5D%0A%5B123,+64,+0,+-4%5D%0A%5B7,+11%5D&m=2)

Manually pads with 1s/0s to get the correct representation.

Displays a single number for each testcase.

Comment: winner for most interesting to look at :)

Comment: there are a variety of answers provided here that use characters I've never seen in used in code before.... I wonder what they're all about.  Are they unique to "golfing" languages?

Comment: @alec in order to make commands as short as possible, each language developer make a [codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) so they can fit a lot of commands within a single byte. Stax uses [CP437](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md), which has a lot of weird unrelated characters, including box drawing characters, which makes it look rather distinctive.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
lambda l:max(l,key=lambda n:bin(n%2**31).count("1"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1RC4IwHMTf/RSHEGzxL5qTBGGfZO1hK6WRTrEF2ZdfGkL3cA/34@7GOd6HIFOrLqmzvbtZdHVv36yjRzOrLQq184GFXbHfS8GP1@EVIstFznmKzTNCQWtBKAiSUBrKsEmLYknOJeFEOCwEf1QRhDAmy9phgiU4@ICPH9k6SdBybRAqw@tfaZz88toyywmrQyk4jvQF)

`n%2**31` - since in python integers are infinite, have to change negative numbers. for example `-4` becomes `2147483644`

`bin(...)` - translate to binary format

`count("1")` - count the number of units

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda n:n and n%2+z(n//b)
f=lambda l:max(l,key=z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwFET3nmI2hYR@sFFpQchJ0iwSVCrVr9gsai6fqgidxSze8GZew2viMkX9TIMbfePANcNxA74U1yg4z73MOn2OQz26rxjo3a46yhTaT4CGMYpQEEpCZSnDGaOKjdwrws0S/vhBUMraLOumBY7g0TNiP4v9jmA26TAfVtaHNS89B9EJJwl7Q2t4ifQD)

two bytes shorter, but doesn't work with negative numbers

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <strike>54</strike> <strike>42</strike> <strike>40</strike> 36 bytes

Saved some bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing, didymus, user, and [some tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala)

```scala
_.maxBy(_.toBinaryString.count(48<))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBC4IwAEbv@xXfcYMpaVIhGeStswSBSCxTMXTWXJKIv30tukWnB@/B63PRCNNdbkWucZoIIdeiRCtqSYWq@hB7pcSYJlrVsspYiKOsNSJMBBhEgzJEUjzSg9QZoh0sbSTm7LbiFY/07OourqVQ4/fg5t1TahpstowZQu7W6UbSktoJ9Th8jiVHwBj7bb71q4BjweH86WsOz/toMs/GOEPzBg)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Scala page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/tips-for-golfing-in-scala)!

Comment: I was super afraid I was doing something wrong and I completely missed that page. Thanks

Comment: You can reduce the size by one, if you replace `'1'` with `49`.

Comment: Replacing `_=='1'` with `_>48`, reduces size by 2 bytes

Comment: @didymus Great!

Comment: Nice answer! You can get [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYxBC4IwAEbv@xXfcYMpaVIhGeStswSBSCxTMXTWXJKIv30tukWnB@/B63PRCNNdbkWucZoIIdeiRCtqSYWq@hB7pcSYJlrVsspYiKOsNSJMBBhEgzJEUjzSg9QZoh0sbSTm7LbiFY/07OourqVQ4/fg5t1TahpstowZQu7W6UbSktoJ9Th8jiVHwBj7bb71q4BjweH86WsOz/toMs/GOEPzBg) with underscores and postfix syntax.

Comment: Actually, make that [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYxBC4IwAIXv@xXvOGFGmhQIBtWpswSBSMyasliz5pJE/O1rXqPT472P93VXrrhrq7u4WpxHQshN1HhwqSk3TZdiZwwfitwaqZsySHHS0iLDSICeK9QpcvEqjtqWyLbw6SFxF6/47Ie5i0aYRSXtoX1r6wh5epNVmtbUH2nEEDOsGJIgCH5Z7Pd1wrBkCP/wDUMUzTOZJufCXn0B) using `Integer.bitCount`.

Comment: @user excellent! But would this still count as _my_ answer?

Comment: Well, the 24 byte version is a bit different, so if you feel uncomfortable editing that into your answer, I'll make a new one with it, but the 36 byter still counts as your answer, in my opinion - all I did was turn `l=>l` into `_` and `_>48` into `48<`.

Comment: Agreed, I'd like the 24 bits one to be your answer, and thanks.

Comment: There's also a [Tips for golfing in Dotty](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210491/95792) question if you want to try out Scala 3. Feel free to add more answers there, since I'm literally the only one interacting with that question.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 13 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Razetime, and then -3 bytes thanks to Leo*

```
►(ΣḋΩ≥0+^32 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr///ilroozqPhuIvOqeKJpTArXjMyIDL///9bMCwxLDIsMywtNF0)

[Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) natively uses arbitrary-precision integers, and so has no notion of 32-bit 2's complement for representing negative 4-byte signed integers: as a result, the 'get binary digits' function - `ḋ` - is sadly useless here for negative inputs.
So we need to calculate the '2's complement bittiness' by hand.

Thanks to [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) help from [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo) for the use of `Ω` here.

```
►                       # element of input that maximises result of:
 (Σḋ                    # sum of binary digits of
    Ω                   # repeat until result is
     ≥0                 # greater than or equal to zero:
       +^32 2           # add 2^32
```

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Xfb55xY/3NGt8ahzgbERmJn4qG2S5qPOpQb///@PNjQy1jEz0THQ0TWJBQA "Husk – Try It Online") (why do you need to increment the negative integers?)

Comment: @Razetime Thanks!  Minus 3 is '1011111...' in 2's-complement, so it's the NOT of the bits of plus 2, and so on, hence the need to increment before the bit-count.  I think...

Comment: @Razetime (but maybe you'll be able to make the 'add 2^32' approach... (see Husk chatroom...)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ñÈu2pH)¤¬x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=8ch1MnBIKaSseA&input=WzEyMyA2NCAwIC00XQ)

```
ñÈu2pH)¤¬x     :Implicit input of array
ñ              :Sort by
 È             :Passing each element through the following function
  u            :Positive modulo
   2p          :  2 raised to the power of
     H         :  32
      )        :End modulo
       ¤       :To binary string
        ¬      :Split
         x     :Reduce by addition
               :Implicit output of last element
```

Comment: Me either, @AZTECCO, first read through. I immediately typed up the exact same solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>9</strike> 8 bytes

```
%Ø%BSƲÞṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/18AxVp@Bjmw7Pe7hz1f///6MNjYx1zEx0DHR0TWIB)

*-1 byte by using `Þ` (sort) instead of `ÐṀ` (maximum). This was inspired by Gio D's answer and after their and my edit, both solutions are pretty much the same.*

### Explanation

```
%Ø%BSƲÞṪ   Main monadic link
      Þ    Sort by
     Ʋ     (
%            Modulo
 Ø%            2^32
   B         Binary
    S        Sum
     Ʋ     )
       Ṫ   Last item
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 73 bytes

```java
a->{int r=0,m=0,t;for(var i:a)if((t=i.bitCount(i))>m){m=t;r=i;}return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PZBBi8JADIXv/orgaQang1VZoaXCsqc9rBeP4iHWaZluO5U0dZEyv707VfGQkDzCex@p8IZRdfkd8xq7Dn7QumEGYB0bKjA3sJ/WhwC5@A5yaeh4ApRp0P0stI6RbQ57cJDBiNFumI4pW6omFKdFS@KGBDZBaQshOLP6bPmr7R0LK@WukUOTcUqZTT0Z7skBpX5MJ/Nrf66D@Svj1toLNIFRHJisKycQKjv5ZJyC3oQICTjzB2/heBqGWK3UWm28GuLVWn1s1FJF07ZVcey9fLgAHO4dm0a3PetrSOHaiSq8Sfdsa/1JhPdOc/skECgX8wTmC6fzML@@4sd/)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                     // Method with Integer-array parameter and int return-type
  int r=0,               //  Result-integer, starting at 0
      m=0,               //  Maximum bit-count integer, starting at 0
      t;                 //  Temp integer, uninitialized
  for(var i:a)           //  Loop over each Integer in the input-array:
    if((t=i.bitCount(i)) //   If its amount of 1s in the binary representation
       >m){              //   is larger than the current maximum:
      m=t;               //    Update the maximum with this bit-count
      r=i;}              //    And update the result with this integer
  return r;}             //  After the loop, return the resulting integer
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, <s>54</s> 45 bytes

```perl
map$a[(sprintf"%b",$_)=~y/1//]=$_,@F;$_=pop@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlMVqjuKAoM68kTUk1SUlHJV7Ttq5S31BfP9ZWJV7Hwc1aJd62IL/AIfH/f0MFIwVjBV0TBV3Df/kFJZn5ecX/dQsSAQ)

Comment: `sort{$f{$b}-$f{$a}}` saves 2

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>36</s> <s>33</s> 34 bytes

*Thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) for correcting my code for a special case! :)*

```ruby
p$*.max_by{("%034b"%_1)[2,32].sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BFSy83sSI@qbK6JrtGQ0nVwNgkSUk1WzPaSMfYKFavuDS39v///0aGJuYmFsZmJub/dQ0NzI3NTQwtjEwA)

Uses command-line args for input, outputs the *bittiest number* as a string. TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves two bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work in general because you're counting `1`s beyond the 32-bit representation of the number. An extreme example is inputs of `2147483647` and `-1073741824`, for which the correct output is `2147483647`.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BFSy83sSI@qbK6JrtGQ0nVwMwkSUk1WzNa19hIx9goVq@4NLf2////RoYm5iYWxmYm5v91DQ3Mjc1NDC2MTAA "Ruby – Try It Online") should work I think.

Comment: @Dingus - Hm, it's a little longer, but I would like to know how it works. Also, then `032b` will work?

Comment: It's taking the `sum` of the codepoints of the last 32 characters. Surprisingly enough, `032b` doesn't work: `("%032b"%(2147483647)).bytes.size` returns `32` but `("%032b"%(-1073741824)).bytes.size` returns `33`, apparently because of the leading `..`. However, you can use `034b` and then [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BFSy83sSI@qbK6JrtGQ0nVwNgkSUk1WzPaSMfYKFavuDS39v///0aGJuYmFsZmJub/dQ0NzI3NTQwtjEwA "Ruby – Try It Online") is 2 bytes shorter than my earlier attempt.

Comment: One other point: it's not clear to me whether OP is accepting string I/O for this challenge.

Comment: @Dingus - I will ask the OP for this, and also suggest this testcase.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 44 bytes

```java
a->a.max((x,y)->x.bitCount(x)-x.bitCount(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZAxb8IwEIV3fsWJyRaO1QBqJWgjVZ06lA6MUYYjmMhpYke2QxNF@e2pQ1BBYrH1zt@9e74czxjkx58hLdBa@EKpuhmAVE6YE6YCdqMEyD3HaycL/l05qRUWr5@eyYSJICW3V@uMwJLvL9cNQbr1Nv3MH9ahkynsQMEbDBhEyEtsCGlYS4Oo4QfpPnStHGlocKdaSoft2F/Vh8L3X23OWh6h9KmJHylVFieAJrN0Sn3ShlwzxAnCBpT4hf9CnHRdyJZsxdY968Llij2v2RMLRvXCwrDv6cUFYN9aJ0qua8crP8UV6u7L78Zga7nTUwKCdDHfwHyhePpITfvxDL1upB/@AA)

This is kind of cheating, as it accepts a `Stream<Integer>` as input and returns an `Optional<Int>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>71</s> 58 bytes

```cs
l=>l.OrderBy(r=>Convert.ToString(r,2).Sum(c=>c-48)).Last()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcuxCsIwFEDR3a94YwKvwdaggiaDglPBoYJD6WDTIIGawkuqiPjtsfgDOt3lXBMyE1w6jN5snY91gzBFQwsq9Ur34kidpd2TkdL7wd8tRXEaqkjOXxlhwUU13phR2mRyzbkoLyEynjazCYeht@JMLtrSecta5u2jbuAFebFAWEqEOUIm4c35D49QIEzPH3aFef5V6QM)

- Refactored to use a lambda as suggested by @user in comments

Comment: A lambda would make this [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##jcuxCsIwFEDR3a94YwKvwdaggiaDglPBoYJD6WDTIIGawkuqiPjtsfgDOt3lXBMyE1w6jN5snY91gzBFQwsq9Ur34kidpd2TkdL7wd8tRXEaqkjOXxlhwUU13phR2mRyzbkoLyEynjazCYeht@JMLtrSecta5u2jbuAFebFAWEqEOUIm4c35D49QIEzPH3aFef5V6QM)

Comment: Is that allowed by the rules?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I thought it shouldn’t because it isn’t a function nor a program.

Comment: No, lambdas are fine - they're basically functions. There should be a meta question somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Same concept, but shaved off 6 bytes ([52 bytes](https://tio.run/##jcuxCsIwFEDR3a94i5DAa7Cx1EGTRXDSqYJD6WBDKIGYwmuqgvjtMfgDOt3lXDMVZnLpMAezcyG2HUKOhh5U8kp7cbo@GSnN9mO4W4riPDaRXBgYoeSimW/MKG2WNUfiXFDaLrKcRm/FhVy0Rxcs61mwj7aDF5RyjVBXCCuEooI35z88gkTIzx92g2X5VekD)): `l=>l.Max(r=>Convert.ToString(r,2).Sum(c=>c%6),r)).r`. Also takes advantage of the fact that the char value of `'1'` is odd to save 1 byte.

Comment: ^should be %2, not %6, but same count in the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```scala
_ maxBy Integer.bitCount
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBC4IwAIXv@xXvOGFGmhQIBtWpswSBSMyasliz5pJE/O1rXqPT472P93VXrrhrq7u4WpxHQshN1HhwqSk3TZdiZwwfitwaqZsySHHS0iLDSICeK9QpcvEqjtqWyLbw6SFxF6/47Ie5i0aYRSXtoX1r6wh5epNVmtbUH2nEEDOsGJIgCH5Z7Pd1wrBkCP/wDUMUzTOZJufCXn0B)

Split off from [Gabber's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99988/gabber) great [first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216711/95792).

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh, 71 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##HcdLCsIwFAXQeVZxIaEkVWk@RUETuxBxkIChLwMFqxNL1x6ts3M@01izVDN736fbCxEJhFLz4wk6xSBmISV5PVw4t1fbts5u6PgPKdV1emkaKQWP5zTIEmibwi9KKea9F6UuLMPAwqFfZR32PTR26w4wpn4B)
 <sub><s>[81bytes](https://tio.run/##HcdBCsIwFEXReVfxIKH8XxWapCjE1K7AFYijxNJkoGB1Ysnao3VyueczT2UkXqr3fb694BEQkcr4eCIefS8XIRc68y@ztSyJomuHixD6qpvG6E20f0TmLFTOdU3kT2Gg1Mdt6D0zV845mUquRihoGHTraYN9hxa7VQcoVb4)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[85bytes](https://tio.run/##HcdBCsIwFEXReVbxICHkV4QmLQppoitwBeIotfg7ULA6MWTt0Tq53PNZbnUylMX7vlxfSBjBmOv0eIKHnKLKUmVzol8W70kZw6E9nqV0F9c0nduw/4OJirSlCGPSYSTSeo6KtR6jSkMRIQQ11yImWDh06NdzHXY9WmxX7WFt/QI)</s></sub>

```bash
for i;a=${$((i<0?[##2]2**32+i:[##2]i))//0}&&(($#a>b?(j=i,b=$#a)))
<<<$j
```

Great challenge, required some of the weirdest `Zsh` incantations! Explanation:
<sub>`for i;` ... implicit iteration over all arguments

`$((i<0?[##2]2**32+i:[##2]i))` ... convert `i` to 32-bit format, using two's complement trick if `i<0`

`a=${ ~string~ //0}` ... remove all `0`s from string

`(($#a>b?(j=i,b=$#a)))` ... keep track of which input `i` is the "**b**ittiest" according to the length of string `a`

`<<<$j` ... output the winner</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔ＥθΣ⍘﹪ιＸ²¦³²¦²ηＩ§θ⌕η⌈η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCoMwFAD3fsUbX@AJrUoXJysUOgQER3F4qJiAJm0SW/8@jTfcdNyo2I2W1xhr7/ViUPIbPwTdvuGD/dwFp82C0k77alETtPY3O8wJilwIgqRkJapLm8KADfuAdXiZaT7Oz1ObCRWB5ENv6anESRVj39/yguBeElwJsnIYYvZd/w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔ＥθΣ⍘﹪ιＸ²¦³²¦²η
```

For each number in the list, cast it to a 32-bit unsigned number, convert it to binary, and sum the bits.

```
Ｉ§θ⌕η⌈η
```

Output the number at the position of the highest bit count.

Answer (score 1):

### SystemVerilog, 66 bytes

This will be an imperfect answer for now as I’m posting from my phone, but SV’s`$countones()` function is perfect here.

```
function m(int q[$]);
m=q.max with ($countones(item));
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>53</strike> 56 bytes

+5 bytes because it did not handle negatives properly
-2 bytes thanks to mazzy

```
$args|sort{$v=$_;0..31|%{$o+=!!(1-shl$_-band$v)};$o}-b 1
```

Comment: It does not work with negative integers. Because `-1 -shr 1` never be the `0`. See test case `123, 64, 0, -4`

Comment: I think we can to use features ot the latest Powershell version by default. For example `...|sort -top 1` instead `(...|sort)[-1]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24pji/qKRaJc9WJd7aQE/P2LBGtVolWdtWQyVPtzijSCVeU9Wo1loluVa3RMHw////hkbG/81M/hv81zUBAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: you can use `%2` instead operator `-band`. see [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24pji/qKRaJc9WJd7aQE/P2LBGtVolWdtWQyVPtzijSCVeU9Wo1loluVa3RMHw////hkbG/81M/hv81zUBAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") again.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that method doesn't work. It works for the case provided because sort sorts ascending by default, and top 1 takes the first element of -30 for -4; you'd need the absolute value of $c to return to sort, and you'd need to still select the bottom 1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDLCsIwELz3K3LYSoO29BFUKoGCJw9evYiUUqIVSlqSFIWab49NiyKIOJfdndkZlm2bGxOyYnVt4NzxUl0bTh00oDdQiIt8uD1wCvkmDIIkslM5px5wX1YCcuzGegOlNtoBxaTaFpJJRFHmjRlZPxaLK287ZRsrEjzyevFrwTvuuEriU5rui/uhqDuG/1n8V6iDP295IBdNDpjWKYI8GNuJFUx2taVn7weg7Et39JAkG6GMCU1kfGLiiKzIOlmS1RM)

Comment: @mazzy sorry, that last tio for my example was all janked up because I tried to adapt from a different one I was working on. This one should demonstrate more clearly: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1WiXPViXe2kBPz9gQxEvWttVQydMtzihSiddUNaq1Vkmu/V/LBVOtppKm4BBfW1OcX1Ty/7/hfw1dI0MTcxMLYzMTC83/cLY5UMJEEwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: got it. you are right. [what about this?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1WiXPViXeWsNAT8/YsMa@WkMlT7c4o0glXlPVqFZTzzm/NK@k9n8tF0y5mkqagkN8bU1xflHJ//@G/zV0jQxNzE0sjM1MLDT/w9nmQAkTTQA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
Last@*SortBy[Mod[#,2^32]~DigitCount~2&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexuMRBKzi/qMSpMto3PyVaWccoztgots4lMz2zxDm/NK@kzkgt9n9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtaGOkY6xjkmtDpBpZKxjZqJjoKML5prrGBrWctX@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```
import algorithm,bitops
func b(n:seq):int=n.sortedByIt(it.countSetBits)[^1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEITEnPb8osyQjVycpsyS/oJgrrTQvWSFJI8@qOLVQ0yozr8Q2T68YqDI1xanSs0Qjs0QvOb80ryQ4tcQps6RYMzrOMPZ/anJGvoJDtKF6prGRjoIRhDKGUCYgKlYviQumyAgqYWYCoQ0glC66QnOIuKEhVPw/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
{.@\:[:+/"1(32$2)&#:
```

As written, when given multiple equally, maximally bitty numbers, returns the first in the array. If `{.\:` is changed to `{:/:`, it gives the last.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WqlrPIcYq2kpbX8lQw9hIxUhTTdkKKOFgp2CoYKRgrGCiYK1gaGSsYGaiYKAQD@KZKxgacgEA)

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tip for golfing in J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/tips-for-golfing-in-j) page

Answer (score 1):

### AArch64, <strike>48</strike> 44 bytes

Raw instructions (32-bit little endian hex):

```
1e2703e4 bc404400 0e205801 2e303821
0ea43c23 2ea31c02 2ea31c24 f1000421
54ffff21 1e260040 d65f03c0
```

Uncommented assembly:

```armasm
        .globl bittiest
bittiest:
        fmov    s4, #0
.Lloop:
        ldr     s0, [x0], #4
        cnt     v1.8b, v0.8b
        uaddlv  h1, v1.8b
        cmge    v3.2s, v1.2s, v4.2s
        bit     v2.8b, v0.8b, v3.8b
        bit     v4.8b, v1.8b, v3.8b
        subs    x1, x1, #1
        bne     .Lloop
        fmov    w0, s2
        ret
```

#### Explanation

C function signature:

```armasm
int32_t bittiest(int32_t *words, size_t len);
```

Pseudo-C:

```c
int32_t bittiest(int32_t *words, size_t len)
{
    int32_t maxcount = 0;
    int32_t maxvalue;
    do {
        int32_t value = *words++;
        int8_t counts[4] = popcount8x4((int8_t *)&value);
        int32_t count = counts[0] + counts[1] + counts[2] + counts[3];
        if (count >= maxcount) {
            maxvalue = value;
            maxcount = count;
        }
    } while (--len);
    return maxvalue;
}
```

AArch64's population count instruction is in NEON (the SIMD/floating point instruction set), and it counts each byte individually. Therefore, it is a little awkward to work with scalars here so we do everything in NEON.

v4 is the max population count (v4, s4, h4, and d4 all refer to the same register). Set it to 0.

```armasm
        fmov    s4, #0
```

Load the next int32 word into v0, and increment words (x0) by 4.

```armasm
        ldr     s0, [x0], #4
```

Store the population count of each byte in v0 into the corresponding byte in v1.

```armasm
        cnt     v1.8b, v0.8b
```

Add all of the 8-bit lanes in v1 together to get the full population count, and store into v1 again.

```armasm
        uaddlv  h1, v1.8b
```

Compare the population count of this word to the maximum. If it is larger or equal, v3 will be all 1 bits (true), otherwise it will be all 0 bits (false).

```armasm
        cmge    v3.2s, v1.2s, v4.2s
```

If v3 is true, set the max word (v2) to the current word.
max is not initialized on the first iteration, but it will always be set because the population count will always be >= 0.

```armasm
        bit     v2.8b, v0.8b, v3.8b
```

Same, but for the new max population count.

```armasm
        bit     v4.8b, v1.8b, v3.8b
```

Decrement len (x1), and loop if it is not zero

```armasm
        subs    x1, x1, #1
        bne     .Lloop
```

End of loop: Move the maximum value from a NEON register to the return register (w0), and return.

```armasm
        fmov    w0, s2
        ret
```

11 instructions = 44 bytes

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you separate the code from the other stuff to make things a little easier to read?  One big code block is a little hard to understand at least for me.

Comment: Is that what you meant? I also added the compiled version.

Comment: Yeah that and the explanation are really helpful.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](https://www.kx.com), 15 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{*x@>+/+0b\:'x}
```

**Explanation:**

Pretty much exactly the same as the ngn/k solution:

```
{            x} / lamdba taking implicit argument x
        0b\:'   / convert (0b \:) each (') to binary representation
       +        / flip (transpose)
     +/         / sum (+) over (/)
    >           / indices to sort descending
  x@            / apply indices to input x
 *              / take the first
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
x->x[argmax(count_ones.(x))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NCsJADIX3OUUoLmYgFfuDrureM9Qixc7IlDqVdgpzD8GVp/MiNa0WXBjIIu9976UeGlNGftSY4ejDvc/L7nItvTi3g3Wn1qp@LbyUxehU73qmcjhYl8R5RBgTJoRpgdNkez4WL2Z9mxJuCEP22QvTxdwRRtEnswRZY4mgAADddigM1RKNxfkpwIRpw8@1MHK@jJ4EJmpYem6dsa6xIng97xgQmqlZf3nV9Oof@fghCYOjE8rf1NmpCle1DL5hWwHv@AY)